# How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, new-users

I've been a "passive user" of Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites for years.  I have derived enormous benefit from it (many thanks!!), and I finally decided to become more *active*. It seems difficult for a "new" user to get started.

A relatively short time ago, I finally created an account to start answering and editing and posting and commenting!  I was full of excitement and vigor and immediately tried to upvote (nope!) and post a comment (nope!).  I need (threshold) amount of rep to do comment on this or that, or even upvote certain things... which is totally reasonable (perhaps "necessary" is a better term).

So I browsed a bit (such as [whats-reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)).  Advice to new users seems to be: just ask, answer, and suggest edits!  But there are *so many* questions and good answers, a truly good question and new question seems hard to create.  To truly give justice to all previous questions on a topic requires as much effort (or more?) as posing a question.  And there are *so many* users that to troll-and-pounce the new-questions board could be a full-time job.  And BTW, you can only put 2 links in a question when you have <10 rep, so it's very difficult to show due-diligence and to pose a truly good question to begin with!

I didn't find any actual "question" on this topic of how to get started -- but found a few gems like [six simple rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast), walking a (presumably-intentional) delicate balance between productive debate and provocative cynicism.

So I decided to post a question on this topic!  Meta.SO seemed like the right place.   NOPE!  I needed 5 rep to even post a question.  Probably also for good reason.

Now that I have >5 rep (w00t), here I am.  After all that background (sorry) --
**How does anyone get started around here these days?**

My understanding now boils down to the following:

- You have no choice but to **start slowly**.
- **Be patient** and try to do contribute where you can.
- Be prepared to **accept initial rejection and failure**.
- Learn [how to edit](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and **make stuff pretty**.

What am I missing?  Do I "get it"?  Have I completely missed the point?  How can The System encourage new users who are here for the "right reasons" to quickly start contributing meaningfully and harness their energy for the Common Good?

Comment: Answer questions when you have something useful to contribute.  Ask questions when you have questions.  If you have time to contribute, spend that time working on a useful open source project, and in so doing you'll accumulate more real-world experience that will make your SO answers more valuable.

Comment: I'm a low rep user and it doesn't bother me one bit. If it's "hard" to figure out a question to ask, that must mean that you can find an answer to most (if not all) of your problems here. Isn't that a good thing? I suppose trying to answer other people's questions is a decent way to contribute (and gain rep, if that is important). Personally I quickly found I don't really have the patience, as the quality of the questions on the tags I follow are generally quite low, but if you have the patience for it then I would say go for it. Gaining rep isn't the ultimate purpose here though.

Comment: One frustrating thing is, that I cannot even upvote stuff on other StackExchange-sites, even if I've been active on this particular site. In a way it makes sense, but it's frustrating regardless.

Comment: @F-3000 There's a per-site [+100 association bonus](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/) that earns you the basic privileges on all your StackExchange accounts once you hit 200 on any site.  That'd take care of your upvote problem.

Comment: I don't know about the West Coast of the US, but over here one's reputation on Stack Overflow carries about as much weight as the number of neighbours you have in Farmville.  Maybe even LESS!  (Skeet and Gravell exempted of course)

Comment: @BradKoch part of the problem is that 200 points is a much higher bar than it used to be. Most of the good questions will be duplicates, meaning it's rare to get points for asking, and answering will require some combination of speed, writing skills, and specialized knowledge. Speed and writing skills can come with practice, but if you're already discouraged you're unlikely to practice.

Comment: @MarkRansom F-3000 I know it's tough on SO these days.  You missed the [*any site*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253658/425313) part.  On the contrary, little of my rep is from new questions; two populists, a dozen necromancers, and half as many revivals that say speed has nothing to do with it.  I don't see an answer that concisely describes what I did; maybe I'll add one soon.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275362/631619

Comment: as a small "trick" for the start: If you register to SO and than any othe rof the SE-sites aswell, you get 100 rep on each. Thus you can at least upvote. Obviosly you should register to SE-sites that you're interested in and at least check out once in a while. Beside that: I don't know if this method is intended or not.

Comment: You ask a question on meta about a critical topic that gets attention. After this, some users will view your profile, and will increase drastically your reputation (consequences of more votes for the questions you've made in the past) if you made a good answer that have not enough views to improve your rep.

Coincidence or not, it worked with an answer I made in the Workplace.

Comment: Also, is getting started on the site really about the Rep? Isn't it about contributing, and the rep is a consequence? This really huge focus on the reputation causes a drop in quality answer... Fastest gun in the west, incorrect solutions (I tried to flag and edit a lot of them)

Comment: Dear @hoc_age, the six rules are pure gold and they are true indeed. To gain reputation fast you have to look for soft questions and answer them quickly. If the OP recognizes your work is +25 points (answer + upvote, typically). I've been scanning the homepage for hours in order to find the right question and quickly provide the answer and that's how you do gain rep points in SO, sad but true. I've been doing loads of edits as well (fair +2). Also, not surprisingly, some more appropriate answers to heavy subjects (e.g. machine learning) didn't get the attention they deserve.

Answer (score 346, accepted):

It seems like you get it. Long gone are the days of camping on the front page to gain fast reputation by quickly answering softball questions. The questions are coming in too quickly, site standards have changed drastically, and there's a lot more competition to either answer or close easy questions.

The one piece of advice that I'll give you that you haven't mentioned is to pick some favorite tags that you're an expert in and add them to your favorites list (in the main page right sidebar).

[image: Favorites]

This will highlight questions with those tags when you view the list of Newest questions, and it will even filter the list of selected questions when you view the Stack Overflow home page so that you see more questions with your favorite tags. By focusing your attention on your favorite tags, you'll see more questions that you're interested in and may be able to answer. You'll also be better able to suggest good edits to questions in your area of expertise.

You can also block tags for languages that you don't know by adding them to your Ignored tags list. By default, questions with Ignored tags will just be greyed out, but you can hide them entirely from the Preferences tab in your profile.

---

If you need a little bit of inspiration, here are a few users that have gained a lot of reputation in a relatively short amount of time, despite not having joined the site at the very beginning:

- [akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun) - Member for 2 years, 6 months with over 220,000 reputation
- [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) - Member for 2 years, 5 months with over 150,000 reputation
- [Jean-François Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6451573/jean-fran%C3%A7ois-fabre) - Member for only 6 months, but already has over 24,000 reputation

What do they all have in common? They answer *tons* of questions!

Comment: Many thanks.  Tags added (it's not obvious to me on the "view" pages, and not available on my "user" page...?) Again, I'd up-vote but even after >1 dozen up-votes on this question alone, it still looks like I have 8 rep?  I have so much to learn about *actually* contributing to this site. :)

Comment: @hoc_age from [What is "meta"?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta): _Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Stack Overflow (synchronized hourly)_. You can not earn (or lose) reputation on meta.

Comment: **One tip:** block tags which has a lot of crappy questions for example `[facebook*]`. The asterisk will find all variants of the facebook tag.

Comment: Being a member for a year now, I can confirm that focusing on special-interest questions really works. Not only for gaining reputation; after all, that’s the best way to improve the site and having fun at the same time.

Comment: **My Tip:** Search for unanswered questions with tags that you are really familiar with. Answer these to get more rep as well as more know knowledge dissemination.

Comment: I would not suggest a user try to "answer a ton of questions".

Answer (score 105):

There's an alternate route to obtaining basic privileges, if you're finding the competition here too intense.

## Utilize the association bonus

If you hit 200 rep on any site, you'll automatically receive a [+100 association bonus](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/) on all sites.  In my experience earning reputation on the beta sites is extremely easy due to reduced competition. Find a topic you have some expertise on, become a valuable contributor there, and you'll quickly earn your basic privileges.  Even better, now you're helping out two sites!

Think of it as someone else vouching for your trustworthiness, so don't let them down by coming back here and making a mess.

Comment: I really don't know if the solution is that users should "game the system". I really would have liked to post comment in the beginng, because often i didn't understand an aspect or wanted to expand on an good answer. Well it's like wikipedia, soon nobody will want to register because the elitist will downvote every new user mercilessly.

Comment: You very much should not think of it as "gaming the system".  The bonus exists for a reason: we only need to validate your basic trustworthiness once.  It doesn't really matter where you earn that trust so long as you uphold it.

Comment: @BradKoch Yet answering protected questions and downvoting require 110 and 125, specifically to shut out low-quality contributions to Hot Network Questions from users with the bonus. So it does matter on which SE site you earned that trust. And only SO rep counts for Careers.

Comment: @sebastian - you hit on my experience exactly.  I don't feel up to giving answer, but can contribute with a comment.  Yet cant' because I'm too new.  And in the process I see new people run off a bit by the process and negatives.

Comment: This is the best way, imo. I tried for months to find good questions to answer, and I tried to find questions that somebody else hadn't asked. . . never happened. So, I answered a few questions on sci-fi and broke through the association bonus! And here I am now, mostly still lurking.

Answer (score 65):

## Take the tour, earn a badge.

If you are reading this, you are probably the sort of person who has the ability to succeed on Stack Overflow. Even so, [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) provides the big picture of how the site ought to work. It also gives you a badge. Another easy badge is [Autobiographer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/9/autobiographer), which has the advantage others can learn who you are as a person.

## Consider editing.

The next easiest badge to earn is [Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3/editor). Anyone may submit a suggested edit for [community review](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). If you find a mistake or outdated information on any post and you know how to fix it, click on the edit link and suggest a change. [Editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) is a good way to learn what the community expects from posts and also will familiarize you with how posts are [formatted with Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). In addition, successfully suggesting edits earns a [small amount of reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

## Answering is often easier than asking.

It's almost certainly gotten exponentially harder to ask questions than when many of us earned our (now slightly dusty) [beta badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/30/beta?userid=1438). This chart tells the story:

```
year questions avg_score deleted_rate closed_rate  dupes dupe_rate 
---- --------- --------- ------------ ----------- ------ --------- 
2008     70372     18.40          6.4         3.9   1145      1.63      
2009    394567      6.19          4.5         3.6   4800      1.22      
2010    820161      3.43          6.3         3.4  10162      1.24      
2011   1445142      2.18          7.9         5.7  21103      1.46      
2012   2065664      1.28         10.2         7.9  34471      1.67      
2013   2759442      0.61         14.7        10.9  52002      1.88      
2014   3040440      0.17         17.9        10.4  68500      2.25      
2015   2061746      0.08         17.2         8.7  52759      2.56
```

New questions are more likely to be closed or deleted than in the past. It's gotten harder to ask questions that haven't [already been asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303704/1438). In the best of times, asking interesting questions is harder than answering them. So I'd recommend looking for questions you can try answering before starting to ask.

If you have a different way of looking at a question, it really doesn't hurt to add another answer *even if there's an accepted answer*. The goal isn't to just help the one person who asked the question, but to [help anyone with that same general problem](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/) who might find the question via search. There's no guarantee that your answer will be upvoted, but as long as your answer is accurate, clear, and noticeably different than others, it's not likely to be downvoted.

## Consider learning a new language.

There's a good chance that your question in C, C++, C#, Objective-C, Java, JavaScript, JavaFX, or JSF has [already been asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303704/1438). Less popular languages have less duplication and fewer grouchy grognards who have seen the same few questions asked over and over again. Newer languages tend to not reach that level of saturation, so it might be worthwhile to learn a new language for the purposes of getting started on Stack Overflow. Plus it's a great way to [teach yourself programming in 10 years](http://norvig.com/21-days.html).

## Debug before asking.

Sometimes, you just need some help solving a problem in your code at which point a question on Stack Overflow would be a good entry point. Don't make the mistake of posting your code verbatim. Instead, [search for the handful of lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843909/debugging-and-binary-search) that seem to be buggy. Surprisingly, doing just that is often enough to discover the problem. If your goal is to participate on Stack Overflow, **don't be afraid to ask and answer your own question**. Be sure to check for duplicate questions before posting (in which case, consider posting your own answer), but don't feel as if your question is wasteful if you already know the answer. Remember that helping the initial asker is not the primary goal of Stack Overflow.

## Learn from setbacks.

You will almost certainly be downvoted at some point using the site. You might get critical comments, have a question closed, or a post deleted. In those situations, it's important to know that:

1. it's not personal,
2. there's almost always something you could have done better, and
3. recovery won't be hard if you take a few minutes to understand what happened.

Far and away the biggest mistake people make when using the site is **ignoring advice they don't immediately understand**. When people continue to post without learning what [those signals are trying to say](http://jericson.github.io/2015/05/18/downvotes.html), they start running into suspensions, blocks and rate limits.

## Get help and get meta.

Most of the common problems people run into are answered in the help center. In particular, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). If those don't help, look around on meta for other people who have had the same problem. If that *still doesn't help* go ahead and ask about your specific situation here on meta. Be aware that meta has very similar conventions to the main site. Much of the above advice applies here too.

Comment: Yeah.  Downvotes aren't personal.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: I was hoping your comment would come with a downvote. ;-)

Comment: @JonEricson Problem fixed.  (nice answer, it's a shame I had to downvote it.)

Comment: @Servy: <strike>YOU JERK!</strike>  Ahem. I'm sure I'll do better next time.

Comment: As a fairly new contributor, I think it should be mandatory to write a comment or do 'something visible to the downvoted' when downvoting, in order to make him/her understand what happened

Answer (score 62):

Try answering at a time of day or day of week when there are fewer users on Stack Overflow and presumably less competition for answering questions. Yeah, I get that Stack Overflow is an international site and people are on it at all hours of the day, but there are times of the day with significantly less traffic as seen here:

[image: GMT Time]

Please note these times are GMT.

See [this post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/the-best-time-to-ask-a-stack-overflow-question/) for more details.

It appears that Stack Overflow's heaviest users are North America as seen [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25598/where-in-the-world-do-stack-overflow-users-say-they-are-from?lq=1) so the lightest times are when North Americans are sleeping.

I would imagine there are days of the week that are also that are lighter eg Friday

Perhaps it is just a coincidence, but I found this out the hard way. I was burning the midnight oil so to speak and posted a question at the lowest activity time and received no answers.

Comment: But fewer users means fewer questions as well as few answers so the ratio remains more or less constant?

Comment: There would still be less competition for answering a specific question. The OP was mentioning that people are waiting to pounce on any new question and answer it right away. There are less people waiting to pounce on any given question at lower traffic times. From personal experience I do find that if I ask a question late in the day, it usually does not get answered until the next day.

Comment: While there will be less competition, the disadvantage is that there are also less views, which could potentially translate into less upvotes. So there are both pros and cons to your time-of-day based approach.

Comment: True, though for a new user just looking to gain some rep to get some privileges and/or remove restrictions, small gains are not such a bad thing.

Comment: Do you get rep from upvotes in meta?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia, No

Comment: There's [a couple of updated charts in an answer on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363293/293308).

Comment: This has to be one of the most useful posts on SO!

Answer (score 57):

I started at the end of last year and it was easy enough to rack up a reputation score. I'm a Java expert so I just started browsing the latest Java questions and when I saw a question that looked interesting I posted an answer for it.

A lot of those questions only need a few lines or a paragraph to answer them. My first ever answer wasn't much over 3 lines but I was lucky and got 6 upvotes. My next few answers got 0 or 1 votes but I persisted and over time got better at answering - and as a result the number of votes I started getting for answers started going up.

Don't expect to get upvotes or accepts on all of your answers but it only takes a few upvotes to start removing the new user restrictions. One thing that does help a lot is replying both fast and accurately. With multiple correct answers generally the first one posted will get the upvotes.

It's actually much easier to get reputation on answers than it is on questions. There are always questions in your favorite topic waiting for you to answer them.

There are no limits on how many questions you can answer - so find a way to isolate the questions in an area where you have expertise and then focus on answering the new questions that do not have good answers yet or questions where the existing answers are incomplete. Duplicating existing answers will get you nowhere although sometimes people do post the same answer simultaneously but that cannot be avoided.

Comment: 15k rep in 4 months. I don't think this is normal.

Comment: @gunr2171 Definitely not normal. As I said I'm a Java expert, if you don't have expertise in a reasonably popular and active field it's not going to be so easy but it is still doable. You also need to be active in finding and answering questions. I've written 862 answers...which is around 7 a day.

Comment: I'm less active than @TimB, but when I wanted to post a bounty on my first question I was able to accumulate enough reputation in a few days, mainly from the "java" and "algorithm" tags. I have some Java experience, and have taken a graduate course on algorithm design.

Comment: While this is good advice for gaining reputation, it's not the best advice for improving the site.  If there were less pressure to answer quickly, more people would take the time to provide more complete answers.

Comment: @WarrenDew I agree, and that is one reason I said accurately in my reply. Unfortunately though the first reply generally accumulates the upvotes as a natural consequence of the way the site works. Quality will win out on more important questions though since they are the ones that get visited after the first few hours.

Comment: "it only takes a few upvotes to start removing the new user restrictions" - that is the saving grace of SO for new users.  As a new user I discovered that I just needed to put forth a good answer 1 or 2 times, and then everything got better.

Comment: That's right -  It's actually surprising what difference a couple of upvotes can make, perhaps 10 at a time or more. As long as you post regularly (1x or 2x per day) and occasionally get upvoted, a new user can expect to get about 50 rep within a week and a half.

Comment: @gunr2171 3 months, 467 rep. I don't get it!

Comment: @gunr2171 [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16676737/bondarenko) 204 in 8 days, squashes me like a bug!

Answer (score 43):

Bill the Lizard and Cupcake provide excellent answers.  I would just add a few things.

- Learn how to identify motivated question askers.  If the asker has been responding to comments, he still needs an answer.  If he hasn't, he's more likely to have abandoned the question, so you won't get rep for answer acceptance.
- Consider looking at bounties, especially on tags where you actually are an expert.  Anyone who is spending their own rep to get a question answered is likely pretty motivated to get that answer, and will probably be back to select a correct answer - and also to answer requests for clarification, which can help a lot in producing an accepted answer.  It can be worth spending quite a bit of effort to answer these questions; for example, on my most successful bounty attempt, I learned parts of an unfamiliar library for a platform I don't write for, but I got 525 rep for it.
- As you allude to, editing questions is a way to grind past the early newbie levels.  In particular, lots of newbie questions have unformatted or poorly formatted code; edits that format the code properly are usually accepted and as a bonus are very helpful to anyone who subsequently reads the question.

Comment: With the bounties, I have actually began further research into things I didn't think I had interest in, but because that was motivation for me I began to use them more. +1

Comment: It surprised me how many bounty questions are easily answerable if you simply take an hour to replicate the asker's environment and debug actual, running code. I've had zero competition on the 3 questions I've done this with, so it was easy rep.

Comment: @MichaelKropat In the hour you replicate the OP's environment: a) how many correct answers to easier questions could you have submitted? b) you run the risk of having someone else scoop you. And then there are those bounty givers who become disinterested (I've seen it) or decide that your answer is not *quite* what they want so accept *their own* answer, based on yours (I've seen this too). If the tag is popular you may still get enough upvotes to get 1/2 the bounty. If not then you get no bounty. When I answer a bounty question the rep math is not the justification for it.

Comment: Do you get rep from upvotes in meta?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia No, you do not get rep from meta upvotes.

Answer (score 37):

There's something that isn't really touched on in the other answers, at least that I saw. I read them all but if this is covered in another post, well, oops.

The other answers seem to be focused on how to gain reputation and what not. And if that's your goal, cool, those are great answers.

But if your goal is to really contribute to the community, do your job (or hobby or whatever it is when you're programming) and when you run into something difficult, post a question. I know answers are much better than questions for rep, but for really learning Stack Exchange, you have to be personally invested.

If you go answer someone's question, you might have some attachment to it. Might. But when you ask your own question, it really brings it home. The question that really brought it home for me was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4823353/330057). I had a problem at work I was given because I was a Java guy and that must mean I knew SQL. But I didn't. But I wasn't one to shy away from the task. So I sought to really understand the problem and thought to myself "I can describe this in English so easy... and this has to be a common problem... but I can't find the solution anywhere with the terms I'm using..."

And then [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135152/omg-ponies) came along and completely saved the day. My manager was super happy, and when I told him I just made a Stack Overflow post, he about had to change his pants. He couldn't believe that someone out there just looked at my question and gave me the code snippet I needed to get my job done right. And so quick - it was about half an hour between asking and having it answered.

And ever since then, it's been personal. It's been "there's people out there with problems, and I want to help them like I was helped." I want to help get people out of a bind (when I can, I find I have stretches where there isn't much time). And if you want to feel driven to help people, you have to know what it's like to be helped. And that means you have to ask questions.

Comment: Thank you.  And that kind of posting HAS helped me out of binds when I'd hit the end and had no idea what to google to figure out the answer.

Answer (score 26):

The only useful tip I can add, that I've found to be extremely convenient, in addition to following your favourite tags, is to make yourself a custom Stack Overflow bookmark; it *really* helps to weed out everything except whatever it is that you are interested in.  Mine, for example:

[Clicky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi+or+c%23+or+plc+or+.net+or+labview+or+assembly+or+x87+or+vb.net?sort=newest)

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi+or+c%23+or+plc+or+.net+or+labview+or+assembly+or+x87+or+vb.net?sort=newest
```

This gives a landing page with posts curated to seven of my key tags and sorted with newest posts on top. Obviously you can customize as desired. It saves a lot of clicking around, and it lets you always drop in on new and active posts. In addition, I find that I'm always learning something new along the way, because nearly every question that shows up is automatically relevant. Also, regardless of how frequently people are posting in a given tag, newer posts almost always need answers more than older posts. This isn't to encourage bottom feeding, certainly, but all other things being equal... you still have to be mindful of what you shoot for.

Read through, pick things that are interesting to you, and just try to answer them. Even if you don't know the answer or even if there is already an answer, just do it anyway - pretend it's a test and you have to come up with a solution; like a personal challenge.  Sooner or later you'll be the one coming up with the answer first, best, or both. It's excellent training for general problem solving skills even if you don't get the repuation points most of the time.

Answer (score 25):

> It's been seven hours and fifteen days*

It took me nearly three active months to get 2k rep and this thread helped me quite a lot, so I decided to contribute some findings.

> I can do whatever I want, I can see whomever I choose*

**Choose your favorite tags:** Choose a topic you really know something about and have fun thinking and learning about. Be prepared to do some research in order to answer a question. You'll learn a lot. (And earn some rep along the way)

> I go out every night and sleep all day*

**Take advantage of timezones:** You'll observe that most answers happen during certain hours a day, in my Tag when Europe or the States are working. At other times of the day or during weekends there is much more time to prepare a "fast" answer and less competition.

> I could put my arms around every boy I see*

**Be clear about your knowledge:** Don't try to answer each question which sounds somewhat familiar. Only answer when you are sure you are right and you can contribute something useful. There are many smart people around here, you will get bad comments and downvotes when you say something 'silly'.

> Tell me baby where did I go wrong*

**Accept critique:** It is unavoidable to do silly things in the beginning: bad answers, silly comments. You'll get downvotes and bad comments. Try to understand what they try to tell you and improve.

> I went to the doctor and guess what he told me*

**Imitate:** Quite soon you'll discover that people from the same small gang tend to be faster, have better answers and get a lot of upvotes for the same questions you are working with. Try to find out what they are doing and try to do the same. In my tag it is @Jon Skeet: He is always well informed, gives very understandable answers with nice code examples, which are explained in layman's terms if necessary. Just study what he is doing and try to do the same.

> I know that living with u baby was sometimes hard, but I'm willing to give it another try*

**Don't give up:** The very first active steps on SE are hard. In fact the first steps are the hardest. After your first upvoted answer things start to be fun and it becomes easier with every answer you write, later every comment, every edit. Try to survive the first few active days.

`*` Lyrics by Prince for Sinead O'Conner: Nothing Compares 2 U

Comment: I totally agree. I almost quit the site after a few weeks, then I got my first upvote, then I got totally hooked. Very humorous & inspired answer.

Comment: I need more upvotes for the structure/Prince lyrics

Answer (score 24):

Easy steps for getting started at SO.

1. Read the rules.
2. Learn the formatting.
3. Ask questions.
4. Understand that not even SO is immune from bullying, ignore the ones who are impolite, they are a very vocal minority, but JUST a minority
5. Enjoy the site
6. Contribute
7. Don't be a taker
8. Build your own rep, but remember, there are people who will vote you down no matter how good your question or answer is.  Don't take it to heart.  Keep trying until you get the feel for this place.
9. Use your up-vote power generously when you get it.
10. When someone gives you a good answer, choose it as the best answer.  They get a reputation bump and it is the best way to say "thanks"
11. Don't take criticism too hard, to those of us who have been doing this for a while, it looks easy, we forget that it's not to a new
    programmer, or to one who has switched disciplines.
12. Start slow, watch, and read. There are some helpful people in here, and there are some who are not, just like everywhere else.
13. The people here really care about the site.  They may seem harsh at times, but it is out of a sincere concern for the site and for the people here.
14. Just like everywhere else, there are people here who are not helpful, while they are the most vocal, that does not make them the
    most numerous.
15. Be patient.  This place gets flooded with bad questions and by people who just want to take what they can get without contributing anything to the site itself. Because of that, they have created a "tiered system" to screen out people who are not serious.
16. You will not be cut any slack.  This is a professional site, you will be treated as a professional.
17. You will encounter the occasional jerk, if this happens, flag for the staff to deal with, don't get into the mud.

Comment: #2 should be "regularly read meta stackoverflow". Rules only get you so far to understand this site.

Comment: @Gimby, yeah, but I only found meta by accident, and then it took me a while to find out that new users were not universally hated.  I mistook the genuine concern people have for this site as hostility towards anyone new.  I got it, eventually.

Answer (score 20):

As was already mentioned above, answering is the best way to gain reputation.

Here are some "pro" tips of how to maximize your reputation points per unit of time spent on Stack Overflow, based on personal experience (observing and answering):

- Try not to answer questions that you do not understand. Chance is you will not get it correctly, and/or it will take unreasonable amount of time to argue with OP about "what they really wanted". If you feel like the question is unclear, consider leaving a comment, and skipping to the next question. If your comment is later answered, and the question becomes clear enough, and it's still unanswered - now it's your time to give an answer.
- Try to only answer questions if you immediately know the answer, or can figure it out in 2-3 minutes by doing a simple Google search + maybe 1-2 minutes sandboxing in your development environment. This way even if you don't get any reputation points (for example, someone did it faster), you've only wasted 5 minutes of your time. It's very unrewarding to spend even 0.5 hour on someone's question only to find out they already accepted an answer, and never bothered to check other answers. This is relevant to the next point.
- The faster you answer, the more reputation you can get. This is because other people visiting the question may upvote your answer. You posted late, they've already been to this question and are definitely not coming back just to upvote your answer. There is a caveat - you answer incorrectly - you may get a lot of downvotes. So your initial answer must be fast, precise and actually address the issue in full. You may later edit it and add links to documentation, relevant articles, other Stack Overflow answers, etc. to make it nicer. Don't even try to write a perfect answer from the first attempt. There is a high chance some other user will provide a "fast" answer, which will get upvotes, get accepted, and then you finally post your answer, to find out nobody's there to read it.
- When answering a 1-2 hours old question, be prepared to waste your time. If a question was not answered immediately (within 10-15 minutes), and especially if it has no upvotes, or worse - a negative score, there is a high chance (I'd say 90%), you will not gain any reputation here (or get an accept 5 days after and that's it). Unless it takes you 5 minutes to answer (generally when it's a complicated subject, but you are an expert in this area), it's best to move on.

Comment: I'm not sure we should be _encouraging_ answers posted in a few minutes, nor as quickly as possible after the question is asked - both may result in poor quality answers. Your last point doesn't concur fully with my experience: sometimes a great answer posted several days later than the others will cause the OP to switch the acceptance over, and it will attract upvotes. Moreover, the unicorn rep is nice 'n all, but it should not be the sole driver of using the site - genuinely wanting to help is a better motivation, imo.

Comment: @halfer: All of it comes from my personal experience on SO. I am not saying this is the way how it should work. But unfortunately, I learnt it the hard way. Somebody better versed with MATLAB and other tools can calculate correlation matrices, do cluster analysis and such, based on real Q/A data from different users. But I am mostly sure they will come up to the same ideas. Why it works like that - is another story. Regarding your "great answer several days later" example, a proof link would help. Also some stats would be nice, i.e. this case vs other cases like that.

Comment: @halfer: Think of it this way (example). To maximize your tax return, you can use numerous loop holes in the tax system. The more successful businessman you are, the more loop holes you know, or so does your accountant. And while this behavior is certainly not encouraged by government, it was, is, and will be the best way to keep money in your pocket, with taxes normally eating >50% of your income. Now the question is, if you know such a loop hole, would you use it yourself? (Knowing that other people use it and benefit from it) Would you share this information with anyone?

Comment: `:)`. Heh, I smiled at your tax example, but I don't think it is a good analogy for reputation on the site. There's no limited supply of "money" and it cannot be "spent", so why hoard it? Admittedly it is intriguing to achieve rep milestones (e.g. 10K mod tools) and it can be helpful as an real-life online CV, but after that, I don't recommend worrying about it too much.

Comment: _I am not saying this is the way how it should work_ - if you mean that you believe you yourself are operating outside the spirit of the thing, then write a proposal to change how the rep system works, or comment on an existing one. (e.g. I am interested in removing reputation awarded from closed questions - I think that might help reduce the amount of quick-draw easy-rep answers that you describe).

Comment: @halfer: Thanks for your support, but I tried to suggest a feature here several times, from a very simple one to a very complex one. None of them were ever implemented, even though a simple one would take like 1hr of development time. Some got upvoted, some got downvoted, but no action taken to date. If interested, see my stackexchange meta account (this is where my suggestions ended up after migration).

Comment: @halfer: And yeah, I am not "operating" as much as I used to - you can see my profile. Partly because of the broken spirit. I see people still providing good answers, but [it's not the same thrill](http://www.releaselyrics.com/9e85/blake-shelton-same-old-song/).

Comment: [Sometimes late answers *do* pay off](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15192/installing-raspbian-from-noobs-without-display/19928#19928)

Comment: @PeterMortensen: I'm sure one can find some statistics to prove a point that bigger part of reputation comes from "quick draw" answers. People often like to use Jon Skeet as an example, so [here it goes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28254567/897326) - 9min accepted answer, 54 upvotes, and btw, this was 2 days ago. Not saying that old school doesn't work, it's just not as efficient to "farm" rep.

Answer (score 17):

I stumbled on this Q&A and was surprised (or honored :)) to find me quoted in the accepted answer.

I feel I can share my experience in a detailed answer that I had written earlier but seemed to be off-topic for the question so I deleted it.

I think it will be more on topic here, and won't hurt people into thinking I'm providing techniques to accumulate rep unfairly. This still requires a lot of work on the site, and it's certainly not designed to game the system (I deleted some upvoted answers because they were wrong, so no, reputation is not the ultimate goal, it's just a consequence of being helpful)

A few hints to get started & get some reputation/badges on SO. Those are "techniques" I used, but I feel that those aren't gaming the system and are fair.

**On the new questions:**

- You need to be *ahead*. Being to be one of the first to read the new questions is a real must have (to answer newer questions on popular tags like python, java, C++, C). That means you have to spend a lot of time on the site, or frequently check new questions all along your day.
- To be ahead, tune your filters to avoid seeing all questions. You won't be able to follow, and you cannot know all the languages/technologies.
- Don't lose time answering crap questions. A question with a score of -4 is very likely to be closed / ignored. You'll waste your time, and won't even get an acceptance from OP who doesn't have a clue (you might get 1 upvote, maybe or some downvotes). And in the meanwhile, you're missing better questions.
- For some questions, you have to be a FGITW (be the fastest to answer), but your answer must be *spot on*. So stay sharp and drink coffee (with a straw so you can keep on typing)
- For some questions, it's better to comment, ask clarifications, leave other FGITWs answer (and do it wrong because they actually didn't *read* the comments). While all bad answers are being posted, hone yours, make it better/more detailed/more performant than the others and post it afterwards. The combination of "a lot of comments" then "an answer" is appreciated by followers, because you took your time before answering properly.
- Don't answer obvious duplicates. Instead, vote to close / hammer them if you can. You'll be punished by some (specially if you have a high reputation) by answering. You should know better. Instead, you can answer the "original" question if you feel something is missing. I did that once, and my answer now has a +10 score.

**On the old questions:**

- There's a "new answers to old question" review queue. I think that's where I got my first +1, because I added a above average by answering to an old question and I was a newbie so someone wanted to encourage me.
- Of course if you're a specialist of some obscure/less popular tags (like Ada) you'll get upvotes on older answers by followers of those tags / people who have the "active" setting in SO page to see not only new questions, but active ones (which is impossible to follow on the popular tags BTW)

**On any question**:

- Once you posted, edit your answer to add details. If it's already good, you can get upvotes, but enhancing it makes it "active" again, and if it's better you may get more upvotes.
- *Answer the comments* made on your answers. Some commenters upvote if you answer them (better: edit your answer to take their questions into account if worth it). Plus it means that you *care*.
- If you feel it's wrong, delete it, edit it, undelete it. You'll save a stray downvote.
- Upvote concurrent answers if they're good (you'll even get a "sportsmanship" silver badge for that eventually). It creates a gap between your score and the other(s) answers, which isn't necessarily bad. Some may even think that yours have not enough votes // the others and that could even play your way (don't do that just to achieve that result, though)
- If the question is bad, but you still want to help, you can comment on what's wrong. Doesn't hurt, and you'll get known as a nice fellow.
- Don't answer like you would comment. If you don't feel like answering, then don't, and just comment.
- Also *upvote the good questions*. That'll make them visible, only if it's worth, not to indirectly promote your answer. A lot of people forget to do that. Good questions need love too.

A bonus: by keeping a spotless behaviour (asking for precisions in comments, be reactive to comments, helping some users with typo questions by commenting on the error "for free", not answering turds, not answering obvious dupes, closing as duplicates with a small personal note to the OP, creating excellent answers,being nice most of the time :)) you may get unrelated upvotes: people wanting to upvote you twice (not recommended, but not serial voting yet), people visiting your profile and finding other good stuff you wrote in the same style and upvoting it)

Asking (good) questions & answering on meta also proves that you care for the site, not only for the rep. That can have strange effects (I frequently get downvotes on my questions after posting on meta, but upvotes on some answers at the same time!!), but globally it has a positive effect on your "reputation" (the one you don't measure with points). Can't hurt.

Answer (score 15):

Gaining a couple of reputation points is not all that hard if you know enough about a certain topic. Just filter for it and start helping people out. A lot of times there is plenty of stuff to add, even if a certain question is answered. Elaborating on a very old question is a good way to earn reputation points and improve Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange. Once you have those 10 reputation points you can edit and improve your own answers with more links.

If there are no more questions you can answer or improve and there are no more questions you can ask, then I'm wondering why you want to get started here. If you can not improve there is no reason to get started. On the other hand, I'm a novice hobby programmer, and I can still help out people here and earn some reputation points when I am active enough. I am sure everybody with some knowledge can improve Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange.

Finally, this site is about putting up good questions with good answers attached to them and not about earning reputation points or some kind of reputation points challenge. Just start, gaining the first 10 reputation points is a cakewalk and from there you can do everything Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange is intended for.

Answer (score 11):

**Edit question, +2 each time suggested edit is accepted => 25 edited questions for reaching the magic 50 threshold**

Fact is if your domain of expertise is C++ or Java or any super well known domain , it is almost impossible to find a good enough question not answered/accepted, and if you pick up the newest, it will be answered before you have sent your  response.

But there are thousands of questions out there that can be improved. Most of them have some Tags missing or some Tags not relevant.
Somes can be improved to help understand the issue.

Comment: Many people are answering their own questions, and approaching SO as a gang sport. Improving the questions, answers and tagging of others is admirable and Socratic, but will not do much for your fantasy social credit nerd score (SO rep).

Answer (score 4):

> I was full of excitement and vigor and immediately tried to upvote (nope!) and post a comment (nope!).

That's indeed the main problem with the blessed site of Stack Overflow. People take this site as fun, as a game, as anything but sharing knowledge.

So, I'd tell you how to *really* start.

- Register.
- Start answering.
- **NEVER read the question body**, but only tags and title
- Write an [answer that just *looks* like a good one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23503224/285587) (preferably just [copy and paste some code snippet from manual](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23545676/285587), or [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23563772/285587), if you want to bring some explanation along), but has no real relation to the problem.
- Get deserved and hard-earned upvotes a ton
- Don't be afraid of getting some downvotes - as long as your answer looks like a good one, the only downvote you can get from someone who have a clue and time to bother, but such people *are* scarce. Yet for every downvote you will get a comforting upvote - this site is for fun and happiness - remember?
- Start your desired "activity" with votes, comments and unicorns. That's the real fun and purpose of this site.

Enjoy!

Comment: I can't tell if this is a "good" answer or a "bad" answer. It has elements of both `:P` Also, why so much hate for this one user?

Comment: This is called "sarcasm".

Comment: I'm fully aware that it's sarcastic, I'm just not sure how helpful that is `:/`

Comment: Surely this answer is bad, or even evil, as it is not about happiness and unicorns and contains no funny image. And it hurts reader's feelings, which is the deadliest sin on Stack Overflow

Comment: Would you like to make use of [the rant tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rant)? Or perhaps a `[troll]` tag? `;)` Or perhaps the [`mad-as-hell` tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254132/mad-as-hell-tag) `:)`

Comment: I would rather prefer to make use of [tag:common-sense] tag, which usually doesn't require such explicit tagging at all.

Comment: "Surely this answer is bad, or even evil, as it is not about happiness and unicorns and contains no funny image. And it hurts reader's feelings, which is the deadliest sin on Stack Overflow " - so you've finally decided to switch the sarcasm off then, and make a stark realisation. Good stuff. Sarcasm isn't usually a very effective medium on the internet, BTW, and not usually deemed helpful in any culture anywhere. If you genuinely don't realise you're a troll, let me clear that up for you; you are.

Answer (score -5):

Apparently my old advice was SO bad, it wasn't even good, it was just bad.

So, here is what NOT to do under any circumstances:

**1.** Write 'Any help would be greatly appreciated' at the end of each question, because that's obvious.

**2.** Do what I did, and pretend that someone's comment was helpful just to influence them into re-upvoting your question, even if it does give you better rep. Stand up for what you really think! It's better for the community.

**3.** Ask a question that you haven't researched, especially one that has a good answer on the very same website (you might embarrass yourself, or make people unreasonably angry).

Here is what you *should* do:

1. If someone answers well regarding a piece of code, but you realise that what you posted was a much simpler version of what you're actually attempting, and you now want active help for your HARDER piece of code, just post another question instead of editing your old one. It's not cheating! Someone told me this and said my EDIT was a completely different question, and more people would notice it if I dedicated it to a new question.
2. If programming, then post your precise error - it's easy to do, and it's really hard to get any sympathy without it.
3. Be concise with your English. It makes a difference: e.g, 'it is important to note that I have already tried X, Y, and Z' could be said as 'I have already tried X, Y and Z'. Or, 'overly complicated' could be said as 'too complicated'.
4. Also, don't include anything that DOESN'T help people answer your question. For example, backstory. No-one cares. This is an exaggeration, but e.g, 'I've been doing this really hard project at this workshop with an old version of X and we're not allowed to use imported modules for some reason, other than X, and it's taken me ages and I feel like I'm missing something totally obvious; lots of people I know seem to have managed it just fine, but by the way, I was never *quite* sure if it would be better to do X, Y, Z' will probably alienate your audience. Also, don't say 'I'm really a beginner, I only started python X months ago', because you may as well say 'I don't know anything, I'm so sorry, I'm completely wasting your time'. It's not going to make people answer your question any better.

Comment: I'm trying to decide how much of this answer is sincere and how much of it is sarcasm...

Comment: @Stijn Halfway through reading the answer I was convinced it was entirely sarcastic.  Having reached the end, and then looked through the author's post history a bit, I'm sad to say I think it is the opposite.  I think that's worse, although that's hard to say.

Comment: Sorry guys; my wording was a bit over-the-top so I've toned it down. I don't mean to come across as sad/green/naive, even though I do, and I don't do sarcasm because it's really hard to convey tone-of-voice across the internet. Yes, I really believe everything I said! That's only SLIGHTLY worse than if it had all been sarcastic, @Servy. I wouldn't post an answer that DELIBERATELY acquires 9 downvotes! In my opinion, the original question was good, and my answer wasn't THAT bad.

Comment: @LauraCookson Your answer is pretty bad.  This is all *awful* advice.  The problem isn't how you worded the suggestions, the problem is that all of the suggestions are inherently bad things to do.

Comment: I'm only going to "nag," for lack of a better term, on one point for the moment for lack of time: For your point 1, that's completely opposite of the current community guidelines. That would be unnecessary noise that is not at all crucial to your question. Yes, you're grateful. Yes, you're trying to be polite... We do that kind of thing with upvotes and accept votes around here. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts on MSE for more info.

Comment: I lied, I'll touch on point two as well. Your questions and their answers aren't just for you, they're for everyone who comes to the site later to look for a solution to the same problem. If you lie about what worked for you, you may very well end up creating confusion and frustration for someone down the line who finds your post and tries what you said was a "helpful" answer when you really feel the suggestion does not help at all.

Comment: Fair enough. If I deleted the answer, would it get rid of the bad impression I've just left? Is that bad practice? That was my first answer, so I'm not that surprised that it was terrible. Ok, I am, but only a little.

Comment: Deleting a badly received answer is an OK thing to do. (You'll even get a [badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure)!) Don't worry too much about the impression though. We vote on the content of a post, not on the person who posted it.

Comment: Well, keep in mind that anyone with 10k rep will still be able to see anything you delete here- Nothing is ever _deleted_ deleted, just soft deleted. Also keep in mind that on Meta, votes do not affect your rep. So if the negative "rep" is what you mean by that "bad impression," it won't actually affect anything. Cleaning up bad or incorrect answers is never a bad idea. You may decide to leave it up to show what _not_ to do in this case, if you wish, or you may decide to research what was wrong with your points and explain _why_ they're wrong. That's up to you.

Comment: As a side note, I do encourage you to try to look into your points and see where the community feels you're wrong. You can learn a lot about the site that you never knew this way. :)

Comment: Thanks @Kendra. I left up the bad advice and tried to add new, good advice. It can't be worse than my old advice.

Comment: Your answer looks a lot better, Laura! I reversed my vote. This is a much more useful answer now. :)

Answer (score -10):

I believe answering those questions which you feel comfortable with. Favorite tags will present you specific set of questions.

However, if you genuinely feel an urge to answer a question out of knowledge or interest, then you can go ahead. Don't worry about an up vote or reputation. If you are engaged in a programming language, you yourself got some errors at that particular time, but you resolved it with the help of Google or Stack Overflow. Try to answer such questions, which you are very sure of.

I don't think it is necessary to answer on a daily basis. Unless and until it's within your helping range, don't go for it.

Answer (score -18):

You should first ask yourself *why* do you want to join this community.

Figure out weather this is a community you want to be part of. Spend some time and research the type of people that are active contributors here (especially the elitists that run this site). Make sure you take your information from sites that are not under the stack exchange umbrella, since the content of those sites is moderated.

In hindsight, that would've made a huge difference, at least in my case.

So, to sum up and answer your question, the first thing a new user that wants to join stackoverflow should do is to understand what he's getting into. Failing to do so will result in a lot of wasted hours.

Comment: A thoughtful downvote because while overall I cannot but agree with you, your overal tone is ... not very constructive. In my opinion it *is* the moderation that makes Stack Exchange sites better than your average discussion forum. "Questions and answers, no chitchat" and stuff like that -- a good thing. Calling the people who attempt to keep the quality high "elitists" is not a good thing.

Comment: @usr2564301 I'm not calling them elitists because they *attempt to keep the quality high*. I was suggesting reviewing content such https://sergworks.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/why-stackoverflow-sucks/ before deciding weather you want to be part of the community or not.

Comment: @usr2564301 The elitists also don't seem to be very concerned with moderating the content of their own. See https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505120/pnuts for a concrete example. Seems like from a certain rep count on, the quality standards become irrelevant and you are no longer subject to moderation.

Comment: I neither see the point of linking to a certain profile (because I do not see **whether** something is wrong with that), nor of linking to an 8 year old blog post, nor of raising the question of "why?". But honestly, I never understood the question here in the first place. I just wrote some answers where I (thought that) I could make valuable contributions, and ... there we go. Started. That's it. Why? I have no idea. Hubris, probably.

Comment: @Marco13 And that's ok. Keep on answering :)