# How does an intermediate programmer find questions of his or her skill-level to answer on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I am a relatively inexperienced programmer, but I feel that I'm semi-competent in:

- Java
- Android
- General software development principles

I am very grateful for the help on Stack Overflow and want to give back to the site by answering basic questions. How can I find questions to suit my experience level as most I find are too complicated for me to answer?

Comment: i suggest using tags and lurking :-)

Comment: Have you tried clicing on stackowerflow logo in topleft corner of the page?

Comment: Favorite your most used tags and just hang around.

Comment: Related: [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252149/456814). Also, "Want to help others, can't find questions?...How can I find questions to suit my experience level as most I find are too complicated for me to answer?" Gain enough rep, and sooner or later you'll be changing that to "How can I find questions to suit my experience level as most I find are too ***simple*** for me to answer?" `:P`

Comment: "I...want to give back to the site by answering basic questions." That might actually ***do more harm than good***, in terms of the long-term health of the site. I don't know. It's questionable. See [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/456814). You're basically signing yourself up for camp #3 ("rep addicts") `:/`

Comment: Reputation seeking aside, there are many "new programmer" mistakes that show up in questions over and over, and good work can be done explaining those in comments and/or matching them as duplicates against existing questions.  Occasionally you'll have an opportunity to post an answer tailored to the specific problem too.

Comment: @ChrisStratton see, maybe we really should [give rep for finding duplicates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90620/163250). I know that's being talked about in some question around Meta right now too, but I don't remember which ones off the top of my head.

Comment: @Cupcake - I'm very hesitant to jump on board in any scheme to offer reputation for meddling with the site; it's too likely to be abused in the way the trivial edit points are.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best bet would be start looking for some question tagged with the technologies you are used to like [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and/or [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android). Filter the questions you think you can answer by their title. Read the content of the question. If you think you know you can answer it, then provide an answer and wait for other users to upvote (if they think it is correct) and for OP to accept it (if indeed is the most exact answer). Improve the answer if necessary.

From my own experience on the site, I can give some recommendations:

- Make sure to follow [stackexchange rules when providing an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118582/182862).
- Be aware of how you [answer a homework-like question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10811/182862). At least I do not want to create new zombie leecher coders/programmders/developers/software engineers. There are lot of them around =\
- There are questions that may look like [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/182862). Before try to answering them, provide comments to understand what's the real problem of OP and try to address to that problem.
- Sometimes OP is new to the site or doesn't know how to accept an answer. Provide a comment linking to [this great explanation about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/182862). This doesn't mean OP should accept your answer, do it in order for OP to accept the best or the most accurate answer to his/her problem.

Comment: Thanks! I will start doing that, btw what is the diff between meta stack overflow and stack overflow?

Comment: @RNI2013 Look at the "help" link in the top bar for an introduction to whatever site you're on.