# How do active answerers find questions to answer?

Tags: discussion

Last month, [more than 35,000 users](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/193759/how-many-unique-answerers-per-month#graph) submitted at least one upvoted answer on Stack Overflow. It's an inspiration to see how many people are out there willing and able to help fellow devs be more productive. Altruism is real — it’s what makes this community so special and the platform so powerful.

But while public data makes it pretty clear ***who*** answers, we’ve found ***how*** you answer to be quite personal, and we’re fairly uninformed about the ways in which you discover questions that you choose to answer. Thus: this quick survey.

Please take a moment to help us understand what’s going on inside your head. **Let us know in an answer how you typically find questions to answer.**

**Please only upvote others’ responses if their answer-flow resembles yours.**

Questions to consider:

- How do you discover Stack Overflow questions you can answer?

  - Do you use tag filtering? If so, how many tags do you have in
    “favorites”?
  - Do you navigate to “newest”, “featured”, or “unanswered” tabs on the
    Questions page to find questions to answer? Another page?
- Does progress towards a badge or other milestone influence your choice in questions to answer?
- Do you answer within the same session that started with a web
  search?
- Do you use any third-party apps to help you find questions to answer?

What else can you tell us about how you discover questions to answer?

We know [similar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44739/166581) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129964/166581) have been posed before, but they're mostly instructive (and old). This is personal. Help us improve surfacing the content you want to see by telling us a little bit about how you answer.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Jaydles I removed my comment when I realized that I really don't care anymore. If SO staff hasn't already figured out what needs to change based on the suggestions presented in MSO discussions, a survey isn't going to help. The site has become an endless moderation chore and frankly, not worth visiting. I hope that changes someday. Farewell.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins, I can sympathize with your frustration, and hope you'll keep an open open mind as we dig into this. If you want evidence that we care about figuring out the best way to address this, and are taking your suggestions seriously, look no further than this post.  We're soliciting more details on users' current workflows to help us figure out the best way prioritize ways to help improve that experience. You can't possibly really argue that our asking for more input indicates we **don't** care.

Comment: Naive question: Can't this problem be solved via analytics? I know when I'm on SO I'm almost always logged in. People taking the time to answer many questions don't often do so anonymously, do they?

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham, we're doing that, too, but it has two challenges: 1) Most of our tools don't work as well for reverse funnels (going from a later event to an earlier one), and 2) Even when you can tease out the majority case, it may well be that the majority of answers are from one-time answerers who drown out the power-user activity we want to understand.  You can obviously then filter for that too, but one power-user description sometimes saves a thousand queries (or at least helps explain their results...)

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham What Jaydles said. Also: third-party apps & unknown unknowns.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253310/1065197

Comment: I predominantly use the favourite tags, but don't like it that they appear below the community bulletin and careers (usually off my screen), hence this post asking for them to be moved up the right hand panel: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251763/move-favourite-tags-above-the-community-bulletin-careers

Comment: Something I dislike was my initial inability to comment. As well as this, people had been answering the questions in the comments and the questions were still  marked as unanswered.

Comment: "*Altruism is real*" - You are living in a dream-world, young man.

Comment: "Please only upvote others’ responses if their answer-flow resembles yours."  ??  If someone makes me aware of a better approach than the one I've been using, I shouldn't tell anyone else?

Comment: @JensG On altruism, I present to you [a Radiolab broadcast](http://www.radiolab.org/story/103951-the-good-show/). Personally, I help people on SO now because I was helped as a lurker for years. If I help, others are encouraged to do likewise. One day, I might need the help of one of those people. SO is self-preservation.

Comment: @WGroleau: in that case you've now switched answer flows and you upvote your new flow. :-)

Comment: Answering questions (for me in C#) has heavily plateaued over the years. I can barely find a question to answer. Mostly because it's so spread out. It could be about WPF, Neduino, anything. With C# as my primary search tag the number of questions I get are enormous, but worse off is that I find some `plz help on windows phone question` type newbie question and I can't stand the way it's written so I'll edit it. But REALLY I really need a better way to find questions I can answer. I want my 20k rep! :)

Comment: @samthebrand are you guys working on this still? Every answer below andrew's is all about how us guys have gained good rep back in the old days but we're all plateauing now into `can't-answer-because-overwhelmed` mode.

Comment: @samthebrand are you also interested in the opposite? When I ask a question, I sometimes find it hard to find somebody answering it, because they are in tags that aren't very active or worse: a combination of such tags. From a handful of views, there's often only an up vote, a comment or edit - but no answer. Die badges influence that? Sure they do: I always hope that my question would not potentially give me another tumbleweed badge.

Answer (score 128):

Overwhelmingly, just by looking at the default [SO home page (Top Questions / interesting)](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting).

Comment: Agreed, with an extensive set of favourite tags to cover the majority of the questions I'm likely to answer (a self-fulfilling prophecy since I very seldom go elsewhere to find questions to answer).

Comment: Sadly, the tag pages are so full of crap that we kind of *have* to use the homepage.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: I do this, and then go to my top 2 or 3 tag pages when I can't find something good on the home page.

Comment: Poll-style questions like this are tricky, because I want to upvote all of the answers that are good and present interesting approaches. But then I *also* want to signify which method I personally use, which would theoretically require voting for *only* that answer, otherwise the results would be skewed. Anyway, all of that to say, this is precisely what I do, too.

Comment: Alas, I faved "java" and "python", and it's still like more than half of the homepage. /_\

Comment: This, combined with sporadically looking at the newest page of a few tags and, if I really feel like it, browsing the featured tab to see if the cowboys skipped a question and it would be possible to formulate a good answer.

Comment: I think it's the best approach *if your interests and expertise are popular*. Otherwise, you can skim through a few pages without finding a relevant question.

Answer (score 115):

The majority of questions I answer I discover via a custom tag search (long URL starting with `/questions/tagged` and loads of tags joined up with `+or+`) to be notified of new posts in tags I am interested in. I look almost exclusively at the 'newest' tab of that view, relying heavily on the live-refresh feature. My current filter page is:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+or+python-3.x+or+python-2.7+or+python-imaging-library+or+python-2.6+or+python-2.x+or+python-module+or+python-requests+or+python-c-api+or+python-2.5+or+python-3.2+or+python-multithreading+or+subprocess+or+python-c-extension+or+python-2.4+or+python-import+or+python-extensions+or+plone+or+zope+or+zodb+or+pyramid+or+buildout+or+python-3.3+or+python-3.4+or+flask+or+python-internals?sort=newest&pageSize=50
```

which won't even be accepted by the search box anymore. Together with the [official keyboard shortcuts](https://stackapps.com/questions/2567/official-keyboard-shortcuts) this makes for very efficient access to new posts.

In addition, I use RSS feeds to track specific, not-so-popular tags where you don't have to be FGITW to stand a chance, as well as bountied posts. The tags in question are for OSS projects I have a stake in and care about support for.

Last but not least, I use [StackPop](https://stackapps.com/questions/4523/stackpop-stack-exchange-meets-os-x-notification-center) to get comments and track reputation changes. I used to use [Newt](https://stackapps.com/questions/1993/newt-question-answer-and-comment-and-rep-change-notifications-for-mac-os-x), which also notifies you of new question titles when I don't watch the filter page above, but is sadly under-maintained and no longer works.

Overall, I track 35 tags with these tools.

Progress towards a badge doesn't influence me as much anymore as it perhaps used to; although the current [tag score script breakdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226681/tag-scores-are-not-updated-and-the-issue-is-getting-worse) has made me watch the progress towards tag badges a little more, rather than less, using [an excellent JS script that queries the API](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/178114/148310).

If I do find posts via a Google Search and find I have to contribute something, I won't hesitate to post in that same session. But most of my answering happens via discovering new questions via the filter page.

Comment: Oh, so that's how I can do an `or` instead of an `and`. Suddenly, tag navigation will be much easier.

Comment: At least for me when having the `+`'s in the url in combination with one of the `c++` (properly encoded as `c%2b%2b`) tags completely wreaks havoc with the search/filter. It works with spaces instead of `+`s though. (On Firefox 29 that is).

Comment: There is also a possibility to use tags with stars. Like [python\*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python*) or [\*python\*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*python*)

Comment: @user3075942 yup, but when they are expanded you quickly expand beyond the limits set on the number of tags supported by the search.

Comment: I also use the tag filter to remove questions related to tags I follow but outside my area of knowledge. I follow PHP but don't answer Drupal questions so I filter them out.

Comment: I only recently discovered the tag/url method that Martijn mentions. If it wasn't for this, I would have left last month :-) I'm surprised there isn't a better way to set up such a feed (that doesn't involve manual url hacking)

Comment: @Disco3: You can use the search box: `[python] or [python-3.x] or [python-2.7] or [flask]`, but the text box has a lower limit than what the URL will take.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters, I meant a better way for that to be your default view (rather than the existing tabs of Interesting, Featured, Hot, etc...). I know my tags are highlighted, but there are so many other posts now, they get completely swamped on those other tabs.

Comment: @Disco3: I've posted a [feature-request to make it easier to create AND/OR tag searches](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231693/137096).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: "keyboard shortcuts" looks very promising. I've abandoned attempts to use keyboard-only navigation on websites long time ago. But it seems that the "shortcuts" might just work for a highly structured site such as StackOverflow. Thank you for mentioning it.

Comment: This is exactly what I do as well - custom link to my favourite tag set, sort by newest.  I usually only ever end up at SO via google when searching for an answer to a question; definitely not when looking for questions to answer.

Comment: I do exactly this, although I have two or three different URLs configured as favourites. That lets me browse different categories depending upon my mood.

Answer (score 57):

I don't answer as often as I once did but I've got a few different ways that I find questions to answer.

My process is typically:

1. I check the Interesting tab on the homepage - since I've got tags favorited the questions with these tags are highlighted. This allows me to decide based on question title if I want to read the question
2. Favorite tags. I've got about 25 tags that are favorites.  I'll browse the "Newest" tab in those to see if there are any questions that I want to answer.  Sometimes I'll search on multiple tags if there is a specific topic I feel like answering.

Badge progress was something I previously used to decide if I was going to answer questions but I don't really pay much attention to that now.

Comment: I could copyNpaste your answer as mine :)

Comment: This is similar to my process as well, but I have a few more favorite tags.  I set the home page to show more questions than the default, and I'll scroll through it a couple times a day to see if anything catches my eye.

Comment: I have only 9 favorite tags. One problem for me is that I have 3 groups of tags: **Threadgroup**: Threads / multithreading / thread-safety / race-condition **Compilergroup**: compiler, compiler-optimization, **Languagegroup** c++, c++11, c++1y.

I have yet to figure out how to say "Questions must have at least one of the first or second group and at least one of the third group".

Answer (score 42):

**Step 1**: Open new tab in Chrome.

**Step 2**: Click on modified Stack Overflow bookmark, which sends you directly to the Newest [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) questions.  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=newest&pagesize=15)

**Step 3**: Find a [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) question which seems somewhat answerable but isn't *so* absurdly basic that it has or will soon have 7+ answers on it.  (e.g., *WHAR IZ MAI NULL POINTERZ?!!!?!1!?1!/1?!??one*)  If you don't see one, go directly to *Step 6*.

**Step 4**: Answer question.

**Step 5**: Cry, because in the time it took you to type up a detailed answer to the question, it's already fallen off everyone's front pages and you will now only garner like two upvotes for it.

**Step 6**: Close Stack Overflow tab and do some of your actual day job.

**Step 7**:  Repeat.

---

When I first became a Stack Exchange user a couple of years ago, badges and points fueled a certain obsession with the site.  But now, really, I just come because I find it interesting and like to occasionally help out.  For that reason, actually, the Code Review beta is a bit more suited to my style (slower paced Q&A cycles, less ridiculous competition, more focused on helping individuals rather than just gaining rep and whatnot, much less hostile to new users).

Comment: This steps sound absolutely familiar because they are my routine too.

Answer (score 34):

**TL;DR Ain't nobody got time for that**

I don't search for questions to answer anymore.

But I do sit on the home page top questions list refreshing occasionally, opening the top few in the list and down voting and voting to close them.  With good reason of course, the vast majority of questions on this list are absolute rubbish.

Sometimes very rarely I'll see a question that's reasonably well written and within my expertise and I'll answer that.

Answer (score 24):

I don't consider myself an "active" answerer anymore. Nowadays I'm mostly a chatroom regular. But nevertheless, I still post about once a month.

Like a lot of other users, I'm only interested in answering good questions. But those are extremely rare and are completely drowned out in the ocean of low-quality homework dumps and "give teh codez" questions. And sorting through all the junk will wear out my patience.

So the goal is: **Find a good question in as little effort as possible.**

1. I configure my favorite tags to what I want. These along with my past activity does a great job of filling my front page with stuff that's relevant to me.
2. I setup an auto-refresher on the homepage at a 30 second interval. I then dedicate half a spare monitor on the side.

Then I just go about my day. Whenever I feel like it, I'll glance over at the homepage and scan to see if there are any interesting titles. If there is, I'll click on it.

I don't waste my time downvoting and closing crap. In fact, I don't even click on them. They're usually obvious from the title. If the title is [*absolutely hideous*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23642590/please-c-urgent-help-please), I'll click on it to see if I can get any entertainment value from it. But definitely not with the intention of stomping on it.

---

What I don't do:

- I don't use the live updates on SO. It takes a click - too much effort. And then I'm presented with all the crap that I'm trying to avoid. Sure, I don't win FGITW anymore, but that's okay since I stopped playing that long ago.

I know very well that I'm not helping with the moderation situation by avoiding all the low quality questions. But if I don't avoid them, I'll be forced away from the site like many already have.

Comment: Live refresh + official keyboard shortcuts is *great*. No click required, a quick hit on (*translate muscle memory to actual key reference*) `F` to get the latest posts loaded, followed by judicious use of `J`/`K`/`U` (navigation) and `Shift-ENTER` to open posts in a new tab.

Comment: I've thought about using keyboard shortcuts as well. But that requires tasking over to my browser and to the correct tab. Whereas with a refresher, I can let it sit on the side requiring zero action on my part and no effort other than glancing at it when I want to. Which is nice since I've found questions that I ended up answering even when I'm watching a movie or playing a full-screen game.

Comment: That's where Newt comes in for me; Growl notifications in a bottom corner.

Answer (score 21):

I never go searching for questions to answer just for the sake of answering. It takes too much time. The questions I answer are found while looking for solutions to my own problem. Sometimes that means answering questions when I finally find the answer; sometimes that means asking and answering my own question.

Comment: Exactly.  It's a nice way to pick up Necromancer and Revival badges.

Comment: That is also the way I do it. It does not give many points though.

Answer (score 14):

I find questions to answer by keeping the [`/questions` page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) (sorted by newest) open in a browser. I use this page because it shows a couple of lines of question text, unlike the site home page. There are so many new questions that I usually don't even scroll that page, but just look at the first half dozen or so that I can see when I have a moment.

I have a few "favourite tags" where the question shows up in orange, and a few "ignored tags" where I really don't care about the subject (generally because of poor question quality combined with a lack of interest - for example, one of them is [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)).

I use the "newest" sort order because I don't want to be biased towards questions that everybody else thinks are worth participating in (upvote/comment/answer), and I want to see new stuff every time I hit reload.

If a question looks interesting, I'll open it in a new tab and keep it open until I'm done with it (I often have dozens of tabs open).

(All of the above only applies when I haven't become so grumpy with the overall low quality of questions that I've deliberately quit looking. This happens from time to time.)

For all the lower traffic sites (*not* SO), I have a filter set up on stackexchange.com that shows a similar list of new questions across several sites at once.

Comment: exactly this. Plus I sometimes, when no question appears and I am bored, I go to questions with nonsense titles to downvote them, leave a comment to the poster and flag them as useless.

Comment: Amen. Questions page is the best view (not only for SO but other SE sites).

Comment: This imo is the best answer to this question. Great insight, not just "do what's obvious, look at the home page all the time"

Answer (score 13):

1. Immediately after login, I click on the "C#" tag (conveniently located in my "Favorite Tags" section.
2. I then stay on the active tab, clicking to allow new questions to appear to see if anything is interesting.

   - The unanswered tab is nice, but nearly impossible to sort by newest, and doesn't auto-update.
   - Occasionally I'll look at featured to see if I know anything about the questions on it.
3. If a question has more than a few answers, especially if it has an accepted answer I just ignore it. I've likely lost FGITW and so it's not worth my time. Since C# is so broad, I also ignore the "C# + Javascript but mostly Javascript" type questions, and others involving libraries outside my expertise.
4. If a question looks answerable, I'll go ahead and answer it. If it looks like a problem question, I'll open it to check/downvote/close.

I choose questions to answer based on my perceived ability to answer them (based on the title and intro text). Progress towards a badge doesn't really affect anything. Granted, I spend all my time in the C# tag, so one could argue that all my progress goes towards it :).

My answering activity is separate from my searching/asking activity, so Google doesn't have much to do with it, and I don't use any 3rd party apps (though I'd love to see something for Windows 8!).

One feature I would really like to see is an auto-updating (even with a click) recently unanswered page (with tag filtering of course). I'd rather spend my time on questions that haven't seen a good answer yet, but don't want to constantly have to refresh. Seeing the "1 new question" bar and the (1) in the page title tells me I have something to look at!

Comment: So you *only* answer questions about C#? To me, that seems incredibly boring. I mean, I know we all specialize for practical reasons. I don't know anything about Java and *can't* answer Java questions. But most of us around here are at least bi- or tri-lingual. Even if I'm not currently working in a language, I like to answer questions about it just to stay sharp. Not to mention, by following questions, I stand to learn something I didn't know by reading other people's answers.

Comment: @CodyGray, The C# world is pretty big :), that being said, I do know C++ and C as well, and could probably answer a few questions about them. Perhaps I will try and spend a bit of time in those tags as well.

Comment: login? I don't even logout! hehe

Answer (score 11):

An overlooked way to gain well-earned reputation is to provide better answers to otherwise good questions that already have an answer.

It doesn't matter if there is an accepted answer or not, as long as you think you provide more and/or better insight into the question. Obviously, this only works if the question actually is worth answering in the first place, but there are many that are.

I have toned down my answering a lot due to the widespread frustration, but I still get upvotes on answers that I posted years ago.

In the recent weeks, I even got the first upvotes on two nearly one year old answers that had hitherto been left with no votes.

So if you don't mind playing the role of patching the holes left by other answerers, then the questions to answer can be found on the first page(s) of your favourite tags.

You just have to be patient and wait potentially many months for the votes - and accept to get fewer votes than the person who answers within a minute with a half-baked line of code.

Also notice that you will have to learn to live with your elaborate answers not necessarily getting accepted, so for this to work for you, you really should be sure that you invest that time in questions that you want to answer, for the award will be mostly in the satisfaction of having provided a better answer.

Answer (score 9):

> How do you discover Stack Overflow questions you can answer?

- I click on the giant orange [Unanswered] button
- Then I scroll down and click the language tag that I'm interested in from the "Unanswered Tags" list
- Default sort is by Newest

<sub>I swear I read (OK, OK, glanced through) through all 26 the answers and was shocked that this method wasn't already listed.</sub>

For me, this is the fastest / laziest / simplest way to view questions I'm interested in that do not have any upvoted answers (I'm not a fan of cluttering up my bookmarks).

This method of course has its downsides since the "Unanswered Tags" list does not contain all the tags I'm interested in, so I largely only ever filter by the primary language tag.

> Do you use tag filtering? If so, how many tags do you have in “favorites”?

I currently have two tags in my favorites: [wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf) (a well-known technology) and [mvvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvvm) (a less-well-known design pattern).

I never click on them because they take me to the `/questions` page which does not contain the data filtered or sorted in the way I want to see it. I want to view `/unanswered`, not `/questions`.

I would love it if you implemented [this proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169500/158605) so I could filter `/unanswered` with my "Favorite Tag" list instead of the "Unanswered Tag" list, but until then I have no use for favorite tags, or any desire to add any new tags.

Actually that's not quite true. The only thing I like about defining my favorite tags is it highlights these questions on the main page. This is the only thing that prevents me from ignoring the main page entirely.

> Does progress towards a badge or other milestone influence your choice in questions to answer?

Nope. I never memorized the exact criteria for badges, and never kept track of how close I was to reaching one. Perhaps if it was clearly displayed somewhere I may care, at least for a few badges, but overall I would not appreciate the feeling of being "harassed" with this data on a regular basis. It would have to be displayed in an easy-to-access interface and on-demand for me to use and enjoy it.

> Do you answer within the same session that started with a Google search?

No, I primarily bring up Stack Overflow anytime I feel the need to take a break from my work by typing the letter "s" in my URL and letting it autocomplete stackoverflow.com.

Frequently Google searches do lead me to Stack Overflow, and something may catch my eye that I want to answer. Or I may use an existing open tab to look for new unanswered questions out of laziness. But this probably doesn't occur as much as me browsing to the site by the URL.

> Do you use any third-party applications to help you find questions to answer?

Nope, too lazy to find them, set them up, and figure out how they work

> What else can you tell us about how you discover questions to answer?

I come to Stack Overflow for two reasons: To find answers to my questions, and to provide answers to other people's questions.

Also, I primarily work in a single language, so I don't care about almost all the other language tags. I suspect many other developers feel the same way.

Your many filters/sorts/views are fun to browse on occasion, however I primarily want to view `/unanswered` for my specific tag(s), sorted by newest (since they typically have a higher percentage of responsive users).

I would enjoy having more one-click ways to access exactly this, without having to rely on bookmarks or third-party tools.

Comment: Basically the same for me, but I specifically look for questions that have one upvote and have been around for a few days. I hate posting a good question, then getting no responses, so I try to help people out in the same boat. I think we get this type of scenario because a question is good, but not easily answered by the people that are just looking at the home page for a quick answer/rep. Once it gets pushed off the homepage, it tends to get lost within a couple days.

Answer (score 8):

1. Tag RSS, something looks interesting and I have time
2. Occasionally hit /questions and see if anything is interesting in the first page
3. Someone pays me via my PayPal account $2000 bucks to answer their question
4. Ouiji

Pick two.

Comment: How do you get two-thousand-dollar deer into your PayPal account? I thought they only handled money.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Dude, check their API documentation.  Sheesh.

Comment: I so want to upvote this.  It makes me sad that I can't because of this: `Please only upvote others’ responses if their answer-flow resembles yours.`  I guess I'll have to go buy a Ouija board...

Comment: Will you answer my question if I ask for code to post Deer to paypal?

Answer (score 5):

I've become much more of an editor than an answerer these days, and where I have advice (or a short possible solution) I will often comment. So whilst rep is a minor motivator, I don't find it all that important. I don't keep track of badges, though I don't mind peeking at the chart when I am informed I have a new one.

I try to answer questions on the home page from time to time, so as not to get too stuck in particular topics, but otherwise it's my tag list in the sidebar that guides me what to look at. I go in cycles often based on my current work; if I've been playing around with [scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scraping), I'll lurk on that tag for a while, and will answer if I see I can help.

I sometimes will go to tags that I know are responsible for a high level of poor questions (e.g. [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)), mostly for editing, voting and comment guidance. In so doing, I sometimes find a good question and, if a comment would not be big enough for the solution, I'll add a proper answer in.

Answer (score 5):

I check 3 small (>200 questions) tags daily, and have a shot at answering everything that comes up. On that front, I wish that was a process which was easier through the iOS app/mobile interface.

Outside of that, I refresh through a few high-traffic tags now and then, but generally don't feel enough of an expert to answer anything worthwhile there.

Answer (score 5):

I keep a tab open on the newest tab for the [c++11] tag, which is the only one I currently lurk, but the set of tags I include in there has changed over time. I refresh it from time to time, but the questions I find tend to fit one or more of the following categories:

1. I have already answered that question too many times;
2. It should not be tagged [c++11];
3. It is about those damned function_traits abominations that people keep tossing around.

Sometimes I find the odd interesting one and answer that. This happens about once a day, I guess. Sometimes I don't have time for flesh out the answer I would like to, so I just leave a hint in comments in the hopes that someone else picks it up.

Recently I started finding some questions to answer by having them handed out to me in chat. For example, some loungizens will toss at me any [unicode] questions they run across that aren't obvious crap and I answer some.

Comment: But, but, how can I find the return value of a lambda?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe I'm the only one, but I **subscribe** for email alerts about my favorite tags.
These tags are low traffic (0 to 5 questions per day), so the email volume is manageable.

[image: Subscribe to tag]

I read every question I'm emailed about, and edit, vote, answer and/or try to close as it suits: my mood, my available free time, and the quality of the question.

---

If my target tags started to get higher volume, I would probably rethink this approach, but it's worked well for me for years.

Answer (score 4):

I have not found an effective way to find unanswered questions that are within my sphere of knowledge without spending lots and lots of time on it. As a result, a few of my answers are a result of such a search, but most of the time the only way I find an unanswered question which I am able to answer is when I find a question about a problem I am currently encountering, realize that it is unanswered, solve the problem and answer the question.

I really wish there was a better way that I could find questions to answer, but usually it takes longer just to find the question than I am willing to spend on it. Maybe I'm not altruistic enough. :)

I would answer more regularly if this mechanism were improved; for example, perhaps if I could opt-in to be notified about questions that still need an answer. If I could sign up to get one email per day on up to 10 questions that have been unanswered for at least a few hours and were strongly correlated to my favorite tags or my highest-rep tags, perhaps I would find some to answer.

Answer (score 4):

> Do you use tag filtering? If so, how many tags do you have in “favorites”?

Yes, although most of the time just the MySQL tag.

> Do you navigate to “newest”, “featured”, or “unanswered” tabs on the Questions page to find questions to answer? Another page?

I tend to use the newest tab 99% of the time, and occasionally the featured tab.

> Does progress towards a badge or other milestone influence your choice in questions to answer?

Not really.

> Do you answer within the same session that started with a Google search?

Sometimes, but rarely. If I have done a google search the chances are the question / answer it brings up will be from some time ago and likely already answered.

> Do you use any third-party apps to help you find questions to answer?

No.

Answer (score 4):

I wish I had more time to answer, but I spend too much time drawn into the quality control vortex.  Even when I do wish to answer, I often won't because a question does not deserve an answer due to lack of effort / basic tutorial stuff / duplicated stuff / do my homework for me.

For instance, today I was the first to spot the error in a regex question (I won't give the link).  Instead of posting an answer for some cheap rep-whoring upvote + accepted answer, I commented, downvoted and voted for closure due to typographical/reproducible because it wasn't worth anyone's time here.

When I do actually give an answer, it is one of two possibilities:

1. In one of my top knowledge tags, such as java.  So I usually do [java][-android] filters.
2. I come across an actual problem in my real work that I solve and see if I can contribute to any existing questions.  These questions may be a couple weeks old or a couple years old but if I see a hole I will relate my experiences in a new answer.

I imagine that my #2 is quite rare and may even be considered an anti-pattern for SO.

Comment: +1 for the second point. It's not that rare, I do it a couple times per (few) month(s), I reckon (not just on Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 3):

I use the "Interesting" tab on the home page. I have three tags favorited (all related), and so questions I'm likely to be able to answer are highlighted. I often avoid the questions at the very top of the page, as they're new within the last few minutes, and will likely get an answer by somebody else if I'm not very fast at typing (though I'll occasionally go for one of them anyway, if it seems interesting rather than "give me the codez").

To find questions to answer without racing, I usually look for questions in the lower half of the page that don't have answers yet (or ones with titles that stand out, without yet an having an accepted answer). The questions at the bottom of the "Interesting" page tend to be several hours old and so if they don't have an answer yet, I'm not likely to be beaten by some other answerer at the last moment. Of course, some times they have no answer because they're bad questions, but I'm happy to help the site by closing or downvoting those instead of answering them.

Answer (score 3):

**How do you discover Stack Overflow questions you can answer?**

Random. I open the site with the intention to answer something because I have some extra time or need a brain break/distraction while I think about a code problem of my own.

Sometimes I use the tag filters, but usually, I click a couple of random questions that grab my attention on the front page. Often (increasingly more common), I run out of spare time and/or dive back into my code without finding a question worth investing time into. If I have a lot of spare time, I might wade in and help someone who seems well-intentioned, but has posted a weak or likely-to-be-closed question because I feel bad that they're struggling and might get shut down for administrative reasons.

**Do you use tag filtering? If so, how many tags do you have in “favorites”?**

Yes, but not frequently. I have about 14-20 tag favorites

**Do you navigate to “newest”, “featured”, or “unanswered” tabs on the Questions page to find questions to answer? Another page?**

Barely, and only with the tag filter on. If I am looking for a question to answer, it would either be a random one off the front page, or an unanswered one from the tag-filtered list.

**Does progress towards a badge or other milestone influence your choice in questions to answer?**

It did at first, but by the time I hit 10k, I had both reached most of the milestones I wanted to and simultaneously cared less about the milestones. By that time, I considered myself a **member** of the community rather than a mostly-anonymous participant. Finding the very active (and awesome!) PHP chat was also a large contributor to the shift in my attitude.

That said, since the gold badge dupehammer rollout, I have a renewed interest in gold tag badges.

**Do you answer within the same session that started with a Google search?**

No. If I am searching Google, I'm fully engaged in working on my own stuff. I might perform a quick moderation task (flag, CV, etc) if I land on a question that needs it.

**Do you use any third-party apps to help you find questions to answer?**

No.

Answer (score 3):

Home page =>> tag ==> newest ...."click"

Sometimes I may go to the 2nd/3rd page from newest.

Answer (score 3):

I subscribe via [RSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) feeds to the tags I'm interested in. Using my favorite RSS reader ([Vienna](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vienna-rss/)) I can quickly read nicely formatted questions and am brought to the Stack Overflow page with a single click to answer.

Answer (score 2):

**What I do as an answerer:**

1. Favorite's Tag highlights the languages/areas I'm most comfortable answering. I'll scan those questions and attempt to answer them
2. If there's nothing that I can answer or the question has a good answer which I've upvoted, I go back to work.
3. If I'm really, really bored or I just need to escape for a few minutes, I'll check the bounties area or review some items.

**What I want as an answerer:**

My own custom tab that I can set as the default view. Really! I just want to have my Favorite Tags+Unanswered as one of my selections ordered as the question would appear on the "most interesting" tab.

Comment: Use a bookmark in your browser maybe, with unanswered page's long URL inside. I use that with as3 tag and I'm happy enough.

Comment: Could you expand on how you view questions from your favorite tags?  Is there a better way of doing this than what I do, a search for "is:question intags:mine"?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Oh when I say "my" I don't mean my own questions. It's just a small inconvenience to have to query for the thing I want to see all the time rather than having a custom tag backed by a custom query.

Answer (score 2):

I find questions via Google when I am working.

When I am looking to answer I look at the top of the question queue with my favorites highlighted.

Sometimes I find questions when reviewing.

Answer (score 2):

Let's get your specific questions out of the way first...

> Do you use tag filtering? If so, how many tags do you have in “favorites”?

Yes, I do tag filtering (C++ and Qt) and although I have C++ in my favorites, I don't make use of that.

> Do you navigate to “newest”, “featured”, or “unanswered” tabs on the Questions page to find questions to answer? Another page?

Almost always newest. On rare dull days featured.

> Does progress towards a badge or other milestone influence your choice in questions to answer?

Not at all. I can't even quickly think of a way it could.

> Do you answer within the same session that started with a Google search?

Rarely, see the "hot network question", "searching for a question that fits my answer" part below.

> Do you use any third-party applications to help you find questions to answer?

Nope

Now that we are done with the specifics, a little free text. Note that I can't give any hard statistical numbers, so take "often", "rarely", etc. with the appropriate grain of salt. Further note that due to my "workflow" this is not restricted to.

The majority of questions that I consider for answering are those from my browser starting bookmark: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20-qt

For the purpose of answering (ignoring the purpose of closing, etc.) there I mostly look at questions that

- Are unanswered
- Have 0 or higher score
- Have a title that makes them sound interesting. This is very subjective, and I can't really elaborate much more on this, but consider it of being the opposite of something that sounds like "do the RTFM for me" or "debug this program for me".
- Aren't about a specific API (maybe with the exception of some parts of boost)

Every few days, someone one [Freenode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freenode) ##C++ IRC channel comes and posts a link to a Stack Overflow question. Surprisingly the quality of those questions is on average much higher, so I always consider those for answering.

I do especially not use any kind of email/RSS/Android app push way to notify me about any questions.

Then there is the "hot network questions" sidebar. I always look through it, open questions that sound interesting, and sometimes answer them. Then when I don't find some questions on Stack Overflow, but I am in the mood of answering something, I go to https://stackexchange.com/questions?page=1 and scan through that longer list. Then sometimes when there are interesting questions on another Stack Exchange site, I open their questions tab and look if something sounds interesting enough.

A totally different way to answer questions is, when I found a solution for one of my problems. Here I might have done a search on Stack Overflow or google, and discovered a question with a non-fitting or no answer. Sometimes I just discovered something on my own, and then quickly search for a question on Stack Overflow.

If I find one fast enough (first couple of any kinds of search results) then I will add my new findings as an answer.

That's pretty much it. Now let me give a few words about why I **don't** answer some questions. I think this is equally important to consider, since the goal might be to get more stuff answered.

Questions that deserve no answer but close votes aside, there are a couple of questions I do not answer/touch because:

- They feel like being a duplicate and I don't have the time right now to search for a duplicate
- They are too easy. I want to be at least challenged a bit, and not merely reciting documentation from my memory.
- They deserve a more elaborated answer, but due to the [fastest gun in the west problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem), when I would be done with writing an answer that satisfies my personal quality standards, there would be already 10 answers, one accepted and everyone moved on. Don't get me wrong, I don't want to [repwhore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19522#19522), but seeing a dozen or two upvotes spent for several two liner answers, all saying the same thing like "do this instead" while I try to explain the *why* behind what to do instead, adding and researching some references, etc., then I find this effort a bit wasted, since it feels like no one will ever look at my answer. Who looks at answers that only have one upvote while there are 10 with 5 or more?

Answer (score 2):

When I was more active, I'd usually find questions using a desktop or browser notifier such as [Newt](https://stackapps.com/questions/1993/newt-question-answer-and-comment-and-rep-change-notifications-for-mac-os-x). New questions in tags I was interested in would show up for a few seconds, so I had a chance to see if anything looked interesting, and then disappear, so I wouldn't need to worry about dismissing them if they weren't interesting.

This is a much better experience than visiting the site and using a manual auto-reloader or something, but there don't actually seem to be any particularly good tools anymore. Many previous ones are broken.

Relying on the community to provide these types of hasn't really worked, and shouldn't be necessary. If good, well-designed tools did exist, I think they would would drive more participation. Stack Exchange Inc. should assume responsibility for this issue and provide official browser plugins instead.

Answer (score 2):

I've only just discovered this, but it's what I anticipate doing in future:

Search for `is:question intags:mine`

Go to Newest tab.

Answer (score 2):

I will add another partially hypothetical partially what I do answer, though it is not my main activity.

There are 2 cases where answers can be given quickly, both involving the poor practice of answer-giving in comments:

1. Promote the OP's self-answer in a comment to an answer (particularly if the OP hasn't been on the site for a while).  This can be proper SO protocol, especially if you mark the answer as community wiki which prevents you from receiving reputation from future upvotes.  See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) .  From time to time I will provide such an answer if I run across a post that needs it, but I don't look for them.
2. Promote the non OP's answer in a comment to an answer.  My highest reputation answer sort of falls into this category.  A high-rep user gave a few steps to solve the problem in a comment.  I turned it into a full answer filling in the details.  Apparently it is useful to a large number of people.  I don't know how the mods feel about actively resolving questions in this manner, but it could be away to clean up the site and gain easy rep at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

I bring up my favorite tag (actionscript-3), hit "New Questions" (not just "unanswered", since some people don't answer it well), and start going through the list. I like getting the fresh ones, because they're usually ones I can answer quickly.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many questions asked on StackOverflow that it's more a matter of filtering questions down to those that seem efficient to answer, rather than just finding questions.

I use tags heavily.  I have one high traffic tag (java), along with a number of low traffic tags which are areas where I have expertise or interest (e.g., ssl, sockets, multithreading).  I watch the java tag when I feel like racing to be the first to answer, and the other tags when I'd rather take my time.

This still results in a lot of questions that are only peripherally related to the tag, so I also look for the yellow shading that indicates a question that also has one of my tags other than the one I'm currently filtering for.

I mostly use the "newest" tab and to a lesser extent the "featured" tab, because questions in these tabs are less likely to have been abandoned by their posters.  I preferentially look at questions with no answers.

Not being a jaded 100k+ members yet, I'm perfectly willing to help people with debugging questions or homework questions as long as it's clear they've made a real effort already and are stuck.

Badges don't affect my choice of questions much, though they are influencing me to spend more time in the review queues and less on answering questions.  I don't use third-party applications to find questions.  When I find something by Google I'm usually looking for an answer to one of my own questions, so my next action is to use the answer to fix my problem, rather than to answer other questions.  Rather, I usually come to Stack Overflow to answer questions when I have a bit of dead time in my work flow - a build is running, or whatever.

Comment: It really is "Stack Overflow".

Answer (score 1):

> How do you discover Stack Overflow questions you can answer?

I browse tags and check the "new" question in tags where I have experience.

> Do you navigate to “newest”, “featured”, or “unanswered” tabs on the Questions page to find questions to answer? Another page?

I check the new ones, and sometimes the unanswered but those tend to be very old questions and/or low quality.

> Does progress towards a badge or other milestone influence your choice in questions to answer?

Not really. At 12.6K I don't *need* the karma for anything really :)

> Do you answer within the same session that started with a Google search?

Rarely, but I do sometimes use Google to find other relevant Q & A to link to in comments or answers.

> Do you use any third-party applications to help you find questions to answer?

Nope.

> What else can you tell us about how you discover questions to answer?

My skill set is pretty limited when it comes to programming, I am primarily self-taught with [VBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications) (although I think I'm pretty good with it). I have a small amount of training with Python and have done some self-tutorial stuff with JavaScript and Google Apps scripting.

Most of my answers are in VBA Q's, or Q's related to MS Office interop/etc., where my knowledge of the object model(s) can often prove helpful even if I don't know the particular language constructs.

**A lot of times I try to answer questions that I don't *know* how to answer.** In this way, I use the questions as a way to teach myself something new and expand my own knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I have about 19 favorites, but this is really more like eight topics (I have three variations on LINQ as an example), and then I just just go to the main page and look for things that haven't been answered. Or for certain topics (SQL and LINQ mostly) I will look if there are only a few answers and none have been accepted.

Oh, I guess I look a little at the title. **But the title rarely signifies anything.**