# How to auto-refresh list of new questions?

Tags: feature-request, questions

Rather than re-clicking questions, is there an option to refresh the list automatically as new ones come in?

Elsewhere on the site there is at least a notification when new comments come in or changes are made.

Comment: This *is* done everywhere else, except on the general new questions pages for Stack Overflow. The volume of new questions is far too large, you would be quickly overwhelmed and lose your place. Just refresh, it isn't that much of an exertion.

Comment: With the questions filtered the volume can be limited, auto refresh option or notification would be good I think.

Comment: Not if you have multiple top-tags selected, such as `php`, `java`, `c#` and `javascript`.. I can sit on the main page and hit F5 every 5 seconds and see new questions =/

Comment: I want to see the new question every 5 seconds. I can tell almost instantly if i want to read more, I don't need 5 seconds.

Comment: If you can scan the list in under 5 seconds, the signal-to-noise ratio is obviously far too low. Automatic updates won't solve this problem, it'll just waste more of your time. Perhaps it is time to investigate [new strategies for finding questions to answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254592/how-do-active-answerers-find-questions-to-answer).

Comment: `ctrl+r`, `F5`, `click`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like with the new site layout, this has been implemented. When I have a tab with a couple favourite tags selected, the browser title shows the new questions, as well as the tab, like so:

> (3) newest (multiple tags)

And if I'm sitting on that tab, it shows the number of new questions waiting to be viewed now, and I can just click it to reload:

> 3 new questions