# What's the best way to regularly check on specific topics?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, email

What is/are the best way(s) to keep a close watch on topics of interest?

For example, how would one make sure to catch interesting *new* threads on SO quickly and regularly with a minimum amount of action?

One can obviously check the site every day and use the search/tag functionality to browse for latest news, but I was wondering if there might be something more convenient which I just haven't yet discovered.

Is it possible to set up a "profile" of interest and get a daily digest sent via email? 
i.e. I would like to specify tags of interest and potentially some full-text search terms like I would do when being online, but would automatically get (positive) results sent to me on a regular basis.

I think such a feature would be great, if it doesn't exist yet.
Other ideas/suggestions how this can currently be handled would also be of interest to me.

Comment: Related: [How do active answerers find questions to answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254592/how-do-active-answerers-find-questions-to-answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes.**

The settings you're looking for are located under the [preferences section](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current) of your user profile.

The first thing you want to look at are Favorite Tags, which can be added from a variety of places, the most common of which is the front page:

[image: Favorite Tags]

These tags will show up more commonly in your question feed and will be highlighted a special color to indicate that they are marked with one or more of your favorite tag.

You can also add Ignored Tags, which will hide questions with those tags from your feed.

These settings can also be edited from the preferences section mentioned above.

What you're really looking for, I believe, is [advanced tag subscriptions](https://stackexchange.com/filters) on the preferences page:

[image: Advanced tag subscriptions]

When you click on that, you get something like this:

[image: Stack Exchange Advanced Tag Filtering]

This is very powerful: it allows you to set up rules and custom filters that email you under specified conditions.

If you want a general overview of new stuff on a site, you can also subscribe to weekly newsletters in the preferences section under **Newsletter settings**.

---

You can also use [advanced search](//stackoverflow.com/help/searching) and use the RSS feeds for a search to keep updated.

So, say for example that I wanted to keep tabs on questions posted in [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) without [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) or [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html). I'd search for `[javascript] -[css] -[html]`:

[image: Advanced search in action]

Now, that works great, but how can you stay updated?

At the bottom of tag search result pages is a link to an RSS feed that updates constantly with new results. You can use the feed with any of your favorite readers or you can use it with services like [IFTTT](//ifttt.com) to alert you of new content.

[image: Search feeds]

Comment: Perfect answer in shortest possible response time. You're my hero of the day! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Slight caveat with your suggestion on search & RSS feeds. I don't seem to get the RSS link at the bottom of the page as in your screenshot. I used your suggested search, get the results, but no RSS link at the bottom. (Tested on IE 11.0 and FireFox 30.0 )

Comment: Actually, there is **no RSS feed** for searches that use text. Only tag pages do. Your screenshot is for a tag page, not for the search-with-text. Your claim that there is is entirely false, I'm afraid.

Comment: See [RSS Feed for Searches?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5857), the feature request was declined.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, that is correct. Sorry about that: the answer now reflects that information.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. Going a bit in circles here, I've added a _similar_ but not identical request now: [A daily digest email based on full search](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238086/daily-digest-emails-based-on-search-profiles).

Comment: Great answer, thank you.