# RSS feed from search result missing (?)

Tags: bug, search, rss

I am following up on an earlier the [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268700/whats-the-best-way-to-regularly-check-on-specific-topics/268702#268702) suggesting to use search & RSS feeds for staying up-to-date.

The problem is, if I follow the [suggested steps](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268700/whats-the-best-way-to-regularly-check-on-specific-topics/268702#268702), I do not get an RSS link.

- Use advanced search (in StackOverflow): `[javascript] -[css] -[html] "JSFiddle"`.
- Scroll to bottom of search results
- > *At the bottom of every search result page is a link to an RSS feed...*
- **No, there isn't (** for me **) !**

I have tested this with two browsers ( IE 11.0 ; FireFox 30.0 ), but all I get is the search result page as shown below. 
Am I just too blind to find it, or what is wrong?

[image: Search result on StackOverflow]

*... (cut out the results) ...*

[image: Search result on StackOverflow]

Comment: btw, the RSS link is at the bottom here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+-css+-html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug; the feature *doesn't exist*. The answer you link to is *wrong*.

When you use a search with *just* tags you are redirected to a tag page, which has a RSS feed. If you add arbitrary text to search for, you are given the search results page and it **doesn't have a RSS feed**. Remove the `"JSFiddle"` part to see the difference.

See the [feature request to add feeds to search results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5857/rss-feed-for-searches) on Meta.SE; it was declined for performance reasons.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up.I've added a _similar_ but not identical request now: [A daily digest email based on full search](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238086/daily-digest-emails-based-on-search-profiles).