# How to explain "instant" answers? Is there a secret queue or notifications for new questions?

Tags: discussion, answers, fastest-gun

Every day I wonder how it is possible that some questions get an answer within the first minute or two?

I barely manage to read the question and there is already a notice that an answer has been provided usualy by high rep users. Is there a second secret queue for them where they can see questions before everyone else? I even had an idea for a no-high-rep-users-day so that other people gets the chance to answer something too ;-)

For some strange reason these early answers also receive often the most upvotes even if better answers are posted later.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281789/just-lost-210-reputation-my-answers-7-upvotes-and-8-upvotes-were-removed/281790#281790 Not always, but sometimes.

Comment: The truth is... some of us are just really, really sad.

Comment: There _is_ a secret queue. But no-one will tell you about it. Hey, it's secret! :-P

Comment: @LuisMendo or maybe the secret queue has been secret for so long because nobody has ever asked about it before ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t. The *real* secret queue can be found by searching for unanswered questions in your favourite tags. Time has far less relevance in that queue, because most of the questions don't have quick answers. People with an insatiable appetite for rep concentrate on easy questions with FAQ-type answers that take no time to research. Those kinds of answers also tend to get lots of quick upvotes, because they are simple for potential upvoters to agree with. If you are more interested in providing good answers than playing tedious FGITW games, learn how to search for the right questions.

Comment: There's also those people like me who will provide some sort of balance to the FGITW people: if an answer is posted and it is not an acceptable answer in its initial state, they have about 1% chance I will revert my downvote even though they added actual content inside the grace period.

Comment: Well, if it's one of those that has a simple canonical answer it'll get 1-10 answers in the first minute simply because the question gets asked several times a day.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

No, there is no secret queue.

All we do is [watch for new posts using the live socket](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254592/how-do-active-answerers-find-questions-to-answer/254603#254603), and use experience to answer posts. For a certain class of questions you can figure out the answer in seconds. Add to that good typing skills and you can rattle out a good answer very quickly.

The rest is called the Fastest Gun in the West; everyone else watching for new questions sees that answer, assesses that it is correct and votes it up. They then *move on to new questions*. Later answers then get less attention as they fall outside those first few crucial minutes.

If other answers are truly better, then over time they'll gain more of the long tail votes.

As such, you have your causality the wrong way around; high reputation is the effect, not the cause here. People that have fine-tuned the art of answering (be it fast or late with better answers) gain reputation. Stack Overflow is, in that respect, like any other online game, you get better at it with practice.

Comment: I have also seen people (repeatedly; no names here) putting in a very quick answer, *then* refining it. You could call that a variant on commenting *First!* - now with actual content ;-)

Comment: @JanDoggen: I do that too; I post a *correct* answer, then refine (add documentation links, further explanation as I gain more understanding of where the OP went wrong, etc.).

Comment: Yes, I noticed ;-) BTW thanks for that link that '+or+' in there is mighty interesting

Comment: Ok, so there is no high-rep conspiracy behind the curtain ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t: nope, just experience (which explains the high reputation you correlate with the behaviour). The reputation is the *effect*, not the cause. :-P

Comment: Yeah.  For instance, if it's a sockets question in C, I just look for the strlen()/printf(s) calls, what is done with the value returned from recv() and if the null put on the end overflows the receive buffer.  It's instinctive.

Comment: In particular, make sure not to waste time looking for duplicate questions. You'll never get high rep if you do that.

Comment: @Rawling: as a high-rep user I'm intimately familiar with the usual dupes. I hammer those shut before any FGITW can try to answer. The Python chat room maintains a [list of common questions](http://sopython.com/canon/) for this purpose.

Comment: @Rawling: So true. Sometimes a little looking can find literally dozens of identical questions, but it isn't worth doing when a quick answer can get 50 rep, easy.

Comment: It would be interesting to know how many high-rep users actually find the brownie points motivating. For my part, I have to say I find them very childish; I can see the point of knowing whether someone answering your question is knowledgeble, but I find the idea that highly qualified professionals will spend their time trying to increase their score rather strange.

Comment: I don't care and never did. I answer questions that interest me. If I get upvoted for that, that's nice, but that isn't my motivation and never has been. Unfortunately, whereas in the beginning, there were so many interesting questions that I could always just log on and pick one, nowadays, there's maybe one interesting question per month.

Comment: Thank you for not telling him about our secret high-rep queue, and perpetuating the myth that it doesn't exist. Can you imagine what would happen if that got out?? Phew, that was close. As Verbal Kint said, "The greatest trick the Devil ever pulled was convincing the world he didn't exist". And thank God that we also have our special secret high-rep user comment box as well to post messages like this in, so that only us high-rep users can read them. I'd hate to see what those lowly peons would say if they ever caught wind of this...

Comment: @MichaelKay I enjoy helping build this great resource, and that is very satisfying. However, I do find the points very motivating: they led to both of my professional software jobs -- which I had hoped when I was earning them. Many others have similar stories. :P

Comment: `If other answers are truly better, then over time they'll gain more of the long tail votes.`  That's pretty rare, actually, unless the question has high visibility or is easily Google-able.  Most Q&As are just a flash in the pan.

Comment: @asteri not in my experience. I've posted plenty of late answers that *over time* gain enough upvotes.

Comment: I am so happy you addressed the intense, and sometimes ridiculous gamesmanship that SO has spawned.  Admittedly it is a good site with useful content.  But all gameable systems sooner or later become skewed by those who want to wield power and influence over them.  I guess the overall goal is to keep the site usable in spite of all the inevitable juvenile skulduggery going on behind the scenes.

Comment: @bearvarine: Quite the opposite, in fact. This particular gameable system is becoming skewed by those who couldn't give a flying frak about the game, power or influence. They just want us to fix their sh!t immediately.

Answer (score 36):

Honestly, it's simply just because many of us sit at our desks, day in and day out, not only refreshing our email inboxes and Facebook feeds, but also our Stack Overflow front pages. When we see something uninteresting and derivative, we cannot help but answer it. This process takes mere minutes *at most*.

I realise that this may sound far-fetched, but it's genuinely the reality.

I'd like to take this opportunity to apologise to my mother for how appalling this state of affairs is and, more relevantly, the fact that I'm caught up in it at my age. Sigh.

Comment: Personally, I can read a question and start typing an answer while still reading the question. Sometimes I can answer questions correctly based on pure guesswork because the question is horribly formulated (and would be marked as "unclear what you're asking" by any sane person). This does show sometimes, where I have half an answer, then I notice something in the question and stop, often mid-sentence, put a `-----` divider, and go "Actually, do this..." and hopefully the OP will understand that their question may not have been formulated in the best way ;)

Answer (score 6):

I type slowly, but I like to provide detailed answers. Sometimes I'll post a quick-n-dirty "This is how: " and then edit it with headers, examples, and links.

Comment: FYI, this is called "Fastest Gun In The West" (or FGITW) and is frowned upon for various reasons.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, How does that match up with *"[I do NOT want to, in any way, discourage **the quick and dirty** answer](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2008/10/solving-the-fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem/)"*?

Comment: @Pacerier It doesn't. Jeff is one man, not a one man consensus. (Just look at all his astoundingly downvoted status-declined answers on meta if you don't believe me.)