# Make it easier for experienced users to find good questions to answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, user-retention

[This discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254592/how-do-active-answerers-find-questions-to-answer) occurred about a year ago but I'm not sure

I felt like answering some questions this morning and I wound up downvoting about 20 questions instead before I came here to grouse. I answered about 2. Both were still on the noobish sign which I didn't realize until I figured out the answer.

To be clear, I am not asking for how to come up with some hackish query on how to find questions interesting to me. Well, I am in a separate pending question because I happen to enjoy SO enough to spend some time hacking it to get it to work right. My question is **Why is SO making itself difficult to use for its most valuable users at all?**

I am not a UX expert or product expert. But some rubeish sections to get my point across:

- Do any ML whatsoever on what I upvote or downvote or answer to show me a curated front page. I almost get the idea that SO has determined I love downvoting so continues showing me questions to downvote, as if this is a good use of both our time. Facebook decides what friends I get to think about but SO won't decide for me what questions are worth me looking at?
- Make it clear how to build a search query. A visual UI. A wizard. A walkthrough. I'm a programmer. We both know I'm a programmer. That doesn't mean coming up with a beautiful SO question query is nearly the top of my list of things I want to do. Programmers don't like hard to use software more than anyone else.
- At least suggest to me that I *should* build a custom query. I've been happy staring at my front page downvoting and closing questions away for probably a year now. Today is the first day it occurred to me I should bother to get out of that business at all. At no point did SO even *care* that I've spent my time on the less productive functions of this site - like, the functions whose sole purpose is to help actually productive things happen - with any sort of suggestion or assistance that maybe I should be staring at better questions to answer in the first place.
- In fact, I'm *trying* to build my own query, [*but it's hard*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288924/1339987). I needed to go straight to meta for help on it.

Why the awful UX? Are answerers not actually valued? Is the user experience geared toward them at any point? Because if not, that's not sustainable.