# Why do tags suddenly disappear once I do a search?

Tags: support, answers, user-retention

I'm trying to come up with a query to find good questions to answer, instead of spending nearly all of my SO time downvoting/closing them and hoping to find any I might like to answer at all.

The front page is at least good at highlighting my tags and showing me lots of questions in my tags. But it's bad at showing me questions that aren't terrible. So I tried:

```
isanswered:no score:1
```

And went to "newest". But why is there no tag information!

[image]

So now what do I do to find questions worth answering?

Comment: The new [Recommended Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended&subtab=needsanswer&minScore=1&noAnswersOnly=on) tab. It's beta, but you can filter questions by minimum number of votes, and show only unanswered questions, in _your_ tags or tags you choose.

Comment: Isn't [this a better search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0..0+score%3A1+is%3Aq+closed%3Ano++%5Bjava%5D):  `answers:0..0 score:1 is:q closed:no  [java]`

Comment: @djechlin, could you elaborate on why you think a `[user-retention]` tag (even well-documented) would bring us more than plain `[support]`?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi "bring us" as in "bring people to come visit this question"?

Comment: @djechlin, nope :) "bring us more than *x*" as "would have a positive net effect compared to the existing *x*".

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi up to 5 tags are supported for a question, I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: @djechlin, no problem at all, I was just thinking the tag wiki for `[user-retention]` was effectively summing up the goal of any site (keep users coming), and its meaning looked redundant to me because our `[support]` tag might already be doing the job. So I was wondering why you created it, 's all :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi they're not really related at all. I suppose you could tag any support question "user-retention" to mean "answer this support question to retain me," but that's obviously a stretch. And a discussion about how to retain users would not be a support question, it would be a discussion. And user retention is a different business problem from user growth, which is a different business problem from monetizing, which is a different problem from moving 0s and 1s across the tube, so it doesn't meaningfully apply to all questions any more than those other examples do.

Answer (score 3):

If you see very carefully the screenshot, you will notice that all of them are answers and answers have no tags, that's why the search results don't show them. I believe that the `isanswered:no` is only selecting answers instead of questions which is quite puzzling, maybe a bug.

Using `is:q isanswered:no score:1 closed:0` would give you better results; all questions, without positive scored or accepted answers, which has score of 1 or more, and are not closed by any reason [which produces ~860k results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ano+score%3A1+is%3Aq+closed%3A0).

Comment: I also suggest adding `hasaccepted:no` because `isanswered` only looks at the score of answers, ignoring acceptances.