# Any way to speed up the slow-answered questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers

As a Stack Overflow user, I find that sometimes an interesting question may get an answer very fast (within one hour). But I also find many interesting questions that take a long time to get an answer (or may not even be answered).

I did some analysis on what factors impact the speed of getting answers. I analyzed around 60k questions which have at least 1 score and accepted answer from Stack Overflow and around 80k questions from other three sites (i.e., [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour), [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour), and [Super User](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#Super_User)). Basically, I find that many of the interesting questions that took a long time to get an answer are answered by non-frequent answerers (i.e., the users that answered less than five questions).

Below I share some points I observed in detail:

1. Because I find that many interesting and useful questions take a long time to get an answer, I did some data analysis to understand the potential reason. I calculate a couple of metrics, including the metrics related to the question (e.g., the length of question), the asker (e.g., the reputation, activeness), the answerer (the time to answer a question in the past, number of answers posted in the past), and the answer. Then I build a classification model where independent variables are the metrics and dependent variable is the speed of getting accepted answer for the question to understand which factors have most important contribution on the speed. **Basically, I want to see which factors are more correlated with the question answering speed.** Here is the link of the data[http://sail.cs.queensu.ca/replication/AnswerSpeedStackExchange/data.zip]. I analyze more than 40 factors that I can think of and did some statistical analysis to control for confounding factors.
2. The non-frequent answerers (i.e., the users answered less than five questions) help answer most of the slow-answered questions. The table below shows the mean and median time to answer questions.

   [image]
3. I find that the questions that are answered by non-frequent answerers are as important as the ones that were answered by frequent answerers (i.e, the users answered at least five questions), and some questions even more complex (in terms of length). The table below shows comparison of the score of the questions that were answered by non-frequent answerers and frequent answerers.

   [image]

So as a Stack Overflow user, I really want to see some interesting questions get answered faster (e.g., perhaps in days instead of weeks or months). These non-frequent answers may not be active enough to spend time on the Q&A websites in search of questions to answer. However, such non-frequent answerers are important for the community since they have their own expertise to answer some very specific questions. In additional, slow-answered questions are likely to remain unanswered if they were not answered by the non-frequent answerers (**and old questions got buried very quickly by new questions**). [Anderson et al.](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2339665) observed that the answerers on Stack Overflow are organized like a **latent “pyramid”** with active answerers at the top. Once questions are created,frequent answerers, who are active on Q&A websites, would try to answer the questions according to their expertise. However, the remaining questions would need to wait for another set of answerers (i.e., non-frequent answerers) to answer. In other words, such slow-answered questions, which probably require unique expertise, could only be answered by such non-frequent answerers.

Based on the findings, I wonder if Stack Overflow should consider improving the way of delivering the questions to the right person, e.g., recommend questions to users since most of users search based on browsing tags [how active users find questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254592/how-do-active-answerers-find-questions-to-answer). Or do you have any thoughts about how to improve this?

Comment: It doesn't take that much text to say that harder and/or more niche questions take longer to get answered...It's also not a particularly revolutionary statement to make, nor does it provide any actual useful suggestion towards improving question answer speeds.

Comment: Questions are already suggested to viewers based on their past actions on the site. Users who answer a lot of python questions get more python questions on the main page.

Comment: @servy  this is why I post more text, because if less detail, you guys complain it is lack of details and misunderstand.

Comment: For the most part, you've proven that [Stack Overflow bikesheds its problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality), and this is not a new thing.  What I don't see here is a way to solve that.  The problem is well-known enough here that I'm not hopeful that more discussion will actually expose anything new.  What we're really looking for now in regards to this issue is an actual *solution*.

Comment: @WangShaowei The solution to the problem of your questions not containing enough information to get an answer is not to fill it with irrelevant information that doesn't mean anything to the reader, it's to ensure that the relevant, important, and *useful* information is there, *without* including the relevant information.

Comment: To that point...this makes a rather large assumption.  The implicit assumption is that every participant of Stack Overflow is capable of answering a question that others would deem to be "interesting" or "complex", when that is genuinely not the case.  In spite of the enthusiasm from frequent answerers, there are going to be topics that go even over *their* heads.

Comment: Hard questions take longer to get an answer, news at eleven.  It just doesn't matter that it takes 6 minutes or 6 days or 6 months, nobody will notice that it did for the next 10 years.  SO is not a forum and not a help desk.

Comment: So....... your feature request is WHAT exactly? I don't see anything that ressembles a feature request in there.... You say "improving"... but I mean, I can open an FR and say "Make SO better!".... that doesn't make it a complete FR, or one that is actionable...

Comment: **Feature Request:** Better users please

Comment: Perhaps an "unanswered, upvoted questions in your favorite tags"  tab should be made available with one click by default. I don't think I've ever created a custom tab for myself.

Comment: I feel bad that OP actually did some analysis and got lots of downvote

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I really want to see some interesting questions get answered faster (e.g., perhaps in days instead of weeks or months).

[Hmm, yeah, that *is* a real problem. If only there were a way that we could fix that…](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065)

That said, adding a bounty is not the only way. *Always take your vitamins, eat your veggies, brush your teeth, do your homework, and upvote good posts.* High-scoring questions get much more attention than the typical [sand](//stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/).

Also consider that others might not think the question is as good as you think it is. By nature, the chance of a question being answered is approximately proportional to the number of people who care about it.