# Have I not tagged my question properly?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48092577/profiling-gpu-code-for-power-draw-and-resource-utilization) about a day ago and it hasn't received many views. This does not generally happen on Stack Overflow. Is it because I haven't tagged my question properly?

Comment: Maybe bring the actual question closer to the top and add why you have doubt about your calculation. I'm also wondering if the other questions you asked near the end (in your edit) doesn't make your question broad. Can't you somehow include the outcome of those tools in your attempt to make sense of the power consumption? The question looks very specialized and I assume only a few could answer it. That is not wrong but might help in setting your expectation right about getting views and answers. As for the tags: Looks fine to me but they are not like java, c++, php or regex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to speed up the slow-answered questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356510/any-way-to-speed-up-the-slow-answered-questions)

Comment: Your tags appear fine to me – don't change them. The domain experts will surely pick it up in a couple of days. For popular tags and titles  ('homework, plz Help ASAP' – *snigger*) comments and answers appear within minutes but a rather specialized question like yours needs some time.

Comment: Hmm, too bad I removed my earlier comment but here it is again @il_raffa: I'm not thrilled by that [duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356510/any-way-to-speed-up-the-slow-answered-questions). That  question describes a generic problem, partly as a feature request. The answer there doesn't apply here, as this question is specifically asking about their tagging.

Comment: @rene, my understanding of the question was, after all, "What can I do to make my question "more" attractive"? so I've flagged the question as possible duplicate of the mentioned question since, in its answer the possibiity of adding a bounty was mentioned. Wrt to the "tag", I think, but I could be wrong, that the more "attracting thing" of a question is its title tather than the associated tag (which, some time might be not the best ones).

Comment: The question is not eligible for a bounty yet but that point goes moot in 38 or so hours. We'll wait then what the rest of reviewers think.

Comment: Be wary of the edit you made, asking something like "Is NVML a superior tool than nvidia-smi for calculating power consumption" puts it in a territory where people start to flag as either opinionated or too broad (because you're now basically asking two questions). It seems an unnecessary distraction from the main topic, you might want to relocate it to a comment.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I removed the statements about NVML from my question.