# How am I supposed to moderate and watch any / my top tags using the old navigation?

Tags: support, search, new-nav

Judging from the latest edit on [Retiring New Navigation (beta) in preparation for Navigation 3.0](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359643/retiring-new-navigation-beta-in-preparation-for-navigation-3-0#359643) the ["New Navigation"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate) has been removed and we have gone back to a system of navigation I do not know and that I have not been introduced to (or at least I do not remember any of it).

My two top tags are [ios] and [swift].

How do I watch out for new questions, read them and judge if they deserve an upvote, downvote, close vote, duplicate or even if I simply can answer them?

Do I have to have six tabs open for [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios), [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift), [swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift3), [swift4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift4), [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [java8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java8)?

How have moderating people used Stack Overflow when this navigation was the only available thing originally?

Comment: I reverted to [my old method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254592/how-do-active-answerers-find-questions-to-answer/254603#254603). Use `or` searches.

Comment: @MartijnPieters okay, that is *some* relief at least. For separating two groups of searches you have to use two browser tabs though, right? In my case one for ios-stuff, one for java-stuff.

Comment: If you want two separate views, then yes.

Comment: I didn't realize how used to the new nav I had gotten, I miss it now :/

Comment: @miradulo: I realised it had been switched of the moment my view broke. :-(

Comment: Isn't this what RSS feeds are for? There are a large variety of programs/browser extensions which will monitor RSS feeds for you. The link to the corresponding RSS feed is at the bottom of each tag-questions page or searches which are only a set of tags.

Comment: @Makyen No, RSS feeds are for reading, not interacting. The RSS feed also can't do exclusions or combinations as far as I can tell. Just one tag at a time. The nav-v2 that just deactivated let us do all of that for multiple groupings all without ever having to leave the SO homepage.

Comment: @TylerH, While I haven't actually tested to verify that it's working as expected, a RSS feed is offered for tag searches with tag exclusions. For example, a search for [`[java] -[android]`](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+-android) offers an RSS feed link, which appears to provide what's desired (exclusions and combinations). I'm not saying that the "old new-nav" wasn't beneficial, just that RSS is another way to accomplish a similar task. Alternately, one would write a userscript which did (much of) what's desired. This Q&A isn't to bash the removal, but to find alternatives.

Comment: @miradulo  New navigation is better, more useful and streamlined. It's sad that so many people are resistant to *any* kind of improvement.

Comment: I truly open tons of browser tabs. Still, new nav was a step into the right direction. And the “we’re not finishing version 2, but dropping it to start version 3” sounds like software development lacking any kind of project management. Which makes it very unlikely (but we should never give up) to ever see a finished version 3 aka Duke Navigation Forever…

Comment: @Skipper what do you mean? We are complaining about *not* having the new navigation anymore but some ancient version of navigation. We are not resistant to change, this is a major step back, in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use `or` in a tag search.

Click on the search box. Type in your tags (with square brackets), and add `or` in between each tag:

```
 [ios] or [swift] or [swift3] or [swift4] or [java] or [java8]
```

This then opens a [single live page for questions matching any of those tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios+or+swift+or+swift3+or+swift4+or+java+or+java8).

The search box has a limit of 240 characters, but you can add on `+or+tagname` entries in the URL. I don't know what that is limited to (apart from the usual [URL length limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)).

If you had multiple such tabs, you'll have to use browser tabs instead (so a separate webpage for each search).

Answer (score 10):

You can also use wildcard in the search like `[swift*]` giving https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift+or+swift3+or+swift2+or+swift4+or+swiftmailer+or+swift-playground+or+swifty-json+or+swift-protocols+or+swift-extensions+or+swift2.3+or+swift-package-manager+or+swift3.2+or+swiftlint+or+swift-dictionary+or+swift-mt+or+swiftydropbox+or+arrays+or+swiftcharts+or+swift-structs+or+swiftbond which also can be acessed as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift*

or [ios*] giving https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios+or+ios7+or+ios5+or+ios4+or+ios8+or+ios6+or+ios-simulator+or+ios9+or+ios10+or+ios11+or+iostream+or+ios-autolayout+or+ios-ui-automation+or+ios-provisioning+or+ios-app-extension+or+ios7.1+or+ios-charts+or+ios-frameworks+or+ios8.1+or+ios-4.2 which also can be acessed as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios*

I use it everyday for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*fortran* which is in my favourite tags. Too bad, this favourite tag is not available in the mobile site or in the app, so they are both useless for me. I only use the desktop version even on the phone.

Comment: I have no idea how to render the URL with two asterisks as asterisks and not italics...

Comment: by escaping the `*` using a backslash, edited that in for you.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the two given answer I created a basic custom Tampermonkey user script that does simply replaces the header hrefs, titles and removes some of them completely:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Custon question header
// @namespace    https://stackoverflow.com/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Replace the "Question" header with a link to your custom tags
// @author       Me
// @match        https://stackoverflow.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    $('#nav-questions').attr("href", "/questions/tagged/ios*+or+objective-c*+-javascript+-javascript-events+-javascript-objects+java*");
    $('#nav-questions').html("iOS and Java Questions");
    $('#nav-jobs').attr("href", "/questions");
    $('#nav-jobs').html("All Questions");
    $('#nav-tags').remove();
    $('#nav-users').remove();
})();
```

Resulting in a header like

[image]