# Version-Specific Tags Hide Questions from Users Subscribed to Version-Agnostic Tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Forgive me if I'm doing it wrong, but when browsing Stack Overflow for questions that I may be able to answer, I would typically add a number of **Favourite Tags** and then browse the set of questions associated with each of the tags.

For example, I have a little experience working with MS Access and so I have the `ms-access` tag as one of my favourites, and so view the questions associated with this tag.

However, by chance, I happened to be reviewing the *First Posts* queue and stumbled upon a question concerning MS Access that I could have answered, but wasn't listed when viewing the `ms-access` tag.

The reason for this is that the question was tagged using a **version-specific** MS Access tag, namely `ms-access-2016`.

And now I'm thinking that I would need to add *all* of the version-specific tags to my set of Favourites just to be able to view all of the MS Access-related questions... but then it would quickly become tedious even just to view the list of questions associated with each and every version-specific tag, and ignore those that I've already seen under the main `ms-access` tag...

I do understand the benefits of having version-specific application tags to avoid users suggesting solutions which utilise functionality not present in an earlier version, but I fear that many questions will be overlooked by users such as myself who only browse the encompassing application tags (e.g. `ms-access`).

Therefore, my questions are as follows:

- Should questions tagged using version-specific application tags also be tagged with the general application tag? (e.g. questions tagged `ms-access-2016` also being tagged `ms-access`)
- Should version-specific application tags just be abolished?
- Or am I just plain browsing this site wrong?

Comment: In search you can do [ms-access-*] but that unfortunately doesn't work on your favorite tags, at least not the last time I checked.

Comment: @rene, Thanks - I didn't realise that wildcards were permitted in tag searches. Perhaps I should bookmark searches in my browser rather than using Favourite Tags - I'm curious as to how others approach this.

Comment: There used to be [new-nav](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359643/retiring-new-navigation-beta-in-preparation-for-navigation-3-0) that could help with that, but it was discontinued and will return in some form when <s>channels</s> SO-teams goes life

Comment: This also affects users the other way around. If there is a tag I want to add to my ignored tags, I don't want to have to add every version specific tag to that list, just the version-agnostic one. I understand that it can be useful to ignore a single version, but it would also be helpful to be able to ignore all versions.

Comment: Tags do not have a hierarchy, and are not connected. Many version-specific tags include guidance on how to use them (telling users to include the agnostic tag at all times) but not everyone reads the advice given. I just follow all the versio -specific tags together with the agnostic ones. You can use a tag search to follow multiple tags.

Comment: I reverted to my old method of searching after the new navigation was deactivated: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254592/how-do-active-answerers-find-questions-to-answer/254603#254603

Comment: Personally, I use [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access+or+access-vba+or+access+or+ms-access-2010+or+ms-access-2007+or+ms-access-2013+or+ms-access-2003+or+ms-access-2016+or+ms-access-2000+or+ms-access-97+or+ms-access-forms+or+ms-access-data-macro+or+ms-access-web-app+or+ms-access-reports+or+ms-access-2002) for the Access questions. People should use all relevant tags. But people often don't do what they should do.

Comment: @rene: It does work. Just to check, I just added `*sql` to my favorite tags and refreshed the front page to see a bunch of `sql`, `mysql` and `postgresql` questions highlighted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many thanks to everyone for their responses in the comments.

Following the various suggestions offered, I have now created a group of bookmarks within my web browser, with each bookmark adhering to the format:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag1+or+tag2+or+...
```

To save some time when setting these up, I obtained an initial group of tags using the wildcard search (e.g. `[ms-access*]`), and then added a few additional tags to the group by manually editing the URL saved with the bookmark.

---

I must admit, it does feel somewhat odd to be constructing my own form of "navigation bar" for this site using groups of bookmarks - it would certainly be a great addition if one had the ability to create shortcuts for saved searches of multiple tag sets from within the SO site - analogous to how tags may be saved as favourites, it would be useful to be able to save searches too.