# How to search one's own questions by tag?

Tags: support, tags, search

In my profile I can list my own questions and sort them by several criteria (votes, activity etc.). Is there a way to only list my questions with a certain tag. I am trying to find a question of mine, related to git, but I don't seem to find a way to only list my 'git' questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the link to **[your git questions/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1836143%20[git])**

You can access your tag history via your profile, go to the **tags** tab and find and click the **tag** you are interested in.

This will show you your questions/answers by tag.

Answer (score 12):

Simply use the following search operators:

1. `user:me` to find all questions and answers by you.
2. `[git]` to find all posts tagged with the Git tag.
3. `is:question` to filter them all down to questions.

Putting that altogether, you get

```
user:me [git] is:question
```

I see that you've asked [8 Git questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1836143+%5Bgit%5D+is%3Aquestion) so far.

### Documentation

For more search tips and instructions, see

- [How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)
- [What is the proper way to approach Stack Overflow as someone totally new to programming?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254572/what-is-the-proper-way-to-approach-so-as-someone-totally-new-to-programming/254579#254579)

Comment: There's no need to look up your user id. You can use `user:me` in the search, and it will automatically replace `me` with your user id.

Comment: `user:me` is the solution I've been hunting