# How can I search my own questions across all Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, search, network-sites

Today I figured out how to search my own questions and answers on Stack Overflow from this post:
[How to search one's own questions by tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266031/how-to-search-ones-own-questions-by-tag). Very handy!

Then I searched for an answer I posted somewhere recently only for it to come up without any results...

Then I remembered that I had posted it on another Stack Exchange site, but I don't have any idea which one. It was an answer to someone else's question. It was *computery* in nature. I didn't pay attention to the tags. One of my incentives for putting the question there in the first was because I thought it was a useful answer that I myself could even reuse one day.

To make matters more complicated, I notice that from time to time moderators move questions to different sites.

Is there something I can add to my question format so it searches more than just the current site?

E.g., `user:me stuff :all-stacks`

Comment: You only have [3 network accounts](http://stackexchange.com/users/1917720/chriskelly?tab=accounts), so the long way would be to search each one individually. Won't be much help if you have more than 5 though.

Comment: True but I have had questions move to sites I am not a member of. Also, I am only a recent active user and I foresee myself using more sites. Also I am pretty lazy about these kinds of things. Once I see a problem I immediately wonder how it might be automated

Answer (score 4):

You can check in the Activity section on the Stack Exchange profile page, [here](https://stackexchange.com/users/1917720/chriskelly?tab=activity). You will see everything you do in every SE account.

Comment: Thanks. That's useful to list all my questions and answer but I can't search them like that. I tried the same search that worked on serverfault but not stackexchange and it did't work. Instead I got a list of google results without any of my questions from what I could see.

Answer (score 4):

If you know what you wrote (approximately), you should just google it with your name in quotes.

Some arguments:

- The search on a site is for that site only.
- The search on http://stackexchange.com is just google search.
- [Data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) is also per site only.

Comment: Thanks. I did find it eventually - but it took some time. googling my name didn't work - just tried now. I thought I would make the suggestion because if I have trouble finding something I wrote 2 days ago, how am I supposed to find stuff back in 2 years. By then I may have invested a lot of time and effort into stack exchange.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I use my profile to locate all questions and answers. I think there is another way, but I think is faster when you have many questions and answers.

If someone has other way, I'm interested too.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add a reference to this post:

[Searching my own questions & answers over all Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102936/searching-my-own-questions-answers-over-all-stack-exchange-sites)

> It's possible (if you don't mind the results to be a bit stale, they're updated every Sunday morning) with a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/775099/searching-a-users-posts-by-keyword-networkwide).

There is an example link there: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/775099/searching-a-users-posts-by-keyword-networkwide?AccountId=6085540&keyword=company#results - it gives you a form with example entries, tried it, got asked for CAPTCHA because was anonymous, ran the query, and it says "Hold tight while we fetch your results" and it ran forever, and it ended with "Line 0: Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding." - not sure if it still works, maybe have to be logged in there.

Comment: That query (although it uses one of mine multi-db templates) is inefficient as it queries in each database the posts table twice. That probably worked back in 2017 because stackoverflow had way less records so you could get away with sub-optimal approaches. Today a rewrite would be needed. It might be enough to only get rid of the union for answers and questions and move that distinction in the final projection.

Comment: There is another SEDE query of the same author for the same aim from 09/01/2022 which I ran a few times and got what I wanted, takes about a minute and sometimes times out, but it works, see meta Stack Exchange [Cross Stack Exchange search through all of my questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360602/787861).