# Where do I ask questions like "How do I make this?" Why are they not well-received on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, new-users, site-recommendation

I am new to the web development world and generally have a lot of curiosity when I see something new. I don’t have that much guidance on web development from my university. I want to ask questions like, "How do I get started with making a feature like the homepage background of [https://some.website.com?"](https://some.website.com?%22)

But if I ask such questions on Stack Overflow, they are quickly downvoted and I have to delete it (to save my 'little but hard-earned' reputation).

Why are such questions not well-received on Stack Overflow? Where can I ask such questions instead, or is it the case that Stack Exchange is not the right community for such questions?

Comment: Related: [Where to start?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start)

Comment: See also: [How can a noob ask questions about "how to start with this cool stuff"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181993)

Comment: *Yahoo! Answers*, *Quora* and *4Chan*'s */b/*. Such questions as you propose are out of scope here. Please read the section about what's on topic on the help center: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Isn't there a canonical (meta) question for the *"How do I get started?"* trap for young players (*courtesy [Mr. EEVBlog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_L._Jones_(video_blogger))*)? Such design level questions are distinct from beginner or write-the-code-for-me questions. *[Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour)* may or may not (probably not) cover such questions.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Why your questions are not well received

If the entire content of your questions are like what you described:

> How do I get started with making a feature like the homepage background of https://some.website.com

the reason they get downvoted is they just aren't good questions.  There is no real problem and there is no real answer other than providing the code on how to do it.  While they aren't explicitly off-topic, they really push the limit for what is considered acceptable by a number of the users in the community.

- Good questions ask a specific question about a specific problem.  You example question does not, it just asks someone to write code for them.  That may not be your intent, but that is what the question does ask.
- While not all good questions need to show code, you need to make some effort on your in doing your research and show what you have tried and what isn't working with your attempt(s).  If you do have code, then show your code (a short sample that reproduces the problem is enough, don't dump your entire source).  There is nothing you provided in your question.  You just provided a link to a site that had something you were interested in implementing,
- When you do show your attempts and what went wrong, don't just say "it doesn't work".  Explain **why** it doesn't work.  Provide any error messages or exceptions, show what was the expected output and what you were getting.  If it isn't obvious, you might need to explain why the expected output is different than what you were getting.
- We can't read your mind, so be very clear when asking a question.  In your example you just say you want to implement the background you saw on a site.  I visited that site and there is a lot going on in the background.  I see 3 or 4 different elements.  What exactly is it you want to implement, and how?  Without this info, no one can even attempt to answer without guessing.

The problem many new users run into is they think Stack Overflow will help them learn to code, or provide advice or opinions, or even provide a full tutorial on something.  These types of questions don't fit the Stack Overflow model for various reasons.  But the short version is Stack Overflow is a Q&A site and is designed for getting good answers to specific programming problems you are facing.

Asking a question on Stack Overflow should not be your first stop when you have a problem, it should be your last.  You need to research the problem on your own (both on Stack Overflow and on the internet), try to figure it out, then when you have problems, then ask a question about the problem and explaining the issue.

---

### Answering this question as asked

As written, there is nowhere on the Stack Exchange network where your question is acceptable.  The topic itself could be on-topic on several Stack Exchange sites including Stack Overflow.  To make your question acceptable for Stack Overflow, you would need to address the issues I mentioned above.  If you want some more guidance, keep reading.  I have outlined the best approach based on my SO experiences.

---

### How to Proceed

I am not a web developer, so I can't provide specific guidance on this specific question, but in general a better way to approach your issue is when you find something you are interested in understanding, dig into it yourself.

1. Examine what code you can get access too.  In this case, your browser should have enough to display it for you, so you should be able to get the code for the page.  You can pull up the source, and use the developer console for the browser, and you can start breaking it down yourself.
2. Search and then search some more.  One general Google (or Bing or your favorite search engine) search is not enough.  Use Google with what keywords you have.  You may not find what you want in your first attempt, but you may find new keywords to help you in your search.  Keep repeating until you think there is nothing else to find.  This is the most crucial step, and the one that most new users don't do enough.  They think that if they don't know anything at all they can't search for it.  You'd be surprised how much you can get from a little effort and a little reading.
3. Make an attempt yourself and see what happens. If it works, great, but if not, then go back to your research and see if you can figure out the problem.  Googling again should be a key part of your attempts to solve.
4. When trying to solve the problem, make sure you use your debugger.  Most questions can be answered simply by looking at the values of specific variables and understanding why they aren't behaving as expected.  This is also critical in writing a short simple program to reproduce the error for posting your question in Step 6 below.  How can you expect someone to reproduce your problem if they don't have a quick bit of code they can execute to see the issue?
5. Only once you have gone through your research, you are ready to go to Stack Overflow.
6. Get your question together, type everything out, then look at the suggested similar questions.  Maybe one of them solves your problem.  Another helpful hint is to try Googling your exact title.
7. Once you are sure you have completed everything and you are positive you have exhausted all of your research, and you have clearly explained the problem and what you are expecting to get, it is finally time to hit "Post Your Question".

I think if you make more of an effort on your own, it will make developing your skill much easier in the future.  Learning to search, and apply similar issues to your own problem is critical to being successful as a programmer.

Comment: re #2 of how to proceed: searching "[x] tutorial" can do _wonders_.

Comment: +1 for [Stack Overflow should not be your first stop when you have a question, it should be your last](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254572/what-is-the-proper-way-to-approach-so-as-someone-totally-new-to-programming/254573#254573).