# Where can I ask questions about Internet of Things?

Tags: discussion

I have an idea about a project which can be classified on under internet of Things. I do not want to post it where it would be shut down.

## More details

There are car tracking systems but they all seem complex and need professional installation.

I am looking at a simple maybe SIM powered hardware the can be thrown into your car via which you can keep track on your phone after a simple pairing is done. it would need to have a long battery life.

It can have ONE basic setting.

Show me my car on a map
I am sure this exists in some form but I cannot find it anywhere.

Two key things. Simplicity and Affordability.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the question?  A little context would go a long way.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables done and thanks. 


To the folks down voting instead of asking for clarification, thanks for the kind welcome. I feel the warmth.

Comment: Note that site recommendation questions are usually better on MSE, since other communities watch that site where they aren't necessarily on MSO. Could explain the downvotes. Plus its a terrible question on *any* site, as the answer notes.

Comment: PS: (Not directed at anyone in particular). I'd want to believe there should be a place of\n the SE network that one should net be afraid of asking a question. A (safe?) place where one is  be afraid of being wrong :). Maybe where before being slammed, the person can be helped to ask right? After all, the purpose of these sites is at least to help those willing to be helped.

Comment: @OoTheNigerian - that's called Yahoo Answers

Comment: You mean, like, a cheapo smartphone with GPS?  It already exists.

Comment: @OoTheNigerian Just one thing : you are aware people are giving you their free time, right? you don't have to be afraid to ask, you just have to respect people's free time and make sure your question is on topic and in the right place by looking at the help center. Also, on meta Stack, downvotes aren't worth rep and don't necessarily mean "your question is bad". In this instance, it might just be people who want to say "you should not ask this in on these sites". Don't take it personally :)

Comment: @Patrice Thanks for your response. This is Meta! The one place that one should be able to ask anything you are unsure of. Every one gives their free time so I do not expect to be given a response. Going out of ones way to down vote is at best VERY unhelpful. A question can easily be ignored. When I ask a question about where I can ask a question and I see 5 down votes before I complete it, it's very unwelcoming. It says "fuckouttahere". Anyway, sorry for polluting the sanctity of this place. PS: I have no issue with the answer which is accurate. The downvotes are offensive.

Comment: All these people gave you lots of help.

Comment: @OoTheNigerian not EVERYTHING is okay for meta. I can't really open a question saying "where can I get a lawyer in Montreal". Whoever is taking their time to read your question is giving you their time. Stack Overflow is "community moderated", which means that as you get rep, you get more "tasks" for moderation available to you (flagging, close voting, editing, reviewing, etc). After doing these for a little while, you can get tired of reposting variations of "this is off topic for us, since it asks for outside resources, and will lead to flame wars", so you just downvote.

Comment: Anyway,  feedback for your community. To you,  it is the 20th stupid question. To the person,  it is their first time.  When you down vote without a comment,  it's unwelcoming. My initial question was merely asking about where to ask IoT topics. I was told to give more details. I did and got  more downvotes. We'll,  it's the internet I should not expect to be treated nice. But I'll still point it our for others to see and maybe take the feedback.  :).  Thanks for your time!

Comment: It's still not clear from this post whether you want to _build_ such a system or _buy_ one premade. If the former, the question is too broad: [Where do I ask questions like "how do I make this"?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272338)

Comment: Patrice first of all, I am not ranting. Secondly I replied you. Should I grovel? People telling me my question is not welcome here are not helpful. You can ignore a question you think makes no sense in "Meta"! and No I did not ask a question about Kamasutra. 

JoshCaswell, I would like to explore building if it does not exist already.

@MartinJames, the problem with phones is they use too much power. I was thinking of something along the line of a sensor that can be tracked remotely.

Answer (score 9):

> I am looking at a simple maybe SIM powered hardware the can be thrown into your car via which you can keep track on your phone after a simple pairing is done. it would need to have a long battery life.

Off the top of my head, I would say "Nowhere on Stack Exchange".  You're asking for a product recommendation, which is pretty much off-topic for every site.

There *is* [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), but as the name says, that's for software, and it looks like you're asking about hardware.  As far as I'm aware, there isn't a Hardware Recommendations site yet.

Comment: Thanks. Is there anywhere on the internet you think I can ask such a question? I am asking of a community that would have people that have an idea of how this can be built even if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Nope, sorry; I specialize in knowing where things don't belong, not where they belong :)