# Where would be a better place to ask on how to start writing a (specific) Android app?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have had an idea about a program to write, although I am uncertain as to where to ask it.

To make it easier to understand, I'll summarize my idea: Basically, I was thinking of writing a program for Android/iOS that will allow you to use a selection of ringtones, which will then be randomly selected every time you get a text/call.

However - I'm not sure whether this is even possible. My knowledge of the Android/iOS systems is rather limited, so whether or not a program like this could even be implemented at all, I just don't know. Can I ask about this functionality somewhere?

And if that gets sorted out, could I ask for help getting started with the program somewhere on SE? Is [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) the place for that or somewhere else?

Comment: See also [How can a noob ask questions about "how to start with this cool stuff"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181993) and [Where do I ask questions like "how do I make this"?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272338)

Comment: Note: Thanks for asking about it here on Meta first :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I've been on SE for a while, so I know how to roll haha. Though I do realise this is a common issue :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nowhere on Stack Exchange.

That question is way, way, **WAY** too broad. In fact, I don't even see a question in what you posted.

You need to narrow it down to some programming problems that you *can* ask about, and ask those here.

See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question/284237#284237)

Your updated version is better, but you would need to ask *specifically* about intercepting calls/texts and selecting ringtones, with the effort and research required by every other SO question. The "getting started" part is still way too broad, and you would need to break it down into smaller pieces as in the linked post.

Comment: Good point. I'll edit my question to add some more information about my concerns, but if that doesn't help then I'll probably delete it :)

Comment: Any better? If not I'll remove it.

Comment: Your question *here* is better. You could certainly ask about selecting a ring tone (please, try something and do some research first). As far as getting started goes, you could ask *some* questions in chat, but realistically, you need to follow the advice in the linked post.