# Tags for kids to ask Python programming questions

Tags: discussion

My 11-year-old kid is starting to learn Python. Stack Overflow is a great place to ask questions and get quality answers. The problem is that my kid is just a kid. Even as an adult, my questions got downvoted when I started out in Stack Overflow. My kid does not stand a chance but I respect that is the culture of SO. His likely low-quality questions are probably not going to be tolerated on SO.

Are there tags on Stack Overflow to indicate to SO members that the question is asked by a kid so that they can exercise more patience?

What are ways for a kid to ask questions on Stack Overflow?

If SO is just not the right place for this, are there suitable Stack Exchange websites for kids?

From a father keen to get his son hooked on programming.

Comment: Step one is to wait two more years, since people under 13 aren't legally allowed to have accounts. Step two is the same for everyone: understand the help center, improve your search skills, ask about concrete programming problems.

Comment: Also, it's ok not to ask questions. From the initial tour: SO is targeted at professionals and enthusiasts, which *usually* doesn't include completely new programmers, no matter what their age.

Comment: I don't believe that Stack Overflow is a good place for someone learning how to program: that person needs _help_, not _answers_. Back-and-forth, hints, simplifications, slowly revealed explanations, pointers. None of these things make good answers. I'd recommend finding a chat or more forum-like site. Best of luck, though!

Comment: Closely related: [What is the proper way to approach Stack Overflow as someone totally new to programming?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254572)

Comment: Oh, also, since it's Python, _you_ could ask [in the Python chat here on SO](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) if _they_ know any good sites. (Not that it was wrong to ask here, though.)

Comment: i am 13 now. if you want to know how to ask good questions, ask me. i browse stack overflow every day. ( mention me here and if the discussion is long, the comment box will ask you to turn this to a chat room. after that, delete all your comments. )

Comment: a good tip: try to be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760790/how-can-i-listen-to-onclick-event-spotlight-helper-and-attach-the-transformcontr i've got 2 downvotes, but when I say I will add it to SO docs i've got 2 upvotes. 2*5-2*2=6 so i won't be question banned.

Comment: Side note: you may want to read existing posts on meta about SO culture... Like why posts are downvoted or "don't add thank you to posts" - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts... :)

Comment: Another side note, at various times I've had to assist all my kids in lying about their ages online, because there are all sorts of interesting and useful sites that age gate them like SO does.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Are there tags on StackOverflow to indicate to SO members that the question is asked by a kid so that they can exercise more patience?

No, there are not. That isn't what tags are for in the first place. Tags have nothing to do with the author of a question.

> What are ways for a kid to ask questions on StackOverflow?

They can ask them *through you*, as an 11 year old is not legally able to accept the terms of service and use Stack Overflow.

> If SO is just not the right place for this, are there suitable StackExchange websites for kids?

There isn't one, at least for programming questions. There are lots of ways for your 11 year old child to learn to program, Stack Overflow is simply **not it**, and has never tried to be it. Teaching an 11 year old how to program is *wildly* outside of the scope of this site. Changing the standards of quality we have for content due to the young age of the poster is absolutely antithetical to the site itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are right. On further reflection, I myself would be irritated if I see too many kidstuff questions on a professional programmer Q&A website like SO.

Comment: Dang meager. Do you _ever_ post a bad answer?

Comment: I would add that "tags for <no matter what audience, kids or not>" would (dis)qualify as [meta-tag:meta-tags]