# Why downvote a simple question about a piece of code that is not working?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes

I am new to programming and Stack Overflow. Before asking my first question, I watched several videos and read the guidelines. I then looked at some existing questions, but was unable to figure out why some questions received downvotes.

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872899/creating-my-own-strdup-function) has received 3 downvotes. I don't know why.

To me, it is just someone asking a 'simple' question about a piece of code he wrote that is not working properly. I must be missing something. Can someone explain what it is that I'm missing, and why that question was judged to be a bad question by Stack Overflow members?

For a person trying to learn to code without any teachers, the help from the community is essential.

Edit: the reason I think it's not the same with "When is it justifiable to downvote a question?" is because this is a very specific case that I didn't understand at first, but after all your comments it is now clear to me and I hope it will be for other new people reading this.

Comment: Relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252677/1233251

Comment: Don't confuse "bad" with "unsuitable". We downvote questions that are not *suitable* for our style of Q&A.

Comment: OK, thanks.  No one is going to be able to tell you why for certain that was down voted but to me it is simply a "debug this" question.  If the OP were to have used his debugger they should have found all the problems on their own.  It is also not really useful for others as it is not very searchable for what the problems are.

Comment: Hmmm...no, not really seeing any reason to downvote this question, if I'm honest.  The problem is stated clear enough, and code is presented to reproduce (and test) it.  While I admit that the question isn't the greatest in the world - that is, it's really a "debug this for me"-style question, this isn't as egregious or as flagrantly bad as the normal suspects in this category.

Comment: The Help Center does not fail to point out that a question needs to be *practical and answerable*.  How the heck is that a practical question?  No way he's ever going to get stuck, he can just use the CRT provided strdup() function.  And no way he can't find out how to write it correctly, every CRT install provides the source code as well so he could simply compare it to his own.  So the question is not useful, one of the standard reasons for a DV.

Comment: _"watched several videos"_??

Comment: [What is the proper way to approach Stack Overflow as someone new to programming?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254572/what-is-the-proper-way-to-approach-stack-overflow-as-someone-totally-new-to-prog)

Comment: @JoshCaswell indeed, some about the actual formatting of the text and also an interesting video with Oded Coster.

Comment: @Makoto While I agree that post actually include correct sample is good staring point... First of all the question is in C tag - basic understanding of pointers is required... Even ignoring that - code is not MCVE as significant portion can be removed to create minimal sample like `return malloc(...) + 5;` (granted OP would likely find answer themselves).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov:  I'm only speaking as someone who's definitely not well-versed in C, but the moderation pieces should be the same across the board.  I can respect the rationale to downvote the question, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Questions like that get downvoted because Stack Overflow is not a place that teaches you to program.

The first steps in programming are translating small ideas into little bits of code. You learn about variable types, flow control, Boolean algebra, sets, and whatnot. You need to learn to read parser errors that tell you why your code doesn't conform to the language's specifications.

Then when it finally runs, you need to learn to test and debug your code, to validate whether your code actually implements the idea you had, and reevaluate whether that idea solved the original problem to begin with.

So when at that level people come to Stack Overflow and ask *"Why doesn't this code work? [code dump]"*, where their code contains syntax errors or real simple logic errors that a bit of thinking and debugging would've shown, they shouldn't really be getting confused about downvotes.

Their question is interesting only to them, hardly ever useful for anyone else and generally only attracts *"Try this [fixed code dump]"* answers which aren't useful for asker nor later readers.

So all in all, while such questions might be on-topic (they contain something that resembles a problem statement), they're generally frowned upon and thus downvoted.

Comment: To add to this, there's even a close reason for this: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.`

Comment: Which doesn't apply to the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872899/creating-my-own-strdup-function), as it contains something that resembles a problem statement (_"why here my chars are not copied"_) and the code to reproduce that behavior.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging

Answer (score 13):

The C and C++ communities have particularly strict standards for what makes a quality question. Part of this comes from seeing the same beginner questions over and over about common stumbling blocks like pointers. If it seems like the asker didn't do sufficient research before asking, and/or didn't sit down with a debugger to examine their code, then the question will probably be downvoted.

Don't confuse that with the question being *unsuitable* for Stack Overflow, though. Such questions are closed, rather than merely downvoted. Downvotes sometimes just mean "this question is not interesting".

Why is "not interesting" a reason to downvote? Well, it's right there in the tooltip, so that's one thing. But it goes deeper than that. Votes are how content is *ranked* on Stack Overflow. We want to get the good questions at the top of the list so the experts see (and can answer) them. Uninteresting questions don't need to be pushed up to the top of the queue. Experts downvote uninteresting beginner questions to give a signal to other experts that question doesn't need their attention.

**See Also:** [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question)

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the answer to the question, it seems that the code presented has more than one error, which sounds like the original poster just wrote some code that he/she didn't really understand and expected the users here to fix. After the problem he posted, there would be another and I've seen follow up questions continue in the comments many times.

You can't really provide an answer to this question without fixing all of the code, because your answer then would also have mistakes.

My guess is that experienced C users saw all the mistakes and downvoted it because of that.

Comment: "I leave the rest as an exercise for the reader" is usually an okay way to get around that proviso.  I don't disagree at all with your thought on why the votes accrued though, me not being well-versed in C.