# What's the fastest way to get 50 reputation on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments, privileges

I need to comment on some questions/answers, but can't, because I don't have enough reputation. I want to help, but the site doesn't let me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: Because for new users it's easier to add to incomplete answers (many of those around here as people are just whoring for reputation and give quick answers instead of going into detail) than write them, but it's often equally useful. And yes, it will end well. The only question is whether I'm going to bother.

Comment: @ucq52ose, *adding to incomplete answers* should be done with care, especially by new users. Posting your own answers is probably a better solution.

Comment: Simple, By *asking a good question* or by *providing a good answer*. Forget comments till then

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164035/how-does-a-lurker-gain-reputation

Comment: I imagine this question has slowed you down a little...

Comment: If you have 38 rep, you can just do 6 edits to get there.

Comment: Relevant, if not a duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252149/215552 It doesn't say how to do it "fastest", but on SO I don't think we want people concentrating on speed.

Comment: edit 25 questions.

Comment: @qwr Many of the easily improvable questions will be deleted and you lose the rep. I would search for new answers with common grammar mistakes, and fix them. Alternatively, I would re-tag new questions with at least +1 score (-> unlikely deletion). More advanced solution is to use the SEDE to find questions likely requiring specific tags.

Answer (score 21):

If you "**need** to comment on some questions/answers" then you likely have an answer or a good understanding of why another answer is flawed.

I'd therefore recommend that you write the answer you have.  e.g. "The @SomeGuyOrGal gave will work but only in Java 8.  To make this work in all versions of Java you'll need to use something like this:

...(code detailing the complete solution)...

If your answer is *truly* the correct answer (or at least worth noting) you should gain some reputation from your answer.  In time this rep will grow where by you can post comments as *needed* when you need clarification.

Answer (score 14):

I feel with gnat, since I also was told "use the comment function instead" by other users and I simply can't. I think using a high reputation level as spam protection is the wrong way to go. This is really frustrating for people like me who just want to help.

Comment: Downvotes and upvotes don't affect your reputation there, on meta.