# Is using Stack Overflow as a whiteboard a recommendable way to get rep as a new user?

Tags: discussion, reputation, new-users

I am new on the site; actually the reason I registered is because IBM moved the Worklight forums to Stack Overflow.

After having asked 3 worklight-related questions, I realize that I do **not** expect an answer anymore when I ask something on SO. I just like the site because it helps me think about how to express my problem, and then I get ideas on how to fix it.

However, I was tempted to contribute to the site because I had been a long time unregistered user; at this point, I feel like the only way for me to contribute in a useful way is with comments, since I am not good enough to contribute a whole answer to questions usually but sometimes think I could add something valuable as a comment.
Moreover, I do not have time to camp the low quality questions and hope the asker will accept my answer before he gets down-voted.

So currently, the only way for me to earn enough reputation to comment is writing my issue on SO and solving it by myself, and hoping some random people will up-vote either the question or the answer.

Is this the behaviour one would advice a new user to follow? Does not the problem come from the fact I ask questions in a not very popular tag ([worklight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/worklight)) which does not get visibility because of the html/js tags flood? Or are my questions not good enough to get enough upvotes to not disappear after 15mins?

Comment: You can edit too.

Comment: @bjb568 Good point; edits always seemed somewhat intrusive to me, but the 'new user tour page' seems to say they should be preferred to comments when not asking for new information.

Comment: @bjb568: Yeah, editing seems todays rep farming golden hammer for people who wont/cant ask/answer, as we can see in the edit review queue with its tons of minor edits that get robo approved.

Comment: What is your motivation in gaining rep? What do you want to have more rep for?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Why would you _not_ want more of dem sweet sweet repz????!??!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: sssshhh, don't tell, I just want to prevent others from getting them so I can get them.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, they wrote "I was tempted to contribute to the site because I had been a long time unregistered user"; that seems pretty clear as to why they would want rep, i.e. to contribute [which requires rep].

Comment: @KennyEvitt: It isn't clear to me what level of contribution is desired. 62 rep is enough to comment, you can also ask and answer. What more is needed here? downvotes? not that far away. free editing? quite some rep left.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, fair enough; I have a (very) mild desire for some more rep so I can access the next set of review queues. But I also love every Magic Unicorn point I've ever earned!

Comment: see [How does a lurker gain reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164035/165773) at MSE

Comment: You're lucky in some ways that you're interested, and I'm guessing knowledgeable, in a low-traffic-on-the-site topic; you've got less competition for Magic Unicorn points!

Comment: Well, had 30 rep at the time of writing and did not expect to be over 50 anytime soon. My main motivation was being able to comment

Comment: You can get rep by asking good questions. You get 5 points for each up-vote to a question. In the old days, you could also get rep from asking terrible RTFM questions, but that is less the case these days.

Comment: What does it mean that " IBM moved the Worklight forums to Stack Overflow"? Stack Overflow isn't a forum platform, and I don't see anything in the tag wiki about that....(I don't know anything about IBM Worklight, or maybe I'd understand what you mean by this.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Contributing comments is fine; possibly great, depending on the quality of your comments.

I'm not sure what you mean by "camp the low quality questions", but please don't *encourage* low quality questions by trying to answer them "and hope the asker will accept my answer before he gets down-voted.". But feel free to edit – nay, pretty please *do edit* – low-quality questions to improve them.

Asking a question and answering it yourself is perfectly fine – as long as the question is good! So don't just use SO "as a whiteboard" but, instead, distill your 'whiteboard issues' into the Ultimate Pure Essence of What Was Really Going-on Behind the Veil of Your Particular Issue. In doing so you probably won't be upvoted by "some random people" – you'll be upvoted by people that find your question or your answer (or both) to be useful and worthy of inclusion and promotion on this wonderful site.

Also, see this Meta-SO question that covers a lot of what you seem to be (really) asking:

- [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow?rq=1)

Comment: This covers most of what I wanted to have more precise guidelines on, thank you !

Comment: "The Ultimate Pure Essence of What Was Really Going-on Behind the Veil of Your Particular Issue" Ahh, the holy grail, the ever-distant horizon.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I've always looked poorly on posting a question with the expressed purpose of answering it yourself. I know the official stance is that it's perfectly fine here, but it just feels disingenuous, like you're farming for rep.

That said, you described:

> After having asked 3 worklight-related questions, I realize that I do not expect an answer anymore when I ask something on SO. I just like the site because it helps me think about how to express my problem, and then I get ideas on how to fix it.

It seems perfectly fine to me for you to ask these questions, without expecting an answer, and then when you figure out the solution on your own later, come back and answer your own question. If you're asking the questions anyways, and the visibility of the tag is so low that you're never really getting answers, then answering yourself, at that point, is the only way the question may ever be resolved.

I suppose it's mostly about motivation. Do ask questions when you need help. Do answer those questions if no one else has and you figure it out. But, don't just post something just to get some rep.