# Found a duplicate but my rep is not high enough to flag/comment in it

Tags: discussion, flags, reputation, duplicate-questions, comments

I was looking through some questions when I came across a duplicate of a question. I, just having started using SO, do not have enough rep to flag it as a dup or put a comment saying it was a possible dup.

What is the standard procedure for taking care of this?

Comment: You wait until you have another 10 points, I am afraid; you can flag when you have 15 points. That shouldn't be *that* hard to achieve.

Comment: .. especially if you take good care of answering. So far, you are doing well, although I would advise you to not put *too* many effort in answering two months-old questions from once-posters. Try aiming a bit higher. [Massive amount of good tips in this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow) (except for Your Common Sense's).

Comment: @MartijnPieters you cannot flag as duplicate until reaching 50 reputation IIRC.

Comment: You have 15+ rep, so you can [now flag such posts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts). Please check and let us know if you are able to flag dupes at 15+ rep, or does it require 50 rep.

Comment: @Qantas: ah! You are correct! Dupes *may* require commenting so you have to have the [commenting everywhere privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Not sure if posts that already have the comment can be flagged at 15 then.

Comment: @Infinte: it looks like the flagging privilege help text needs updating. You need to be able to comment to flag as a dupe.

Comment: Wait..wait..and wait..is the only good option until have have reputation to do this

Answer (score -8):

Do what other news users do and write an answer with a link to the duplicate question.   Not great but at least the information is then recorded for other people to act on.

Comment: ... or, instead of adding to the clean up effort involved in an answer that is not an answer, just wait until you have the required privilege.