# Can you become reputable on Stack Overflow for already popular languages?

Tags: discussion, reputation, answers, popularity

I really like the concept of Stack Overflow, but sometimes I feel that you can only gain a reputation for contributing to newer languages/frameworks or less popular languages/frameworks.

My main language is Java, and I would like to contribute to it. But the chances of asking a decent question is reduced by the already good questions. And the area is so saturated that new answers for Java appear extremely quickly so yours has a reduced probability of getting marked correct and upvoted.

I think that what I am asking is maybe along the lines of advice. If your aim is to earn a decent reputation and your 'main skillset' is an area also saturated on Stack Overflow, what's the best way to approach answering on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Answer to help, don't think about reputation, you will start scoring if you write quality answers with decent explanations

Comment: **Write as many answers as possible, as fast as possible, even if the questions are absolutely stupid.** You'll get about 1 upvote for each answer on average. Write about 1000 answers and you'll have 10k easily (that's about 4 months and 8 answers a day -- most people take *years* to get 10k). Of course, if you're here to actually contribute and learn, rather than just to get a big fat sum of imaginary internet points, you're better off following what the others have said.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, it looks like you've been taking (sarcastic) advice from [Your Common Sense](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254141/372643) ;-) I wish I'd realised that earlier, it took me a year and a half to get to 10K.

Comment: Less popular languages/frameworks have their own problems in terms of rep -- you can write great answers that garner hardly any upvotes because the question and answer don't get many views.  Also, if the answer is complicated and technical in an area without a large community then most people who view the answer won't know if it's useful or not so they probably won't upvote it.

Answer (score 14):

I joined SO in November 2012, and I'm now over 10,000 reputation, based mainly on Java with some floating-point, double, and algorithms.

An answer does not have to be the first posted, or even the accepted answer, to collect upvotes, although that helps. It just has to add something useful.

Also, don't assume the immediate upvotes are all you are going to get. I got an upvote this month for a Java answer I posted over a year ago. A good answer to a good question, which I like to think that one was, goes on giving indefinitely.

Answer (score 7):

Write really good answers.

Think about it. If your tag of choice is saturated with answers, wouldn't it also be saturated with questions? I've seen lots and lots of questions like yours, phrased a little differently:

> My main language is `$unpopular language$` and I would like to contribute to it. But no one reads those questions, or votes on their answers! How can I get reputation if I don't contribute towards a popular tag?

Answer (score 3):

Ask a question *only if you must*.  Don't ask questions for reputation.

And write really good answers, eventually they will get votes. The system *does work*.

*The best approach* is to first write a 100 answers and based on that experience, decide for yourself which ones gave you the most satisfaction as a contributer and also helped you gain reputation.

After a 100 answers, writing skills also improve significantly. Use that skill to edit and improve poor-worded unclear questions. Fixing questions is very important. Your good answers are useless, if the corresponding question is unclear or poorly written.

Comment: I guess the difficulty is to find 100 questions where adding a new answer isn't redundant. By the way, when you say "*don't worry if you don't get the accept mark for your answers*", "Unsung Hero" works the other way around: it's for answers that have been accepted by not upvoted. You'd tend to get it when you answer more niche questions that few know whether to upvote, but you help the asker at least.

Comment: Thanks @Bruno,  I was wrong about the badge, deleted that part. Almost half the questions asked in Java in the past 30 days [are unanswered](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/topusers). Out of these 22K+ questions, a few can always be found that are worth answering. I chose 100 based on my experience on SO in past few months, it could be any number based on individual preference :-)

Comment: Indeed, it looks like there are still many interesting questions in that list. That's good advice. It's good to see newcomers making a positive contribution.