# How to help out without being able to comment?

Tags: discussion

I recently wanted to help out in this thread: [Powershell: convert string to number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25322636/powershell-convert-string-to-number)

But since I don't have enough reputation, I couldn't comment the question, so I posted a question as an answer instead. Big mistake - it was deleted quickly.

My question is.. how can I help out in a situation like this? My question was a leading question that might have got him on the right path, and based on his reply it could well have been the correct answer even.

I understand why it was deleted, but I just wanted to help the guy out.

Comment: In what form specifically did you want to help out? If you have an answer, you can post an answer. If the question requires more questions, it's probably a bad question is should be deleted.

Comment: Did you make it clear you didnt have enough rep?

Comment: Well.. his question was how he could convert what he conceived as a string representation of a number (1.500) into a string (1500). My question to him was, are you sure it's not already a number and that it was just his culture settings that formatted the number in that way?

Comment: Then why not post that as an answer? Explain that this is *one possible scenario* which might explain the situation and how the OP may test whether it applies. Offer it as a solution and what to do in this case. If it works, great. If not, oh well.

Comment: No, I didn't state in the "answer" that I did it that way because I didn't have enough reputation. That's something I should have done of course.. but couldn't someone have pointed that out to me instead of deleting my "answer"?

Comment: @deceze I thought it was worded in a way that made it look like it could very well be the correct answer.. but the one that deleted it wrote that it was not allowed and that it was not an answer..

Comment: This is what I wrote:

Are you sure it's not already a number? Could it be just your culture settings that is using '.' as a group separator?

What does (Get-Culture).NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator tell you?

So you can clearly see that it is a question to him.. but one that could help to figure out his question.. or at least so I thought.

Comment: Well, what you posted was indeed not really an answer. You asked the OP a question. Just make it a well presented statement instead. You'll probably have to flesh it out a bit to make it a really useful answer.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow

Comment: @deceze Well, I couldn't be sure if my answer was in fact the answer, before I could get him to check the culture. My reason behind this post, was just to figure out how to help out in a situation like this. I don't want to break the rules.

Comment: Requiring new users to follow a different process for answering questions than established users is silly. There are so many times when you just need a bit of clarification from OP for the question to be valid and answerable. With all the restrictions on SO for commenting (can't do more than once every x seconds, and I think there may also be a per day limit) I don't really get why we restrict new users from commenting. It doesn't save moderation time cause then we just have to deal with all the comments posted as answers. -_-

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *think* you have an answer, but you're not entirely sure. Well, unfortunately you do not have commenting privileges yet, so there's nothing really you can do to clarify. If you're reasonably sure that there's a good chance that your hunch is right, **post it as an answer**. Present it with all the caveats that apply.

> It's not entirely clear from the information given in your question, but it appears that...
>   To confirm whether this is the case, try A, B or C.
>
> If this is the case, you can fix it by doing ...
>
> Note that if this is the case, you'll also want to be aware of X, Y and Z.

Even if it may not solve the OP's problem because it did not apply after all, it may be useful information for other future visitors.

Comment: I have a feeling you are spot on here. Unfortunately, this whole thing have left me with a sour taste in my mouth, I would have liked it to be some way of actually helping out even though I'm a new user. Thanks for you time and help btw! :)

Comment: @ojk You'll cross the 50 mark to be able to comment everywhere very soon, I'm sure.

Comment: @ojk As an aside, asking for clarifications in comments is not always successful anyway. Many question askers are just in fire-and-forget mode and do not actually respond to comments quickly, or at all. Posting what you think may be the right solution is often more helpful for everyone. Please help! :)