# How I can thank an answerer on Stack Overflow if I don't have enough reputation?

Tags: discussion, user-experience

I have 11 reputation on Stack Overflow. 
I read an answer which was useful for me, and I want to vote it or write a comment. But I can't.

I can not get an answer for this question.

But I am allowed to edit the best answer in someone else's post. This doesn't seem to be the normal behavior of the system.

For example, I was allowed to edit [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19870176/xcode-5-debugger-doesnt-print-objects-and-shows-nil-when-they-arent/19904143#19904143). My edit was 
"--test message--".

Comment: [Your edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5747642) won't be approved. In fact, it has been rejected already.

Comment: You could say the test was successful, the community passed it by rejecting your edit. I believe you meant no harm but next time please read the FAQ instead of trying to play with the site like that.

Comment: You have received upvote privilege. That answer is worthy of your first upvote. And don't forget to upvote good questions too, because if someone hadn't asked the question, the answer would not have been written. Use your votes wisely. Good luck.

Comment: Also read: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 8):

You will have to get enough reputation to vote the answer up. You are *almost* there already, just 4 more reputation.

As for your [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5747642) - yes, you can edit the answer, but the edit will not be shown until it gets approved by a few people. And they didn't approve it, so it didn't actually show up.

> It isn't normal behavior of system.

It is here! We have checks and balances for many user activities, in particular for new users.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a follow up question then ask a new question.

> I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/... ) but didn't understand this part:
>
> > Quote the part you need more information about
>
> What am I missing?

(or words to that effect).

Other than that, post a question or answer that gets one up vote. At that point you'll be able to vote up to thank the user.

If you want to comment then just get 5 answer up votes or 10 question up votes to earn 50 reputation.