# Add “works for me” comment with 1 reputation

Tags: feature-request, comments

There are numerous occasions when I find what I'm looking for on Stack Overflow and get my own code working, then want to vote up the answer or at least add a comment: "works for me" but need a higher reputation. Rather than post loads of pointless questions could there not be a "like" button or "works for me" button?  I recognise Stack Overflow depends heavily on reputation and that they are extremely important to prevent spammers, trolls and fakers. It does seem a tad too challenging to provide meaningful content, namely finding that an answer worked. I feel unwanted ;)

Comment: Why do you think a "works for me" comment would be meaningful content? The reason why you need more reputation to post comments is to avoid spam comments like that from users who don't know how the site works.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271165/how-i-can-thank-an-answerer-on-stack-overflow-if-i-dont-have-enough-reputation  Essentially, you are asked to earn enough rep so you can upvote.  Edits are often a good way to do it.

Comment: That's the point, I would like to add useful information. For example when I find an answer or just a comment that works, I would like to flag that and ideally add my comment with context to show how it worked. I had occasion today when I searched and found many answers, none of which worked. Finally, I found the correct answer in a comment that was deep down with no comments or anything. As a noob I can't add comments so couldn't flag it as useful.

Comment: @DavidSavage Then you should earn the reputation required to comment or upvote. These restrictions are well thought out and intentional.

Comment: A comment saying "works for me" will be automatically deleted by the system when flagged as 'not needed' because it's so devoid of meaning that even a computer can tell it's not needed.

Answer (score 19):

The tooltip on the upvote button says

> This answer is useful

That's *precisely* what we need; comments like 'works for me' are **pure noise**. [Comments](/help/privileges/comment) are meant to

> - Request **clarification** from the author;
> - Leave **constructive criticism** that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but **minor or transient information** to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

and **not** for

> - **Compliments** which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!"); instead, up-vote it and [pay it forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)

Comment: One needs a rep to do all that, no? That's the point of my request.

Comment: Yes, but only 15 (not 50). Making comments available to 1 rep users would cause massive spam waves, as comments aren't monitored. And reputation doesn't matter, a "works for me" even from Jon Skeet would be noise.