# Should I be worried if I most of my questions stay at 0 votes?

Tags: discussion, questions

Most of my questions stay at 0 upvotes.  I'm fine with that, but I'm worried that I'm doing something wrong.

I try to make sure that all of my questions are:

- Given descriptive titles
- Well Written
- Only asked if I'm stuck and can't find the answer by Googling or reading the appropriate docs

Is there nothing to worry about, or should I be doing something else?

Comment: No upvotes can also simply mean very few people were interested in viewing your question, and those that did didn't feel it was interesting enough to upvote.

Comment: It looks like you have quality answers on 3/4 of your questions (the last you posted less than an hour ago). Shouldn't that be more important?

Comment: Unfortunately really easy questions that shouldn't even be asked by developers who want to be developers tend to get upvoted more often. Based solely on that, i wouldn't worry about question score unless it goes negative.

Comment: With the meta effect, I'm so tempted to vote to close as: "The problem described here can no longer be reproduced...."

Comment: @Tanner You're so right.

Comment: I agree with gunr2171, reputation isn't the goal here.  Rather it's the transfer of knowledge.

Comment: I've noticed that beginner-level questions tagged [tag:haskell] tend not to get any votes, although their answers are often upvoted. I imagine different tags attract different voting cultures.

Comment: You shouldn't be worried about the votes for this question that's for sure :)

Comment: My questions very rarely get up-voted. And being an experienced user, they tend to be well-researched, well-titled and very specific. It used to really bug me, then I realised that challenging, hard questions attract fewer views and fewer up-votes. Still bugs me a bit though.

Comment: My only question has almost 2400 views to-date and no votes either way. It's just the way things fall sometimes.

Comment: You're lucky that you have not asked more questions. Otherwise the meta effect could be [reversed due to serial upvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Comment: @BonsaiOak : Questions like this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25838472?noredirect=1)?

Comment: @ouflak I believe people tend to upvote heavily upvoted questions more easily also... At least that is a tendency I saw in my own behavior. Which I'm trying to correct, by asking myself simple questions like "was it helpful?".

Comment: @Duncan I have this experience as well. Some of them even get downvoted. I think this is due to most of the upvotes being cast by new users, who often (not always) happen to be programmers with little to no experience. They don't understand the hard questions.

Comment: You  should check out the badges for tenacious and Unsung Hero

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Currently, your 4 questions are at 20, 27, 27, and 27 views. (But that may include the [Meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect); so subtract the number of views of *this* question to be sure. Which is 24, leading to either minus-4 views, or not everyone viewing this question *also* checked your SO questions.)

So, your questions are not viewed more than a dozen times -- and not *one* downvote. That is pretty good, since most first-timer's questions are so abysmally bad, they don't survive 5 *minutes* without being downvoted into oblivion.

This indicates that your questions are read by *a subset* of your target audience: people interested in [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb) (you're the only one), [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) and [meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meteor) (again, you're the only one). It's a subset because there not much time has passed since your first question (12-Sep-2014, just ten days ago) and some of your tags are obscure enough to attract only a small amount of field experts. They may have read your questions (and, noteworthy, did not find them worth *downvoting*), or, alternatively, they do what I do and only check up all of their favourite tags only once a week -- or even less.
The more obscure (in the SO sense only) a tag is, the lesser questions will be tagged with them; and questions using them, good *or* bad, may be far apart.

This suggests you would only need to wait a bit longer for up-votes. Your questions are not *bad*, but may be too obscure for the general population. If a field expert comes by, he may well consider them upvote-worthy.

Checking your tags I found you used a couple of *very* rare ones. With the amount of new questions passing by tagged only [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), you may be correct to assume "general" or "popular" tags may drown in this flood. Using obscure tags is a good way to avoid this, but only if the tags are not *too* obscure; per above, they may get too *little* attention.

All of that said: there seems nothing intrinsically wrong to your questions (for me, I feel some of them are a bit broad; then again, I'm not a field expert and those who *did* view your questions don't seem to think so). It's usually downvotes that have people turn to Meta; no need to worry about not getting upvotes either.

You're new to Stack Overflow, but [you got started very well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow). Don't worry about the null-votes; keep on asking good questions, and getting helpful answers. Reputation, it will come naturally.

Comment: Wow.  As you said, the rep did come naturally with time.  I just went from 23 to 66 rep overnight.  (Probably mostly having to do with the meta effect in this case.)

Comment: A reminder: the Meta effect can work both ways! But yeah, I'm glad to see the voters agreed with my eyeball assessment of the quality of your questions.

Comment: Yikes! Just the thought of that many people downvoting my posts is scary to think about.

Comment: @BonsaiOak: I find (maybe due to the questions shown) that good posts tend to get a lot less votes than they used to. Typically 5-10 votes for something really good, whereas it used to be possible to get much more in a  day for a great question/answer.

Comment: @Ian: well, given the amount of crap we sift through, I would not be surprised if this were due to questions being less *viewed* at all. Furthermore, it may be that "non-experts" in the fields do not feel confident enough to upvote.

Comment: Since we are limited to 40 total votes per day, i suspect a lot of people who do use a lot of votes tend to save them for downvotes more often now than in the past. I used to upvote a lot more than i downvote, but now i find myself doing primarily the latter.

Answer (score 2):

I view question with 0 as good and if you all your questions are 0 to 5 range you are making good contribution to SO. If you can edit your questions out of -3-1 range quickly you'll make a lot of people happier as you show that effort of answering/commenting is not wasted.

The way I look at numbers of votes for questions:

- -4 and less - really bad question, no effort show at all
- -3 to -1 - some effort shown, good chance of recovery *if* author care and updates post quickly
- 0 (no up/down) - good question, likely simple answer, unlikely to be generally useful. Be happy asking solid question.
- 0 (up/down matching in an hour) - good question, author shown good effort to edit and improve. Very welcome behavior.
- 0 (up/down matching over long time) for old question it turned out to be generally useful. Don't be proud of it as it has nothing to do with you asking good question.
- 1-5 - good and likely generally useful question.
- 5-30 quick votes (less than a day) - good research/clear sample and non obvious answer.
- 5-30 long term votes - really useful question.
- 30+ long term votes - FAQ, quality likely have absolutely nothing to do with original poster.

Answer (score -1):

If your questions are answered, what do votes matter? SO is not online for the beauty contest, but if you do care about reputation points then spend some more time sharing your knowledge.

Comment: The OP seems mainly worried about the *quality* of his questions.

Comment: Yes, I'm worried about the quality of my questions.  True story: Back when I was 13 years old I got kicked off of SO by a bot who noticed that most of my questions got downvoted. This is my second time around so I'm really trying to be careful.