# Questions and answers

Tags: discussion

Do you think it's possible to earn ANY significant stackoverflow points in 2014? This might be why people don't bother to try and answer questions now. Not only that, I have noticed that early on in the history of SO, some absolutely joke questions and answers have earned 1000's of points? Don't hate on me but I know you will so delete this.

Comment: _"Don't hate on me but I know you will so delete this."_ ... If you expect it to be deleted... Why did you post it? I'll add to that: If you think there's an issue with the ability to earn rep, provide examples. What kind of real discussion are you trying to have? I see a couple of tangentially related topics in your post here. Narrow down your point, and maybe give examples. If you want to have a discussion, initiate it, don't just give us a topic and let it roll.

Comment: you havent answered a question since 2012 (and asked one question this year) - how do you expect reputation to come to you? In the mail?

Comment: When you've been a registered SO user for 6 years and you averaged only one vote a week for your contributions then the probable answer is "no".  Little point in fretting about it now perhaps.

Comment: *Do you think it's possible to earn ANY significant stackoverflow points in 2014?* I got mine by exchanging Unicoins! I would be number 1 for the year, but Gordon Linoff uses goblins to mine them so he got more than me! You could mine Unicons too, send me a self-addressed stamped envelope with 1000 Unicoins and I'll tell you how!

Comment: "Questions and answers" is possibly the most generic title imaginable for a post on this network. I feel like you should get a prize.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: If you post questions that contain phrases like "Don't hate on me but I know you will so delete this...", you can rapidly **lose** reputation on SO. In order to earn reputation, you have to actually **participate** here - we don't award reputation for just lurking and whining.

Comment: hmmmm... just pointing it out... less than 6 months ago I had less than 100 rep, I'm now up to almost 1000..... not ALL tags get you there... butyeah, it's feasible, sorry

Comment: hmmm can you post those "joke questions and answers" , if you like you can post to discuss a way to remove those, ofcourse that's just your opinion, we might see them and say they are good, who knows

Answer (score 6):

Absolutely, it is possible to earn significant *points* (by which you mean reputation, I assume) on Stack Overflow. Don't forget that you can't earn more than 200 reputation in a day, so even those *joke* questions you talk about would have to be points gained over a significant amount of time.

The thing is, you gain the most rep from good quality questions that are **interesting** to other users. Tomorrow you might just ask or answer such a question and you'll be able to "live off the interest" where it becomes the highest ranked SO question on google, and every day you will earn 50 rep from it. Until then, you should continue to ask and answer good quality questions.

I have answered around 80 questions, and around half of them I have gained absolutely no rep whatsoever; some of which (IMHO) were particularly good answers. Other times I have got a good chunk of rep for relatively average answers.

But SO isn't just about reputation. In order to encourage users to answer less popular questions, we have some badges such as [Tenacious](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/225/tenacious) and [Unsung Hero](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero), which are awarded for various numbers of your accepted answers with a zero score.

In conclusion (using more clichés than anyone has ever done on SO before), you only get out what you put in to SO, what you gain on the swings you lose on the roundabouts, and that's just the way the cookie crumbles.

Of course, I won't gain any rep for *this* answer (just you wait and see) ;D

Comment: cAaarL! wHat iS wRong wITh yOu? thats the way the cookie crumbles when you [dont] put all your eggs in one basket; but no need crying over spilt milk - it is water under the bridge, after all.

Comment: (For what it's worth, he's not kidding about getting rep from old questions; I personally get roughly one upvote a month, and I've answered twice as much. Someone who's been around longer and posted even better answers will obviously get even more "residual" rep)

Comment: I don't have any friends here.

Comment: @DennisMeng well I'm using so for let's say 4 or 5 monthes and my answers are steady, I mean I didn't get any reputation from old answers(yet)

Comment: @niceman Give it time; getting a decent flow of residual rep is one of those things that takes a lot of time and patience. The rate depends on 1) how high quality your answers are, 2) how many high quality answers you've posted, and 3) how visible the questions are. If you're not making good posts (or at least, not many good posts), or just not answering questions that get that many views, then you're not going to have as much residual rep coming in as someone who is.