# Are my questions too special or am I asking them wrong?

Tags: discussion

On nearly daily basis, I'm seeing good questions and answers to those, when I Google my problems.
Most of those are here on Stack Overflow, so I decided to join in and ask two questions that I simply couldn't figure out.

I managed to solve one of them on my own, but the other one is still open.
I'm wondering if there is something wrong with the way I ask or with the question itself.
I know most (or all, not sure) of the users are doing this of their own will and aren't getting paid or anything to answer these questions, so I am not *complaining*, I am trying to figure out what I can do to ask the questions **better** or to find out what's wrong with them.

I would like some constructive comments, **if** there is something wrong with the questions.

Or maybe I was to excited about the Stack Overflow community and the questions where too specific or hard.

Comment: Your questions seem to have a large amount of code.  It is best to show only a minimal example to generate the problem.

Comment: Should I rewrite the question, which is still open or should I close it and refraise a new one?
I mean I did reduce the code a bit before asking and I think most of the code is mandatory for giving an example in that case.

Comment: I would definitely edit the questions

Comment: Ok, would this "reset" the questions position, so it can get attention?
Hope this doesn't sound wrong :D

Comment: Yes, editing will bump a post to the top of the new queue

Comment: Your question is rather broad or opinion based and not ONE question but several questions. If you ask to do things better / faster, please specify in which context? Faster in execution? faster/better for maintenance? faster in the UI layer? Faster in the DB? Peceived faster? And if you have working code you might check codereview.se if your question is on-topic there (visit their help and meta!)

Comment: Related: [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: @rene Is it better to split this question into multiple?
Also I did state that I would like to see faster responses on the UI level and I also thought that it would be obvious that I wouldn't ask an Oracle/DB performance related question, with this tags.
Thank you for the link to codereview, I will def take a look at that site. :)

Comment: Yes, ask one question. And for performance still goes: What are your current meassurements/timings, which path is taking the longest, where are you aiming for and what did you try to improve the performance.

Comment: Ok thank you all, very quick and helpful input.
I will try to refraise my question, maybe it will be anwsered then.

Comment: Please go easy on the formatting. _Italics_ are good for emphasis, ***bold italics*** is overkill. ***Writing entire paragraphs in bold, italics or both, is even extremely annoying.*** The larger "headings" in between can also be in the regular font. Finally, you don't have to ask for *any* suggestion -- you have stated your questions, and if anyone has anything more to offer, you're sure to get a comment on it.

Comment: In case you missed the CodeReview link: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 63, accepted):

[I put your question on hold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25997429/how-to-quickly-show-new-data-from-oracledb-using-wpf-and-possible-ss-paging) to give you a shot to fix it.

Here's what I suggest:

- Reduce the scope of your question to one part of your application. It could be the database, it could be the rendering, whatever.
- If you have a *problem* with that part of your application, give us just enough detail to reproduce the problem. Menu doesn't render like you think it should? Application repaints everything on every load?  Give us a small isolated example that reproduces that issue.
- If your application is slow, narrow it down to whichever part you need help with. Database? Then give us a straight query; the table structure; sample data; and how long it takes vs. how long it should take? In your case, you have dynamic SQL, and there can be a few reasons why it's slow (no indexes, no ability to cache the query plan since you're not parameterizing your queries (depending on your settings); bad statistics (based on the whole parameterization thing), `SELECT *`. It could be a lot of things.  So, give us a query, its execution performance, what you'd like to get it down to, and the indexes, table structure, parameterization settings, etc.

Does this sound like a lot of work?

It is.

It's also required.  Not so much for us (although it is), but more so for you.  If we give you a copy/paste solution, it may not work; and even worse is that you may not understand it to the depths you need to to know how to apply it.  By framing the question in such a way where you've done all this research first, you've made our job easier (we don't give you a false answer), and you've learned a lot in the process so when we tell you to add specific indexes and only query on what you need, you know what that means.

There are four approaches to well-received questions:

- An easy subject that everyone knows about
- a problem everyone has
- luck
- hard work, research, cutting the cruft out of your question, and focusing on one thing.  Giving us everything we need to solve your issue without burdening us with things that don't matter.

Your question falls into the last category. Good luck.

Comment: *`↑↑↑   art of asking a question on SO`*

Comment: I will try to rethink my question and set the focus on my main issue, very nice and constructiv answer. Thank you very much.
How can I "disable" the hold, after I did the edit?

Comment: @MichaM. After you edit the question, it'll automatically get kicked into the re-open queue.  The community will review it and if the edit makes it clear and answerable (and addresses the issues I brought up in my answer), it'll be re-opened.   Since I'm already directly involved, if you reply to my comment on your question, I can look and see if it should be reopened right then.