# Is there any way to be helpful besides answering questions?

Tags: discussion, flags, answers, edits

I have a lot of questions because I'm relatively new to programming. I'm trying to solve as many as I can before asking here, but I still have a lot left. Also, I haven't yet found any questions I can answer yet.

Are there any other ways I can be helpful on the site?

Comment: I don't think that question really is a duplicate. OP is asking about how to help, not how to ask questions. At low rep, the only tools available to help improve the site is to suggest edits or flag low quality content, but please make substantial edits and only flag actually problematic content as it all needs to be reviewed by actual humans who'll spend actual time doing it.

Comment: @ivarni: fair point. If this question gets re-opened, you could submit your comment as an answer, as there is not very much more to say about it. *Helpful* would be closing bad questions, editing bad grammar, and the occasional bout of LQ post reviewing -- but all of these need a substantial amount of rep.

Comment: Prettify: format [your code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26559669/119775) `as code`. Makes it more legible. Which is helpful.

Comment: @Laura, I personally have just started programming as well (about a year ago now), and was wondering the same thing that you are wondering now, at that time. The major reason is because it was so frustrating that I couldn't even engage in other people's conversation to help understand! _I felt as if I was a child at the children's table_. That being said, my resolution was just to get better. To study more, to code more, to bring up good questions, etc. Eventually, this leads to being better than some (where I am now), which leads to points. It will all come in due time :)

Comment: You've found meta, care about the quality of your contributions and are actively trying to improve the site. That's a good start.

Answer (score 12):

As a newcomer, your options are limited. Certain things get unlocked by reputation. However, there's very definitely ways of being helpful that aren't just answering:

- Editing questions for clarity/tags.
- Commenting on poor questions by obvious newbies steering them towards asking *good* questions.
- Finding/flagging duplicates.

But as said - there's a reputation threshold to unlock these, because the idea is - you gain reputation as you gain familiarity with how Stack Exchange sites work.

As a side suggestion - there is a 100 reputation bonus available once you get 200 rep on any Stack Exchange site. 100 reputation is enough to get started with. You may find you can answer questions more effectively in a different subject area.

Comment: *"200 rep on any stack overflow site"* - did you mean *StackExchange*...?

Answer (score 8):

I've asked myself that many times in the past, especially when new to one of the sites.
Now that I'm 58k+ on the stack exchange network I can reflect on my experience.

So, the best answer I have found is actually just to practice your craft and see what questions arise and what newly learned knowledge can help you provide answers to others and to pose good questions that others will want to engage in, upvote, etc..

Another approach that can help is to ask questions (and provide answers) to new technology areas.  For example questions and answers about Visual Basic and C++ are likely to: already be asked; already have answers; be answered quickly by experts.  However questions about Ruby on Rails version 4 or new approaches to using MongoDB are more likely to be questions and answers that you can get points for.

It is also a good idea, as you start to have good answers and to have asked good questions to link to them in other, possibly highly-read questions/answers.  Use the actual 'link' link as this will include your id.  Obviously you should only do this only actual questions/answers that are relevant to the one you link to (judgement call of course).

Also 'upgrade' your own (or others) questions and answers as time goes by to:

- provide more detail
- add helpful tags to existing questions, especially when your answer has up votes
- provide the content referred to in links.
- update out-of-date links with new urls.
- add tags to your own homepage view so that the questions are more relevant to you.
- delete your own 'bad' q&a's that got downvotes.

Answer (score 7):

What you do after your question is answered is important as well.

When you get an answer:

- select it if that's the correct one
- vote for it if appropriate
- comment on it if that's not helping - explaining why

Ignoring people who took time to help you out is the worst you can do.

Once your issue is resolved, you can also edit your original question adding any extra useful information for someone who's facing a similar issue (an incorrect assumption you've made for example).

Answer (score 4):

Questions and answers are the bread and butter of Stack Overflow. At the end of the day, everything revolves around quality questions with expert answers.

One of the things we strive for is a high *signal-to-noise ratio*. It's the most important metric we have, even if it isn't exactly quantifiable as a metric... We want to trust that if we go to a series of random questions that they're all high quality and helpful. The most obvious way to help the site is to supply quality questions and expert answers to increase that ratio. But you're looking for ways outside of that. Well...

- The best place to do this is the **Review queue**. You won't have access to this until you reach 500 rep, so you'll want to grind out that reputation to get here. Once you're in here, you have access to thousands of questions that need attention. Close votes. Low quality posts. Suggested edits. These queues give you a nearly endless supply of "grunt work" that helps the site keep its quality ratio up.
- **Meta burninate requests**: Sometimes there are tags that need some cleanup because they're used wrong, or that need to be deleted outright. We don't want to leave questions without any tags, though. Unfortunately, you'll need more rep before you can do this without pushing it all into the review queue though. Once again, grind out the rep (I think it's 2,000...) and when you're there, this tag cleanup helps make the site much more accessable.
- **Clean up your favorite tags**: you don't have permission to edit questions and answers outright, but you are allowed to suggest edits. So be on the lookout for questions that could use a little love. Not one or two typos, those are rather minor. But code blocks that need indenting; non-english-first-language users who get idioms or grammar wrong: even if you can't answer his question, if you can clean up the text so it's clear to others, the question has a higher chance of getting answered.

Remember that in the Stack Exchange philosophy, we are all moderators gradually increasing in our ability to moderate. The 'diamond moderators' do not have significantly more moderation features than a high-rep user.

So it all boils down to you acquiring more rep to unlock the [moderation features](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges?tab=moderation) of the site. Note that the last one, suggesting edits, will earn you 2 rep per approved edit, which will get you on your way. But you can pull a few hundred rep from a solid question or answers, so in terms of reputation per unit effort you'll find edits to be a slow, slow grind.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you upset with me for not participating in the community enough? OP asked what else she could do to help. I said what she could to do help. I think retags are very important. I do spend more time (diamond) moderating [another SE site](http://sqa.stackexchange.com) than I do on Stack Overflow, but I won't apologize for not doing more on SO. I commit the spare cycles I can to the site [that I'm reasonably passionate about.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265428/330057) Not knowing their lives, I wouldn't ask more than that of anyone.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the reputation to downvote questions, downvote questions that you think deserve to be downvoted. Read the hover text of the downvote button for guidance.

Yes, downvoting is helpful. It helps people by signalling which questions are not worth looking at. It can make a very bad question eligable for deletion. As another answerer mentions, maintaing a high signal to noise ratio keeps the site worthwhile.