# Am I allowed to answer questions as a new user?

Tags: discussion

I'm new to this website and I want to answer some questions. But I can't find the answer button at all. Am I allowed to answer as a new user?

Comment: Check out the bottom page, the "Post Your Answer" button. Also take a few minutes to read the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/answering)

Comment: Please do answer questions! Note that questions which have been closed or placed "on hold" cannot accept new answers (plus some other less commonly encountered situations)

Comment: Yes, you are allowed to answer questions. [This post contains very useful information for new users, please read it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow) and welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: I didn't ask a question until I had posted ~7200 answers. And then I posted the answer with my question. I think that means you are allowed to answer without having asked a question.

Comment: Given that you asked this in the wrong place, I'd say no.  Not until you lurk a little, figure out how stuff works around here, and then only if you have a good answer.