# Is there a "first steps" guide somewhere for using any of the Stack Exchange websites?

Tags: discussion, privileges, meta

I know this question is "off-topic" here, but frankly, there's no other place to ask it if you have "no" reputation. I tried to use https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask (where it probably belongs), but you have to have a reputation of +5 to ask a question there. And through search of questions there, it doesn't seem anyone has ever asked this (quite strange in itself).

I've read all of the help articles (https://stackoverflow.com/help) including help on privileges (https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) and reputation (https://stackoverflow.com/help/reputation), but there is no information on exactly what steps a "newbie" should take to start gaining reputation to interact with the website!

I use "newbie" in quotes because I've been using this website for years to get answers to questions I have. However, I've never been able to contribute because I don't have a high enough reputation.

Point blank -- there needs to be a step-by-step guide to joining the site and building reputation, like:

1. Sign up
2. Vote on 5 answers
3. Answer 3 questions
4. Ask 2 questions
5. Flag 4 questions
6. Etc...

Otherwise, you're always going to have people who want to help, but can't (or don't know how).

Comment: A newbie can (1) ask questions, (2) answer questions. If you ask good questions/answer good answers, you'll get some reputation in no time...

Comment: [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: The first step for most new users: ask a poorly written off-topic question and get downvoted into oblivion

Answer (score 0):

Read the unanswered question list https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers and answer one or two. Also, you can ask your own questions. The rep will start flooding in, don't worry.

Comment: That may be a good starting point, you'll have to survive the peer reviews though.