# How do I find questions that are more "my level"?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, search

I'm new here and would love to help the community as much as possible but I keep running into the problem where either questions are already answered or are far past my level. Is there anything I can do to find questions that fit me better?

Is there any filter in the search, tags, etc.?

Comment: F5ing the question page helped me, then beating others by fractions of a second to the answer got me to where I am today.

Comment: Partially duplicate of [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252149/2564301), partially [answered in the Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging): "Tags can also be used to [help you identify questions that are interesting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics) or relevant to you" [*sic* the hyperlink in that sentence].

Comment: you are in luck: most questions on SO are simple. Just [follow new questions in your favoriate tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).

Comment: I’m having trouble finding questions that are not low quality…

Comment: @Xufox low quality !== low level/easy

Comment: I think the problem is that most people would prefer to answer easy questions. So, unless different bonuses are given for easy/difficult questions, everyone would answer the easy ones first.

Comment: @KevinB I know. I just have the feeling that most questions within my tags that I encounter aren’t answerable, because they don’t show enough research effort, are unclear or are duplicates (i.e. _lower_ quality). I actually sometimes explicitly search for the most recent questions that have a positive score (i.e. _higher_ quality) and I often miss the opportunity to find them and to answer them (as they often already have an answer). What I want, is to answer _good_ questions, not necessarily _easy_ or _too easy_ questions. I kind of wish, I had Lea's “problem”.

Comment: Use that as an opportunity to turn them into answerable questions by providing feedback on the question in the form of votes, close flags/votes, and most importantly, comments.

Comment: Don't just try to answer questions you already know the answer to. Unless you are only doing it for rep (why?) use answering questions as a chance to learn something.  So pick questions that are slightly above your comfort level and actually try to figure out the answer. I'm surprised to see people say they prefer easy questions, I don't find them rewarding. You'll hear right away if you really get it wrong.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

First of all, answering questions that are already answered is sometimes viable: accepted answer is not necessarily good. If you know something about the already "solved" problem that other answers have not mentioned, feel free to add yours. This is especially true for "novice-level" questions that sometimes attract answers that appear to be correct, work out well and get accepted, but are in fact misleading or completely wrong.

You might get a bunch of upvotes or even get your answer accepted (in an event the OP decides that yours is **that** better). That happened to me yesterday.

As for finding the questions: pick some areas you understand the most (or want to) and search the corresponding tags for questions you can answer or **find out how to answer**. This way **you'll likely learn something new**. Even if someone answers before you can, **the experience gained in the process won't disappear and will gradually raise your level**, allowing you to answer a broader range of questions that don't attract good enough answers faster than you can write one.

Comment: `find out how to answer` I'm by no means a super experienced developer and this is exactly what I try and do. I research questions that interest me and try to form a complete and helpful answer. Sometimes someone else beats me and I give up, sometimes I'm wrong (and just delete my unhelpful answer), but most of the time I learn something along the way. And teaching others is the best way to learn!

Comment: @jkeuhlen exactly. The great part about this is that you can watch any tag you want to know more about, provided that it has some questions appearing on SO regularly. Sometimes when writing another answer I wonder how many folks like you or me will walk the same path through my answer.

Comment: This is especially true for tags with a bit lower activity where there are a few experts around, but the general noise level in answers is very low, like the [perl] tag I'm active in. We usually beat each other to writing an answer for simple questions, but since there are no more than 20 to 50 questions per day, all the interested people will look at most questions. Some of them answer. If they come back and see your later-added answer that is good those seasoned (I'm talking 10k+ rep) users will almost allways vote you up.

Answer (score 40):

It depends on the things that you work with. If you're into [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), then you really only need to keep an eye on [the feed of recently active questions](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/java) - it tends to be an 'omelette' when it comes to complexity and difficulty.

If you're into [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c),  then you'd probably want to keep an eye on questions about [pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pointers), and possibly [memory-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-management), which sometimes mention [valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/valgrind) or [gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gdb).

If [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) is your thing, then you'll generally find folks struggling with queries in [mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysqli), and folks with framework-specific questions in those various tags. New programmers often need help [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debugging).

For every tag view, there's a link to a feed at the bottom of the page. It takes a little while and some tweaking, but you can *generally* find questions that are likely to be at a certain level of difficulty by refining tag searches. It's also easy to see stuff tagged a certain way that is also unanswered.

Just be careful to watch for duplicates. Look at the "Related" list of questions in the sidebar when viewing a question, could this have been asked before in a slightly different way? Once you get 50 rep, you can flag these to suggest closing them as duplicates.

As you go through questions, don't be shy about suggesting edits that could improve them. Titles are pretty critical for a question to get the attention it needs, as you'll see when you start browsing feeds to look for things to answer. If you see something like "Issue in Java", *edit that* to actually summarize the question. You get 2 rep for each edit you suggest, up to 1k total rep through editing. It's a great way to unlock some creature comforts while you look for the best way to dive in.

Comment: "It tends to be an omelette"?!

Comment: I like the language-specific suggestions. Could you give some suggestions concerning 'javascript'?

Comment: Except you generally remove the shell before you throw the egg into the omelette. :)

Comment: @biziclop and try to include food in it instead of... well... anything you can find

Comment: @AakashM Meaning everything is mixed all together of course.

Comment: To the topic: it's a good answer for a question "How to find a question on my topic" or "How to begin on SO". The question it tho about the questions **on my level**. I don't think we have a **filter** that does that. It's also worth to note that **it doesn't necessarily mean that if you're here longer, your level goes up**. And one more thing: I think the OP's question is absolutely relevant. I would like to filter by the level of expertise needed to give an answer.

Comment: @Harbinger For javascript, i would suggest not following the javascript tag directly, but instead following something related to javascript such as ajax, node.js, or maybe a js library that you're familiar with such as angular or jQuery. javascript is such a heavily followed tag that it would be difficult to beat the FGITW answers as a new user.

Comment: @wiktus239 No, not officially per level, but if you look at tags applied to .. _less hard_ questions, it's not difficult to look for patterns that human intuition can spot much better than software can .. ***for now*** :)

Comment: Sometimes language specific questions are not the issue. The implementation or algorithm is the main focus of the question and answer. Many people may know their favorite or most used language very well and write a solid code base, but at times may struggle to determine which is the appropriate algorithm or how to properly construct it. Since that same algorithm can be done similarly in all most all languages the language isn't a factor. Now as for one who is answering questions then that may lean towards their language of choice since they are most comfortable with it.

Answer (score 10):

In the search box, type your favourite tag and "answers:0". If you want the newbie questions, you can also type "newbie".

> [C++] answers:0 newbie

Then on the results screen, click on the Newest tab to sort them by date/time.

Scroll down a bit to get past the questions that were posted in the last couple of minutes. Those are the ones that are being answered right now!

If you get to the older ones that still have no answers, you can answer those at your leisure.

Avoid, however, questions with too many upvotes. Highly upvoted questions with no answers are the hard ones! Save those for later, when you are more experienced.

Comment: When I do this search, the most recent one is a week old.  Am I doing something wrong?  Did you try this before suggesting it?  Did the upvoters try it before upvoting?

Comment: @Yakk That's right, the latest C++ question that says it's from a newbie is that old. If you want, you can search for questions without the word "newbie" though, then the latest is from 1 min ago. Edit: or you can try different tags. [php] questions with "newbie" in them are more prevalent!

Comment: Questions don't have "newbie" in them for long, because that word is found in introductory spiel that does not belong in SO posts.

Answer (score 7):

See, the whole point here is to not BUCKET yourself in a single level. Choose the technology you are currently working or learning or are interested in.

Go to Tags right next to Questions, it has already categorized the questions with the help of tags. Read along and see if you can solve any of the issues others are facing. Or try to relate to the issue and think on WHY it is happening. Try it yourself!

The best way to start off would be to actually start off with something. If you get stuck, search here for similar questions and read the answers. See if it solves yours. If something worked out for you, help out someone with the same.

If you want to do the level-wise thing, try out codeacademy or tutorialspoint.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem as you. I really wanted to contribute, but whenever a question suitable for my level came along, someone else would answer it faster and better. I felt a little bit like a leech, for only recieving answers, and not contributing to them myself.

I think that this is a little bit like being a good author. In order to write well; read a lot. I've been a member for nearly three and a half years, and I just recently started answering questions. In fact i think I got my first accepted answer this very week. I am no Jon Skeet, or Martijn Peters, but I am finally getting to a point where I can be useful, and contribute to others.

So my advice is, dont' rush it. You'll be a much better teacher if you allow yourself to be a student first.

Answer (score 3):

Very late to the party, but often times I find the questions that are out of my league have associated tags with them that I know nothing about. For example, I feel very comfortable with Java, but have no idea how to do anything with Android.

So if I'm looking for Java questions I can answer I search something like `[java] -[android]`, and still get a good feed of Java questions without APIs that are completely foreign to me.

Answer (score 1):

If there's an area you know something about but which isn't a very popular subject on SO, easy-to-answer questions hang around a lot longer without getting an accepted answer - or even any answers. There's a lot of competition to answer questions with popular tags, and unfortunately this means that it can be very tough to get a chance to answer the simpler ones, especially if you take time over your answer. This is much less of an issue in many more niche tags.

The downside of responding to older questions can sometimes be that the person has wandered off and never sees it. And in general, answering questions in a niche area won't cause you to rack up reputation points as quickly as in other tags. But that said, if you're interested in helping the community it's quite rewarding as you may well be answering questions which otherwise would have remained unanswered.

Obviously this advice is a bit useless if you don't have knowledge of such a topic, but I'd suggest it's worth having a look through tags related to things you know, and seeing whether any look like they could use more attention.

Answer (score 1):

You may not feel like you can answer questions to improve yourself.

```
\\ Don't be afraid to ask questions.
```

Sure, you get pixie points for writing a good concise answers. I was never formally taught coding (I was raised by wolves on punch cards) I found that asking questions helped. Several people thought that some of my early questions were for homework assignments - I left school a loooong time ago and I didn't really care for those comments - but I did find an awful lot of very useful answers. There are clever, kind people out there that want to help others. Listen to them.

The **real** secret to getting ahead on Stack Overflow - learn Regular Expressions - there will *always* be RE questions to answer.

But you have to be really good at RE.

And really fast.