# How do I answer others' questions when I have a lack of experience?

Tags: discussion, support, questions

I'm not advanced at programming. I'm just not. But I want to answer others' questions on the site because, from my understanding, it appears like good etiquette for the site. Do I need to answer others' questions, and what do I do if I feel like I don't know what I'm talking about half the time because the person asking the question is probably ahead of me?

Comment: learn first then help others, is the only mantra, nothing else.

Comment: You don't have to answer questions if you just don't know the answer. There's zero obligation to do so. You can easily give back to the community by just keeping your questions that you post high-quality and on-topic. Really, even if you _do_ know the answers, there's nothing anywhere that says you _have_ to post an answer.

Comment: If you really want to contribute then rather than finding questions that you already know the answer to, find a question and then *figure out the answer yourself* and then post what you've come up with.  It's one of the best ways to become an expert in a topic.

Comment: ... I think "spam" is a bit of a stretch. There's a difference between putting oneself out there and straight-up astroturfing.

Answer (score 17):

You're not required to answer questions, particularly if you don't feel comfortable with your expertise in a given area. There are other ways you can contribute, such as taking the time to ask unique, well-written, and thoughtful questions. You can help to edit poorly written questions into shape.

I started out on the site in a manner like Servy describes above. I sat down every morning and found one or two unanswered questions that I was interested in. I then tried to figure out the answer to those questions, often by writing little throwaway projects. It was a tremendous learning experience, and helped make me a better developer.

Try finding unanswered questions where you don't have people falling over one another to answer. While you won't build a tremendous number of immediate votes for good answers to these, you'll see those votes come in over time as other people hit the same problem. Almost all of the score I have on this site was built in that manner.

Finally, read a bunch of good answers. Learn from how they explain their solutions and try to apply that to your own writing. Improving your communication skills in that way can have huge benefits outside of your participation here.

Answer (score 4):

> what do I do if I feel like I don't know what I'm talking about half the time because the person asking the question is probably ahead of me?

My advice is to answer only for the other half of the time -- those times you *do* know what you're talking about.  That's might be a little hard with your limited experience, but it's certainly possible.   Follow specific tags that you are familiar with.  For example, when I first started I browsed [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) because it had more schoolbook questions that I could answer.  This will help you find more questions where you do know what you're talking about.  For other new user considerations, read [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow).  That post is a bit more geared towards getting privileges and reputation, but it has useful information for new users.

Answering is good etiquette if your answers are well-formed and honest attempts to completely answer the question.  You are under no obligation to answer anything, and really I would advise you to be selective on when you try to  answer a question.  Incomplete or erroneous answers are likely to get downvoted because they are not helpful.