# Why is contributing on Stack Overflow impossible?

Tags: discussion

Most of the time when I reply to a new question with an answer that might have a small error in it, but other than that it's fine, I get downvoted. Sometimes for no reason/no explanations given. I took my time to help somebody and I get thanked with a reputation points drain.

On another question where somebody asked for something he could have easily found on Google, I posted an answer with the link(s) the person was most likely looking for and people rained downvotes on the asker and the answerer obviously unfairly just because it was a redundant question.

Why is it impossible to contribute on this site? You get punished or not rewarded by upvotes or whatever for trying to help most of the time so why even bother? The only way to use this site is to ask decent questions and to post a decent answer to **popular** questions you googled so that you might get some upvotes after all.

Comment: Suggested read [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late)

Comment: Posting decent answers to _good questions_ (not popular ones) will make an impact here. Posting answers to bad questions won't, because the bad questions tend not to live long.

Comment: "might have a small error in it"... then why do you post without being sure? Also... if the question is bad, stay away from it.. some people will DV anything on a bad post.

Comment: See also [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: Choose some tags where you're knowledgeable and add them to your Favorite Tags. Then watch the homepage for new questions. When one is asked, and it is thorough and understandable and well-asked, take a shot at answering it. If your answer is also thorough, you will without any doubt gain reputation for your efforts.

Comment: *question where somebody asked for something he could have easily found on Google, I posted an answer with the link(s)* Thanks for being part of the problem.

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza would you agree with my post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305491/stack-overflow-junior

Comment: @Craig
Page Not Found

Comment: wrt posting an answer with the link(s) you better keep in mind that [meta-tag:link-only-answers] are quite heavily discouraged over here. Answers are expected to be able to stand on their own, links are okay _only_ as a complementary details

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why is it impossible to contribute on this site?

It's not impossible to contribute.  [Badges are awards to recognize various kinds of contributions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17854/280467).  Looking at the [list of badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges), you can see many different avenues of contributing to Stack Overflow.  So if answering isn't working out for you, try asking questions or  moderating the site (you have 500 rep and access to basic [review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/review)).  Voting and editing are also an important aspect of participation.  Every vote you cast and every post you help to clean is a contribution.

> On another question where somebody asked for something he could have easily found on Google, I posted an answer with the link(s) the person was most likely looking for and people rained downvotes on the asker and the answerer obviously unfairly just because it was a redundant question.

That's how our voting culture works.  People downvote questions for "lack of research."  People might also downvote the answers to these questions to try to discourage duplicating a lot of information.  If it's obviously google-searchable, many users will try to find the duplicate post first and close the question as such.  That way there's less clutter on the site.

Answer (score 27):

> The only way to use this site is to ask decent questions and to post a decent answer...

That's all. If you post answers with errors in them, fix the errors. Don't bother posting links you quickly found on Google as answers to questions that didn't need to be posted in the first place. Just stick to quality questions and answers.

Comment: (also suggest edits, but point taken :-) )

Comment: Ooh reviews and other moderation are another important aspect of contributing to the SO community.

Comment: You can also try a pedagogical approach when you answer a question, like some people do :] (@MichaelBerkowski)

Comment: @Rizier123 Right on. Our little club needs to grow :-)