# What should I do if the community isn't effectively answering a question, but I don't have rep to clafiry?

Tags: discussion, answers

There is a question that requires some specialized knowledge that I have, here:

[StringIndexOutOfBoundsException Java Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32525184/stringindexoutofboundsexception-java-error)

The comments on the question are from people who, while I'm sure are very knowledgeable in Java, clearly don't have experience with the Niagara framework.  In particular, they are asking for details of methods that are part of the pre-built framework, not actually code the questioner has written.

I suspect this is why the question itself is down-voted.

This is my area of specialized expertise.  I could help with the question based on what the user has provided, but I need clarification to properly format a good answer.  However, I haven't managed to get my rep high enough to comment (seriously, it is really freaking hard to get rep here).

I can see the justification for restricting commenting as it is, but in my specific edge case--where I can see a question that is clearly not going to be answered by the community, and I have still not earned enough rep for the tools I need to effectively answer it myself--which is the lesser of two evils?  Should I leave the question un-answered, so that future users won't be helped if they come across it, or should I at least attempt the best answer I can give with the information I've got?

Comment: _"seriously, it is really freaking hard to get rep here"_ Not really, see [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow?s=1|1.9490).

Comment: If you answer with a less than optimal answer, it might get downvoted. If you answer with a question asking for clarification (that should have been a comment) it will get downvoted and then deleted. You might also want to read 
 [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ: Erm...all the answers to that topic boil down to "Yup, it sure is hard, isn't it?  Here are a few tools to make it marginally easier"

Comment: The OP has moved on quite a while ago, probably figured out how to debug it.  Pretty unlikely you'll do anybody a favor with an answer, not a good way to fish for votes.

Comment: None of the top answers (including my accepted one) on that topic boil down to anything approaching "it sure is hard." You're unlikely to get 50 reputation from a single answer, but it's far from difficult to get over that bar.

Comment: @Frank not to sound demeaning... but you have 4 posts in 8 months of membership... while they are decent posts, it's not necessarily a lot of activity that would give you the required rep to comment. You say "it's hard" but looking at your profile, you don't seem to really do a lot to try and gain rep either...

Comment: I guess I'm unlcear in my initial post, but not sure how to clarify.  Specifically, when I say "specialized," I mean "there are (exactly) three questions that I could contribute to asked in the last year."  Since it seems like the only real way to contribute is with highly expert knowledge it is hard (for me, at least)

Comment: @Frank then edit some posts? Each suggested edit you get approved gives you 2 points, up to 1000 points (no more points once you hit 2K rep)

Comment: @Patrice: Not taking it as demeaning, but the reason why there are so few posts is because I usually answer questions myself, either through independent research or through previously answered SO questions.  I haven't really grokked any other way to acquire rep with my particular skill set.  I will look into editing, I guess.

Comment: @Frank and honestly, that is commendable of you to find your own answers to your problems (not a lot of users do this here unfortunately). Maybe if your problem isn't super specific, you could use that research to post a self answered question? Be careful though, they can be tricky to get just right

Comment: @Patrice I don't think self-answered questions are difficult to get right. The problem that I see self-answerers fall into is that they don't write the question and answer *for others*. Q: "Why is this jQuery function not submitting my form? [OP helpfully includes HTML and JavaScript code.]" A: "Turns out I had an error in my server code. The SQL transaction was never committed. LOL! [Of course this answer does not include any details about the server and the question did not either.]"

Comment: @Frank - The only things you need to know to make good edits are: fix all problems with the post (don't fix capitalization but leave spelling errors), don't add your own new content to questions (adding code they placed in fiddles/comments is OK), don't change the original author's meaning, and don't edit posts that need to be closed for other reasons, *especially* spam.

Comment: Are there any other programming areas that you have knowledge in that you could answer questions in? If you limit yourself down to a very small area, you're going to have a very hard time getting past the early rep thresholds. I wouldn't suggest resorting to editing if it isn't something you enjoy, because then it just becomes a chore and you may not put enough attention into it to do it correctly/effectively.

Comment: @HansPassant Actually, the way the software works the OP probably still has a working system despite the errors, it's probably just cluttering their console with stack traces, even if they never worked out the issue.

Comment: @KevinB Broadly, I have experience and knowledge in Java, but I don't have much expertise with various tools out there (e.g. Guice) which pretty much everyone uses, and which comprise most of the new questions.

Comment: If you see a good question then just ask it yourself.  You can post the answer as well.  Just be sure to follow the normal Q+A format and requirements.

Answer (score 5):

1. The question doesn't talk about specific conditions that cause the crash. A read through of it makes it seem that the first debugging step was to post it on SO.  (I'm not saying that's what happened, just that it doesn't show any work done towards a solution. The OP didn't say what they tried to get it working.)
2. The original question didn't have a complete stack trace. [It seems now that it the linked content has been incorporated.]
3. Leading with code is exactly the opposite of the guidance in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

   > Introduce the problem before you post any code
   >
   > In the body of your question, start by expanding on the summary you put in the title. Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself. The first paragraph in your question is the second thing most readers will see, so make it as engaging and informative as possible.
4. Some visitors to the site will never make it past the wall of code before figuring that the question doesn't apply to them.
5. You can always qualify an answer with: "Based on the question as it stands it looks like..." and update it with clarification.  If the community finds it useful, it will get up voted.  If not it will get downvoted.
6. Rep: This is difficult to address.  There are lots of ways you can build it. At a glance you have 3 decent questions and 1 decent answer. To put it into perspective, it's 4 items on a site with hundreds more Qs & As coming in every minute.
7. Last but probably most important: *How* people vote is entirely up to them.  The law of averages suggests that if the question stays on the site, eventually it will have the votes it intrinsically deserves.

Comment: The formatting of the question is poor.  However, Niagara AX is an esoteric tool, that most of SO isn't familiar with.  Asking for the stack trace sort of leads responses down a red herring, because they see the code as a typical Java project, when I can virtually guarantee the only actual explicit lines of code the OP wrote were what they posted.  The rest is all graphical programming--the OP is (likely) not going to have any idea what the stack trace even means, because it's tracing into pre-built, pre-compiled objects that are represented by pictures in the Niagara Framework.