# Give a suggestion on Stack Overflow, not an answer

Tags: feature-request

Stack Overflow is a nice place to get answers/give answers. At this point I see people's reputation points removed, because they didn't answer the question. Now I'm at the point were the answer is already given (not marked as answer yet), but I have a suggestion (not really an improvement).

What would the proper way be when you don't have enough points to comment?

I suggest to create a new option called suggestions... as they are not really comments or answers.

It is not an **answer**, but definitely an improvement for others who are reading the question. So it's not a comment either. Just a **suggestion** or if suggestion falls short an **improvement** to the question.

Comment: Or the standard option: get 50 rep (like by suggesting meaningful edits) and then comment.

Comment: No, Nope, Nada, Nein! Stack Overflow is designed as a FAQ format style Q&A site, not for opinionated suggestions. These are explicitly off-topic here for good reasons.

Comment: Your proposal could benefit from some examples.  What would constitute a "suggestion" and how would it differ from an answer or a comment.  And why is it necessary?  Is the only purpose of this idea is to allow users who can't comment to propose vague solutions?

Comment: _"Just a suggestion or if suggestion falls short an improvement to the question."_ So are you meaning it's a suggestion to _improve the post_ or a suggestion of what the answer could be? If the former... That is _exactly_ what comments are for.

Comment: Finally Kendra explained it in terms I can understand.

Comment: Judging by some of the comments here, I think a few people thought you meant suggesting an answer. Until your edit, I thought that as well. Might be where the disconnect was. Your best bet is to try to get up to 50 rep so you can comment- No need to introduce an extra feature. You can do that by 1) writing good answers to questions, 2) asking good questions, or 3) suggesting good edits that improve posts. For some good ways to get started and get earning rep, check out [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252149/)

Comment: @Kendra while these are definitely good suggestions, dave posted another question about being answer banned, so for HIM, I think "1)" will start with "edit your current answers to be in better shape so they get upvoted and you can start answering in full"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you *only* intend to suggest...don't.  Suggestions are nice in theory, but they don't make for good Q&A material.

If you have an actual *improvement* to an answer, then you should be able to post that as an answer itself.  You need to be clear that this is building on an existing answer, and ensure that it also directly answers the question while still remaining an improvement.

Comment: could you elaborate on how to do an actual _improvement_ and that you're building on an existing answer?

Comment: It's a case-by-case scenario for most questions, but...[this is an instance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20320177/1079354) of me doing this personally.

Answer (score 2):

As [Makoto's answer suggests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308839/1380752) you could give an additional answer which applies to the question. For instance, if it is fixing a typo, adding a relevant link to the current answer, or somehow improves the current answer then you could suggest an edit which will incidentally help you to get to the needed 50 rep to leave comments (assuming the suggested edit doesn't change the meaning of the original answer).

Also, [ryanyuyu's comment is a good suggestion, as well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308838/give-suggestion-on-stackoverflow-not-an-answer/308840#comment263310_308838)

And if [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308838/give-suggestion-on-stackoverflow-not-an-answer#comment263315_308839) gets deleted then this answer won't make as much sense.