# Seeking more information on open question without spamming

Tags: discussion

I'm a relatively new user, working hard to accumulate the reputation necessary to leave a comment on an unanswered question (50 rep required) that's a few months old.  I'm attempting to leave a comment to request that the OP update the question if he/she has had any offline progress with the issue.

Obviously I don't want to ask in the answer form, nor do I want to create a duplicate question in consideration of the community.

I fully realize the best answer to is to keep interacting with the site to earn rep to reach 50; I'm working on that.  However, I wanted to know if there are any tips one may recommend that I may be overlooking to follow up on the question at a lower rep level while at the same time observing SO's social mores.  I totally understand and respect the site's reputation model, however in this case it seems engineered to compel folks to create unnecessary duplicate newbie questions, which I want to avoid.

Comment: Good on you for realizing misusing the answer section is _not_ the way to go. Unfortunately, there really isn't a whole lot you can do until you can comment. I suggest favoriting the question (the star under the vote arrows, if you didn't already know) so you can come back to it after you _do_ get the necessary rep. As for getting the rep, [this Meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow) may be of some help to you.

Comment: Thanks Kendra!  This is actually the kind of tip I was looking for.  Do you know if the Favorite passes a notification to the OP?

Comment: On the plus side, you can get the necessary rep with 17 good, accepted suggested edits (those give you 2 rep a piece), 4 answer upvotes, 7 question upvotes, or any combination of the two. (Or you could get lucky and go the way I did it: Find another site on the network you can consider yourself very knowledgable in (For me, this was [Arqade,](gaming.stackexchange.com) the gaming site) and answer questions there. Getting 200 rep on any site gives you an automatic 100 rep on all accounts associated to the same network profile.)

Comment: The favorite feature passes no notifications to anyone, but it _is_ a good way to keep track of questions you've taken an interest in. There's a tab on your profile labelled "Favorites" which will have an indicator if the question is edited, receives new comments, or receives an answer. There have been requests to enhance the feature a bit, but they've fallen through so far.

Comment: You have the same problem and want to ask about it as well? Or you think you have an answer but need more details?

Comment: JC: I have the same problem as the OP, and the question hasn't had an answer.  I wanted to ask the OP if they'd had any progress with the issue not posted in SO... the question has aged a few months with no updates.

Comment: @Kendra Did you mean 12 good accepted suggested edits? :p

Comment: The duplicate closure feature was made to require an answered question a while back. If the problem is languishing without a solution, and you can write a good, detailed new question out of your version, it wouldn't be the end of the world. Best case would actually be that your question gets an answer, and then the older one can be closed as a dupe of yours.

Comment: It looks like you've solved your problem by getting the reputation necessary to be able to leave comments.  That's the standard fix.

Comment: JL: I did! All is well.  I finally got some feedback on some answers I left several days before.  This question also had an unintended benefit.  Thanks everyone for your well thought out advice.

Comment: BTW, to ping someone in comments, you need to add @ and the handler without spaces. The system hints you when you type @ first letter like `@v` and tab auto completes @VonRugen

Comment: *"Obviously I don't want to ask in the answer form"* I almost wish we could all team up and just grant you the 50 rep for that alone.

Answer (score 6):

> Obviously I don't want to ask in the answer form,

Good job for being conscientious about that.

> nor do I want to create a duplicate question in consideration of the community.

Well, just because we close dupes doesn't mean we don't like them. Identical dupes will be deleted, but when it comes to similar dupes - we close them so they can be used to point to canonical questions so that all the best answers will be on the canonical question. If they're different enough (marginally similar, maybe?) we don't even close them.

See Dr. Strange-wood's official guidelines on question duplication [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/), but for the sake of those who would rather not click and read the whole treatise, here's some words of wisdom I'd point you to:

> 1. Having one "perfect" form of a question that contains every possible answer to every slight variation of that question is a myth
>      at best and actively harmful at worst.
> 2. Having dozens and dozens of variations of the same question is clearly bad.
> 3. What we want is on the order of 4 or 5 similar-but-not-quite-the-same duplicates to cover all possible search
>      terms and common permutations of the question. It is also OK for these
>      duplicates to have their own answers so people who find them don't
>      have to click yet again to get to a good answer.

And I'll also cite [Josh Caswell](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319334/seeking-more-information-on-open-question-without-spamming/319381#comment324323_319334):

> The duplicate closure feature was made to require an answered question a while back. If the problem is languishing without a solution, and you can write a good, detailed new question out of your version, it wouldn't be the end of the world. Best case would actually be that your question gets an answer, and then the older one can be closed as a dupe of yours.

And keep in mind that comments are second class citizens - they can go away. So answers go in the answers, and questions in the questions, please.