# Automatic warning box/block submission for submitting comments as answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I found some users mention they have no enough reputations and post comments as answers honestly: when [search with "enough reputation comment"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=Enough%20reputation%20comment), it has already found some answers fall in this case:

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37019339/5263291)

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37017728/5263291)

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37003581/5263291)

So, is it a good idea to have automatic warning box/block submission when users are trying to mention "enough reputation comment" in their answers?

Comment: I think it's a good idea myself!  And don't see any downsides!

Comment: I think it is waste of effort - if one knowingly does something wrong and proud of it there is nothing can be done to stop such person... Downvote such "answer" and move on.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov As a fairly "new" user, I also found the issue of not being able to comment very frustrating. I don't participate in the most popular tags, so getting enough reputation with a few good answers/questions took a while. I'm not sure the bar to submit comments is set at the right "height." I suspect well meaning users that want more clarification on a question are being hindered instead of encouraged. Sure, it stops spammers, but if other measures are more effective, perhaps lowering the bar on allowing comments might be useful.

Comment: This won't stop users from posting them, unfortunately. They will just remove the sentence and make it even harder to spot that it is not an answer...

Comment: @BoogaRoo 6 days it took you to get first 50 points sounds like a reasonable time to learn about how site is working and basic rules. [Getting started](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow) discussion provides some hints on more consistent start. Note that whole point of barrier is to stop something - several days is reasonable time and discourages enough people to create comment-only fake accounts. (I understand that it is not instant gratification and may not be acceptable for younger visitors)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I had been visiting the site for years before signing up and starting to participate. The mechanisms behind the scenes that are all detailed here in Meta were never discovered before hitting that invisible wall that is the comment reputation limit. Being forced to answer a question without being able leave a comment asking for clarification feels especially harsh. When you're someone new and wanting to help someone and your only option is to leave an answer, that's all you can do. That's what the system feels like when you start to use it.