# Can we block some obvious comments-as-answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, not-an-answer

I'm tired of reading things like this in answers:

> I don't have the reputation to comment, so posting this as an answer.

Do we want to have some kind of automatic filtering to catch answers like this and display an error instead of posting them?  Perhaps something like this:

> **Do not post comments as answers.**  Answers which do not answer the question will be downvoted and may be subject to deletion.

We discussed this [in May](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322372/automatic-warning-box-block-submission-for-submitting-comments-as-answers), but I don't see a [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) or [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) on it.  It looks like it got bogged down in an argument over whether or not it would magically solve every instance of this problem (to which the answer is "no, obviously it won't, but it is likely to stop at least one well-meaning but ignorant person from doing this, so it is better than the status quo.").

Can we please get a firm yes or no on this?

Comment: It's a fair proposal - but would it not just lead to the OP removing such a statement from the post, and therewith dastardly avoiding your road block?

Comment: @Rad: I don't care.  Such people are not the target audience of the block.

Comment: @RadLexus All of the blocks against certain bits of text can be circumvented trivially. The hope is that we'll throw a message up in front of the user telling them that if they don't have an *answer*, they shouldn't be *answering*. Whether or not they'll read it is a different question. I'm not for or against this idea, but "the user can circumvent it" isn't a good counter argument. Anything can be circumvented.

Comment: Are you suggesting that someone be presented with a text warning when certain criteria are met, but still allowed to go ahead and post, or to be blocked entirely from posting answers with certain matching strings of text? If the latter, what strings of text? Can you show that those won't have false positives, leading to p0rblem-style frustration?

Comment: Hey, once they know their answers get blocked when certain "string conditions" are met, they just won't add the (sorry for answering a comment) part and they will go straigth for their comments-as-answer without specifying anything. Remember... most of them are programmers, they know about string conditions. They also know they should not do it, but they will still do. When someone do that, it's because he feels like what he has to say is important. The sad part is that... most of the time it's not...

Comment: "Make sure the answer you are posting answers the question. Answers that don't answer the question, can be deleted and the system could prevent you from answering questions."

Comment: @BradLarson I would expect that a strongly written message, like the above, would prevent this.

Comment: @Antoine They won't necessarily know that the error is triggered by a set string text, nor what that is.  They'll just know that they're seeing a warning telling them that they shouldn't post an answer when they don't have an answer.  Some percent will figure it out, or find a relevant meta post describing what the filter text is, but a notable percentage will, at a minimum, not consider it worth the time to figure out how to violate the rules, even if they're not interested in following them.

Comment: @Servy seems logic, what about a (please copy/paste in comment and i delete my answer after) ? I mean, can you really determine wich strings represent a comment-as-answer ? I don't know, guess they could still detect an amount of comment strings.

Comment: Side note: there is positive part of downvote and delete process for such "answers" - posters are getting close to answer ban in addition to question ban... And than may potentially read some SO guidelines to get out of the ban... :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov What is positive about getting someone closer to an answer ban when they are posting a comment as an answer? It doesn't solve the current problem of posting comments as answers and I am unsure what future problem it would solve.

Comment: @JoeW on average I'd expect person who purposely ignore the rules to not produce on-topic content. So if such person get answer-banned by just posting comments as answers it will save people some reputation that otherwise had to be spent downvoting future off-topic answers.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Once again, **those people are not the people we care about**.  We care about the people who don't know what the rules are, but are willing to follow them once they are informed of the rules.  Yes, it would be nice if those people read the whole tour page and the entire help center, but they do not actually do that.  The people who don't want to follow the rules will get banned sooner or later anyway, and at any rate, this proposal will not make things any worse w.r.t. those people.

Comment: I think this is a good idea, but I really hate the rhetoric of "if it saves even one person, it's a good idea!" There are far too many ideas that can help many more than just one person, and SE can't possibly implement them all with limited resources, so *priorities*, people. [Features start at -100](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/).

Comment: Highly related http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285924/311398

Comment: @BradLarson Slightly related. Here is a list of [blacklisted words](https://gist.github.com/Bhargav-Rao/942b95de4d7fb366c5b786fcdce2a9a6). [Here are the 597 posts](https://gist.github.com/Bhargav-Rao/ee07b4e94f46191cf4b47e54678be2c7) caught by the filter. But true, we can't guarantee that there will be no fps. There were [40 fps](https://gist.github.com/Bhargav-Rao/cef8dea6614a63d7d73778278eb0899a) (many due to a bug in the detection).

Comment: I remember when I hadn't enough rep that a short answer was triggering a message like "Are you sure you don't want it to be a comment instead ?" and then it was automagically converted to a comment on the question. I even [got the commentator badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/31/commentator?userid=3702797) while [I still didn't had enough rep to post such comments](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido?tab=reputation&sort=time&StartDate=2016-08-05%2005:00:02Z&page=17). Has this feature been removed since then?

Comment: @Kaiido: No, that can still happen, but it only happens with short answers that are basically just internal links. If it's an external link, or has no link, it's not going to be auto-converted.

Comment: This has been addressed so many times on meta. Still nobody has managed to give a sound rationale why the site allows a 1 rep user to post an answer and not a comment, when we have so much higher expectations on answers than on comments. The original reason was something about spam filters and poor mod tools for comments. I guess the core problem is that user moderators aren't allowed to moderate comments.

Comment: Counterpoint: I *just* edited a [question that said](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/89a37517-a9ff-4b0f-bf45-13c3f77dac21/view-source) "i can't add comments to that post cause my low reputation". If they had enough rep to post a comment, they would have asked their new question in a comment.

Comment: I think there should not be a minimum reputation for posting comments. That would solve everything. Instead we should have a mechanism for downvoting comments. Downvoted comments from people with less than a minimum reputation will be hidden unless a "show all comments" link is clicked

Comment: @Lundin We don't want to stop new users from answering. Suppose you're an expert in ObscureStuff, but you've never been on Stack Exchange before. One day you come across a question on ObscureStuff Stack Exchange, to which you know the answer. We don't want to stop you from posting the answer by forcing you to gain rep first. On the other hand, if comments were free, we'd see a lot of off-topic commenting, joke comments and general clutter from people who don't understand our model - or don't care about it.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I didn't say that we should stop new users from answering, that would be silly. I'm rather saying that the 50 rep to comment doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Lundin Ok, guess I missed your point. The threshold for commenting does make sense to me though. I believe that if comments were free for all, we'd have a lot to clean up every day. I don't think spam would be the real problem - spam never surives long here. The problem would be mindless chatter. Comment chains derailed into arguments about politics, people trying to be funny, and whining about moderation. ("Why was this closed?! Everybody needs to know what the best PHP framework is! The modz are evil!!!") I would, however, be in favor of lowering the threshold a bit. Like 15 or 25 points.

Comment: @Lundin - I agree, and [have proposed some ways](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258670/19679) that I think we might be able to open up commenting to more people while improving community moderation of comments. This could eliminate that bit of frustration people have with the site, prevent many of these non-answers, and still do a better job of cleaning up comments than we see now.

Comment: @BradLarson How much work is there for diamond mods to moderate comments with the current system? Is there some pattern where low rep users yield more flagged comments than others, etc?

Comment: @Lundin - Comment flags are easy to process. It's getting people to notice problematic comments in the first place that's the challenge. Without a review system that points out new comments in the way that new posts are reviewed, many bad comments are just buried until someone happens across them. There needs to be a better way for the community to review these so that bad comments can be found quickly and flagged.