# shortcut to being able to upvote and add comments to posts?

Tags: discussion

Is it possible to have my credentials reviewed and not have to go through the rigmarole of trying to gain enough points to give credit where credit is due?

I truly appreciate the knowledge being shared by the Stack Overflow community, but am too busy to spend the time to even figure out how to get reputation points.

Comment: We don't review profiles or credentials, we only judge posts by voting on them. That is all we do here, for everyone, high rep or low rep, doesn't matter.

Comment: See [Why are 15 reputation points required to upvote?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41347/310998) on Meta.SE.

Comment: This isn't Twitter, you don't get a blue tick if people know who you are.

Comment: There is plenty of guidance around on meta, like [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: I'm getting some very strong deja vu when reading this question...I feel like we've had a discussion to this before.

Comment: Lol.... That smells like a sock

Answer (score 2):

> and not have to go through the rigmarole of trying to gain enough points to give credit where credit is due?

No, you have to.

It's actually easy to get these required 50 points rep, as you're showing positive contributions to the site.