# Cannot comment, stuck below 50 reputation

Tags: support, reputation

I am down at 44 reputation, I have been stuck there for quite some time. I have asked questions and gotten no responses, and also answered some questions, with no real feedback.

I am just trying to find simple ways to increase my reputation without adding posts like this one that is probably not adding to the conversation. I simply want to get up to 50 at least so I can start commenting.

I know what reputation is too, so no need to post information about that. I am a conservative poster, looking for ways to contribute more. But so often, my answers are already asked somewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure why your *meta* question got downvoted without a comment or two, not needed IMHO as your question is (though somewhat "dense") a legit ask for tips. What *might* be the reason is that you could've shared some more research on what meta posts and help center topics you visited, and why they didn't help (there's a lot of info out there: what did you read already?). Not sure. - At any rate, from first glance at your SO Q&A: don't be discouraged, you've got a net postive vote score. Keep at it, keep improving posts using help/meta, and you'll get there.

Comment: @Jeroen Probably lack of research, as the tooltip says. This question has been asked and answered many times.

Comment: Check out [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow) for some tips for newer (by time or rep) users.

Comment: well I have more than 50 reputation now, thanks all. This will help me to comment on the site and be a positive force moving forward. Thanks.

Comment: ugh, i just got downvoted on another answer I had posted for one of MY questions. Now I cannot comment again. I love stack overflow and always will for getting answers from previously answered questions, but it is not kind to newbies of a particular language who just want to comment and cannot because of reputation points.

Comment: oh also, Kendra, good post, that was exactly the same chicken and egg situation I am finding myself. No easy questions to answer anymore, and a lot of the unanswered ones are not well formed questions or are very specific problems, I cannot find quickly.

Comment: +2: suggested edit is approved

Answer (score 10):

Why do you want to comment? Comments don't usually accomplish much.

Over 3.6M [unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered), I'd guess you could probably find a few places where you could do some good...

Comment: Oh, I was looking at "my tags"... Heh. Yes, so, plenty of work to do.

Comment: Why is this community wiki?

Comment: I just figured out why you made this community wiki. To make people wonder why you made it community wiki. Wikinception.

Comment: Obviously it is community wiki so that we can keep it maintained with an active count of unanswered questions.

Comment: Um, I don't know, maybe because I find a topic directly related to what I want discussed, and because I only had a reputation of 44 I cannot contribute with a simple comment.