# Giving back to Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

I, being a newer coder, often cannot help answer questions on Stack Overflow. So I feel that I am not really giving to the community. What should I do to help out the site? I cannot give money to the company. Now I do answer every question I can. So how do I give back?

Comment: Use the moderation tools [available to you](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). (comments, voting, and questions/answers/documentation posts)

Comment: Post questions that entertain other SO users.  Try to give some back when you can.  Judging from your profile, that's what you've been doing.  Well done.

Comment: Well, the first thing you can do is research before asking a question :). See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17310/194720. All I did was search for your title (using Stack Overflow instead of SO)...

Comment: Wow I actually looked for some questions like mine. Couldn't find any

Comment: Read the linked question and answers, they're pretty good. One quick note though: folks tend to think of their current state as being more or less permanent, but... Rather quickly, you are not going to be a newer coder - you'll be an older coder, with lots of experience and esoteric knowledge. Remember how you feel now, so that you'll be willing to share when the time comes.

Comment: @Shot9 I really hope I don't become a permanent noob. I am working on learning C for fun and to give back for SO

Comment: [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflo)

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you. I may not seem like much to say well done but it does help know what I am trying to do is good :)

Comment: Regarding your choice to learn C... that's excellent and good for your education, but do keep in mind that this topic has been covered front to back on Stack Overflow, so it may be a difficult subject for you to earn reputation points with.

Comment: I don't really care about earning the rep. I just want to help people out

Comment: *"I am working on learning C for fun"* weirdo.