# The duplicate is the answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions

Many new users ask questions which are quickly flagged as duplicates. Many are also flagged in other ways, but I'm focusing on duplicate flags.

When new users' questions are flagged `duplicate` some seem to become distressed and frustrated rather than realize an the community is helping them. Hence part of the reason for SO's sometimes [negative](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late) rep, or why new users can [feel hated](https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d#.4705xbjpm), and even experienced developers [become frustrated](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/why-i-refuse-to-use-stackoverflow/38483).

It seems there is a obstacle to connecting *why* a duplicate *is* an answer in a constructive manner, and is instead resolved through patience and time on the site, to [Atlas' frustration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156122/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-moderators/156125#156125). Is the community harming itself by leaving flags unexplained?

I think there a better way to improve this process. The review queue is very explicit when it asks for reviewers to leave comments and vote... Yet it is not so clear to new users [what is going on](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow). Typical reviewers are more experienced - so, rhetorically, how does that help the community and the brand new OP, whom usually doesn't know a review queue exists, when their question gets flagged with little explanation? (Not that this is a hand-holding site either, it's definitely not.)

**EDIT:** clarified that I want to *improve* the user notification, rather than add. Because many new users still seem to lack understanding, even after the fact.

**I think a good feature request would be to improve and clarify the user-friendly OP-facing notification** for questions which are flagged duplicate. Such a notification would explain to the OP the answer **is** found, and the duplicate **is** the answer.

To clarify: **my goal isn't to add to moderator work-load**, but to reduce the work-load by making a small by making a quality improvement to user notifications in order to make them more apparent to new users, who generate the largest amount of high-effort low-return headaches for the community at large.

**EDIT:** In fact, as I state in the comments, just brain-storming, the *smallest, most impactful* change could simply be changing "On Hold" or "Closed" (Which, with context, communicates that a conversation is now "closed", or that a user is put "on hold," which no one enjoys.) to a more positive "Answer Found!" **Changing "Close/On Hold" to "Answer found!" has the benefit of also being more accurate.**

Incentivizing the community (and moderators) to provide constructive feedback doesn't mean that those who don't are penalized, but rather those *who already do go above and beyond* are rewarded better for their efforts.

I would hope better incentive/reward for taking the time to explain things (and more a more apparent and effective notification process to new users) would be welcomed as a positive enhancement to overall community-wide experience, along with improving new user education, and thereby reducing the amount of work the volunteers must do in the long run... Instead of leaving new users feeling like having [shouted for a doctor](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/senior-doctor-who-shouted-its-7538975) in a hospital, and being ignored.

Comment: I'm not sure if it happens when a question is *flagged* as a duplicate, but once a question receives an official *vote* to close as a duplicate, a message is presented to the person who asked the question explaining that their question might already have an answer "over here", linking to the proposed duplicate. If they agree, they can mark their own question as a duplicate. So, this basically does happen—nevertheless, your observations are correct, there seems to be a lot of hurt feelings over having a question marked as a duplicate, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: @CodyGray It is in fact presented to them even when they're just a flag, although the wording is slightly altered "to say, 'possible duplicate' rather than 'duplicate'", and to include a button to let them close it themselves.

Comment: `I would hope better incentive/reward to moderators for explaining things, and reduce the amount of effort to follow through on flags, which is incredible, to encourage moderators/reviewers to engage OP's` - I don't think you really have a good grasp of the sheer volume of work this would entail.  Keep in mind that every "moderator" (both the elected moderators and the user community with close powers) are 100% volunteer.  And with the numbers of questions coming in (whether they are dups, or just bad questions, or good questions), there isn't time to tell the OP exactly what they did wrong.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I have a good understand of the sheer volume of work - which is why I'm suggesting something to reduce moderator work, and new user frustration. That "something" is a single thing: to improve the notification process. I also discuss adding incentive to help new users, which doesn't mean taking away from others or adding more work, but **better rewarding those who already go above and beyond**, maybe by just awarding a badge, or giving a point,  for adding a comment AND throwing a useful flag. Neither of those points seem like a sheer volume work to accomplish.

Comment: It doesn't matter how we change the text notifying the user their question is a duplicate. Most of them won't read it at all. I don't know how many times I've voted to close a question as a dupe, only to have the OP say "It's not a duplicate because X is not the same as Y", even though the banner(s) explicitly tell them to edit their question to include why it's not a duplicate, and the question will get reopened. All new users see is the "Closed"/"On Hold" text and freak the heck out, without even trying to apply the duplicate's answers.

Comment: *"improve and clarify the user-friendly OP-facing notification"* that would require the user to read the banner Servy pointed out which should be leading the user to read the answers, trying out the solutions presented and if none work, edit their question with what they have done and how they didn't work. but many would rather whine or edit their questions with *"**THIS ISN'T A DUPLICATE!!!!!!!**"* without any further explination

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan what you say is true, and that's my point. Maybe it's crazy talk, I'm just brain-storming, but how about changing "Closed/On hold," (which seems negative - no on likes a prematurely closed conversation, or to be put "on hold"... Those words explicitly state "we are ignoring you, for now or forever")... to a more positive to "Answer found!" or some such, which is **actually more accurate**.

Comment: One trick I like to use wherever it makes sense to do so is serving the duplicate vote with a short comment (one or two lines should be enough) highlighting what makes the duplicate useful (if the duplicate is not obvious) or suggesting another relevant related question (if I stumbled upon one while looking for the duplicate). It seems to work well, though perhaps that's just because I have been lucky when it comes to meeting cooperative OPs. (It also goes without saying that there is no way to systematise, automatise or enforce this strategy.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is the community harming itself by leaving flags unexplained?

Sometimes, yes, but it's not clear how often. There are some cases where it's abundantly clear that a question is a duplicate. For example, [Emacs and cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/269520/1288), where the OP accepted an answer that was simply a link to another question and its answers.

There are other cases where it isn't as clear (at least to the OP). For example, take a look at [while loop not working Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1288). Some people will know before even clicking that link to read the question that it's one of thousands of duplicates of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1288) But even after reading the string comparison question and answers, it might not click to an inexperienced programmer exactly where the problem lies in their own code. (After all, they were having a problem with a loop, not a string comparison, right?)

Since we're already displaying two banners explaining that a question is already answered, I don't think any more automatic notifications are the answer to the second case. Instead, I think it's a good idea to leave a comment with your close vote stating exactly where the problem is, and how it's solved by the original post in cases where it might not be clear to the OP. It's a little more work for a close voter, but I think a custom message is what's called for.

Answer (score 12):

> I think a good feature request would be to add some new user-friendly OP-facing notification for questions which are flagged duplicate. Such a notification would explain to the OP the answer is found, and the duplicate is the answer.

That was implemented like 3 years ago.  The duplicate banner says all of those things.