# Would a low reputation discourage answers to a users questions?

Tags: discussion

I'm relatively new to SO but am getting the impression that some users who have a lower reputation are getting ignored by those who could help most due to their inability to up vote (cannot upvote until a minimum of 15 reputation) prospective answers to their questions.

Obviously those with a lower reputation are probably not as experienced as others and this results in lower quality questions (sometimes due to the user not knowing **how** to ask the question) but given the inability to upvote constructive contribution, could this result in low-reputation users not getting the constructive contribution they need due to the lack of incentive for experienced users?

Comment: In addition to Pekka웃's comment; a good question can always be edited into even better shape. It's enough if the question shows (research) effort and an honest desire to learn. At least that's my experience ...

Comment: *sometimes due to the user not knowing how to ask the question* which is a bit strange given they have passed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice) (and checked the box) but beyond that the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is full of guidance and here on meta there is the [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). I would be eager to know why the efforts to provide guidance don't get picked up by new users.

Comment: Stop just "getting the impression" and use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to confirm or deny your assumptions. If you've proof that that's happening, let us know.

Comment: I certainly don't ignore questions from low rep users  I have to check to make sure they're bad, (even though I'm often pretty sure from the title), before downvoting and voting to close/delete.

Comment: worth reading this thread too: [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: I'm confused, what would the ability to upvote have to do with anything? Voting is anonymous, you can't know who upvoted you. And anyone with the minimum required reputation can still upvote anyway, it's not like that right is reserved for the person asking the question.

Comment: I definitely don't notice askers rep unless the question is particularly bad...Besides a user can vote only once(if I were to be that rep hungry) on the answer and others can vote too..

Comment: *Obviously those with a lower reputation are probably not as experienced as others...* Being new to the site does not necessarily mean being new to programming.

Comment: Even if there is a valid issue here, (not convinced), I would have no anwser to it.  Lowering the hurdle to upvoting would increase fraud:(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> am getting the impression that some users who have a lower reputation are getting ignored by those who could help most due to their inability to up vote

This seems very unlikely. Even if the community were this greedy and point-focused, what gains the most points is upvotes from *other* users. The asker's would just be a drop in the bucket.

Also, you're not entirely powerless even as a 1-point user: as the asker, you can mark an answer as accepted regardless of your reputation level. This nets the answerer 15 points which don't count toward the daily 200-point reputation cap, making it a much more attractive prize to power users than upvotes (which *do* count against the cap).

Ultimately, and most importantly though - while everyone likes to play the reputation game to some extent, you'll encounter plenty of users here whose primary focus is *actually helping people* and providing useful content rather than optimizing every interaction for point gain. To those users, the asker's reputation is not going to be important - but then, they usually do care a *lot* about the question's quality!

I'd recommend focusing on making the question as clear, well-titled, well-tagged, etc., as possible. The rest will work out over time.

Ideally, the under-15-rep situation is very temporary anyway: you need 2 answer upvotes, 3 question upvotes, or 8 accepted edits to get past the limit.

Comment: ...and accepted edits are *easy.*