# How can I ask better questions?

Tags: discussion

I am new to posting on Stack Overflow but I have read many answers in the past. I have read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) along with other threads with tips on how to ask good questions.

I try to ask questions about a specific problem and include minimal code showing what I have tried and where I am stuck, but I am still getting down voted.

Can someone review my questions and give me pointers on writing better questions?

For review:

- [How to insert text at line and column position in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49742962/9614249)
- [How to get list of all channels using discordgo?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49715470/9614249)
- [Send private message with discordgo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49717232/9614249)
- [Use string defined type value as string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49716191/9614249)

Comment: worth a read: [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: So I'm not sure if this is because of the Meta effect or not, but **none of your questions are scored negatively**.  You're doing surprisingly well.

Comment: @Makoto All my questions were at 0 or -1 when I posted initially.

Comment: Googling the title of the 1st question in the list seems to give answers. Read the downvote arrow mouseover text: "This question does not show any research effort; [...]". So that may be why downvotes. Also there is a close vote for lack of [mcve].

Comment: @philipxy When googling I didn't see any answers that accomplish what I am trying to do in python, only bash. And does the the close vote give more detail? I gave a working example of what I am trying to do and explained why my solution is not ideal. What would a good [MCVE] be in this case?

Comment: Does googling your title with 'python stackoverflow' give answers or not? You asked why downvotes: that's a reason why. It doesn't matter how your googling went, if you want better response, learn to google better. Here is my current standard comment: Always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags.

Comment: ... Surely you can expect the 4th link is also a duplicate. Always google the manual & web for an error message with & without your specific names/strings; read all the answers of questions, as there can be many causes. Re MCVE: I mentioned the close vote as a reason for a downvote. But I don't think it merits a MCVE close vote. It's good you gave code to at least acccomplish the update somehow.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first question seems fine to me.  There are some comments steering you the right way, but nobody has put in the time to write up a complete answer yet.

The last one also seems fine and has an accepted answer, so I'm not sure what you are worried about.  Be patient.

Answer (score 2):

Your questions seem fine to me as well.  You stated what you were trying to do, and then you provided some code that you were trying to use towards that purpose.  Usually when I see questions that I have an issue with they have just one of the two; either stating what they want without any code attempt given, or only code provided not stating what their goal is.

To me, you need both.  The statement of what you want tells the readers what your goal is and can direct them towards possibly telling you if your approach is not the best approach to reach your goal.  Providing code not only shows that you made an attempt to solve the problem yourself, but makes it much easier for people to help debug it and hone in on your possible issues much faster.

Answer (score 1):

**General Approach To Ask a Better Question**

---

While there are guidelines - I believe it all starts with understanding what you are trying to do. The typical cycle is:

- Understand the problem (simplify it if you have to, write it out on paper)
- Try to solve it yourself. You will be surprised how many people hunt for a quick answer and not the actual knowledge.
- Do a research. Use Google, Stack Exchange Communities as well as other resources.

Then analyze and see how much information should be given to others to understand your problem and form a good title and a description.

I believe if you follow this pattern - others will be responsive and helpful.

---

**In regards to the feedback to your questions:**

Your last two questions need to start with how to it seems like. The body of those look fine to me but I am unaware of the context so I just scanned it with my eyes to get the idea. The first two look fine to me.