# Can we make the "belongs as a comment" text more welcoming?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

While I was going through the Low Quality Posts review queue, I spotted an answer to the question that was genuinely helpful as a comment. When you reccomend for deletion, you're given an option to leave a templated comment on the post to help the author learn. Here's the current text for when an answer belongs as a comment:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.

The current text feels overly cold and bureaucratic. It's like being told [your post is bad and you should feel bad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jG2KMkQLZmI). For a user with good intents and knowledge to contribute, it reduces the chance the user will return next time. Having your post deleted isn't exactly a good first experience for a user.

I propose we use:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. **Thank you for your contribution. We hope to see you again on Stack Overflow!**

Can we reword this comment to be clearer? I'm open to hearing other ways to make the text warmer.

Comment: 'The current text feels overly cold and bureaucratic'.... like a computer, say?  It's purely informational/instructional.  I can't see anything much wrong with it.   Replacing 'instead' with 'for now'. would be marginally better English, but that's about all.

Comment: Your proposal sounds overly friendly and somewhat patronizing.  They left a non-answer; we want to encourage them to post more?

Comment: @fbueckert: Well, we don't want to discourage them from posting; we want to encourage them to post *correctly*. Granted, I don't think the suggested change does this, nor do I feel that the current text is unwelcoming. But there's no reason why we shouldn't encourage them to post further, just in an appropriate fashion.

Comment: The current text doesn't say "Your answer is more of a comment, but you don't have enough reputation to comment."  That's why it is awkward.

Comment: @Elin Sometimes they do have enough reputation to comment. Apparently it's very easy to accidentally post an answer instead of a comment on mobile.

Answer (score 24):

I think you're reading this too literally.

First and foremost, the post that the person is making *is* bad.  They shouldn't be providing comments as answers in the first place.

Second, I don't see any value or purpose behind ***thanking*** someone for a contribution which we *explicitly* ***do not want*** on the site.

Third...how much sympathy do you want to spare for someone who gets offended when they are corrected for not following the established policies of the site?

Comment: Yes, the post is bad. The system should be thanking the person for puting the effort into writing the commentary. It's not about "getting offended". If we provide more sympathy, we'll have more returning users that will contribute for years to come.

Comment: Do you have ideas for another text so as to not imply the post was good?

Comment: ...Do you mean to tell me that there seriously are people who felt offended or put off of the site because of that comment?  Who gets thanked for work which cannot be used?

Comment: I'm mildly offended by the English:  the grammar seems a bit 'off' to me, but not so much that I would suggest effort to change it.  The suggested additions don't add any value and, if anything, would increase the [very small] number of users who are put off.

Comment: @Makoto No, of course not.

Comment: Okay then @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ, why are we then looking to solve a non-problem then?  I'm not swayed by the argument that this text is overly *anything* right now...

Comment: @Makoto The current text dissuades people from coming back to the site.

Comment: While I absolutely agree that we shouldn't be thanking them, "we" are trying to be more welcoming. As far as I'm concerned, the entire "be more welcoming" effort is directed towards improving the experiences of those who don't quite know how it works around here (which presumably includes users posting comments as answers), because someone who does everything perfectly shouldn't receive any "unwelcoming" comments, votes, edits or messages. If you were to argue there's nothing offensive in the message, fair enough, but your argument seems to be closer to saying causing offence is fine.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing I might add to the existing text, if I were going to change it at all, would be to add: *"[More advice on how to get started as a new user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow)."*

Because what I usually see when people respond to the comment is some variation of, "But I don't have enough reputation to comment!" This also sometimes results in meta posts with folks either asking how to earn enough reputation to comment or asking for the reputation requirement to be lowered.

I personally don't find the auto-comment unwelcoming but maybe it's not as useful as it could be.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but it could be useful to have a link explaining how things work around here (Q&A with no distractions - that type of thing), why we have this restriction and what one should do instead of posting a non-answer in each case (a "me too" answer, asking for clarification, adding some related information, posting some "too chatty" or whatever else).

Answer (score -4):

You can make text "warmer" by adding a word here or there. Adding entire sentences is too much.

> Answers must attempt to answer the question that was asked, which this **unfortunately** does not seem to do. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; until then, **try to** provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.

(Bold only to highlight (part of) what was added. I would've added "unfortunately" to the current phrasing, but that just sounded weird, and I didn't like the current phrasing much to begin with - yes, it doesn't answer the question, but we're not actually telling them that's a problem)

Although I don't think the current text is particularly cold - the second sentence in particular seems ... fine?