# Can I proxy comment a question?

Tags: discussion

In a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637534/does-access-vba-has-listbox-list-method-as-excel-vba-has/21732430#21732430) I suggested an edit but was rejected because my edit is expected to be added as either an answer or a comment, I don't wanna add it as answer because it isn't a complete answer, but I would wanna add it as comment but that too I can't do because I don't have 50 reputation so is there a way my comment could reach there as I think it will be something helpful for other.

Comment: Simple rule: [First earn 50 reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252149/2675154), then start commenting.

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As the comments on your question already mention, if you cannot make a complete useful answer you basically are expected to wait for the commenting privilege.

However, you have two more options, which are based on participating in the answering process when/where no perfect answer exists.

- start off the answering process with some relevant research results or experiment outcomes - provided they are a noticable step towards answering
- adding some valuable insight to existing answers

The first one matches the concept that partial answers are an accepted part of the answering process at StackOverflow. Even only "observations from the wild", i.e. detailed experiments confirming something or narrowing a problem down are accepted, if they really provide valuable insight and do not fit into a comment (whether you can comment or not). Even if they are not actually an answer or a solution which covers all details - a reasonable step towards solving a problem or a good answer to one part of a question is accepted here.
This does of course only make sense if there is not already an answer or solution which does cover everything. The question needs to be "less unanswered" with your participation than before.
You probably want to mention that it is supposed to be a partial answer and not accidentally incomplete.

The second one is an answer which adds something valuable to an existing answer. It can be in the shape of referring to the other answer (maybe with a short summary, in case you are worried that it might be deleted; but do not copy) and then explaining your additional input or your alternative to part of it.
Again, the solution by combining your add-on answer with the other answer should be noticably better than only the other answer and it should be different from all other existing answers.

Whatever you do, it must be useful, or deserves to be downvoted; "cannot be flagged" is not the same as "useful". 
A useful first partial answer must be noticably better than no answer.
A useful add-on to an existing answer must be a noticable extra improvement on top of the best existing answer.
This is hard. So in most cases you are better off with the initial "Either wait for the comment privilege, make a complete useful standalone answer or don't post anything."

Comment: Thanks now I know I can add answer as partial with mention of the rest part from another answer in same question.

Comment: I did as you said on the same Question, guess what ! A Down Vote and -2 in reputation - I'm not complaining you had disclaimer in last passage but this should keep me away from stackoverflow for brief period I guess

Comment: Well, as you can tell from the downvotes on my answer (no upvotes in betweeen by the way), I have trouble getting users to agree even on the generic part. 4 or even more (down)votes are more or less neglible noise on meta. I am waiting for some actual voting counts and hoping for some agreement or some explanation. Ideally I hope for a quote from help or a link to a relevant meta discussion. If I am proven wrong I will delete and ask you to accept my apology. But of course I am convinced of what I wrote - admittedly just cannot quote anything myself either...

Comment: Well I guess it's just the way it is, apologies are not called for, sometimes I guess it's better to keep quiet and pass by! And of-course I do still agree with your notion after all if you can't collaborate to bring about a better well thought and well structured article (answer) then what the point in using internet.

Comment: my answer on Subject Post was edited by "Petter Friberg" which rendered my answer as sole answer than a dependent answer and earned me +10 in reputation, So the mechanics here is to answer solo and it will work, but obviously it should add something valuable to the Question (Question Post not the Question itself)