# Questions of mine getting downvoted – how can I become a better community member?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes, new-users

I'm looking for some advice on becoming a better member of the community. I feel like I want to leave because I keep on getting downvoted.

I understand why two of my questions were downvoted: they were off-topic and closed; there's nothing I can do about that.

But I want to know about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54675888).
I answered this question and was downvoted twice and lost reputation, which I am upset about now. I think I answered it well, but the thing that bugs me is that I didn't get any reasoning on what was wrong. So now I have an answer, two downvotes but nobody commented to let me know what was wrong with it. Why?

And how can I get some deeper advice on how to be a better member of the community and earn more rep?

Comment: The first thing that pops to mind is that the question isn't great (it's too broad, to be precise). I don't necessarily condone it, but some users have a tendency to downvote answers (even good ones) on bad questions. Not saying that's necessarily what happened (short of a mind reading device or one of the downvoters coming here explaining the, we'll never know anyway), but it seems like a good starting point

Comment: It's pretty hard to give a good answer to a bad question. Maybe they're reacting to statements like "seems like you could do research online..." which is not normally something that belongs in a SO answer (as asking a question on SO *is*, arguably, doing research online). That said, I wouldn't usually downvote answers on bad questions unless the answer contains actual misinformation. Keep contributing, persevere - you'll eventually get to the point where downvotes no longer significantly affect your reputation.

Comment: IMO the main reason about downvotes is the question itself but I would like to point out some points from your answer. First of all, I can see a bit of question like language in your answer and also you are unsure about some of your suggestions. In terms of wording your answer, take some hints from the other answer on that question(It also has 2 downvotes) but for me it is better written than your answer. If you have any doubt in answering, first try to clarify those via asking in comments like you want free versions or paid, something like that.

Comment: The thing that stuck me first is that both of the answers to this (now deleted) question are nothing but a list of off-site resources without any information how and why they would solve the asker's problem. So even if the question isn't a resource-request the answers tend to make it look like one.

Comment: Regarding "deeper advice", maybe this is a good start: [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252149/2675154)

Comment: Some users are telling you that the answer could have received downvotes because of the question's quality, but that's not completely true, and could send the wrong message. That answer wasn't useful, period. If you are going to try your hand at answering, choose subjects you are already an expert to, and can write good, specific, detailed answers. Off the cuff, vague advise about wildly different off-site services, not very useful.

Comment: Thank you all. I'm definitely gonna take my time, learn more, take this advice and be better and smarter.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Remember that downvotes exist to indicate how *useful* an answer is, not how *correct* it is.  An answer that doesn't have inaccuracies, but that is not useful to others *still merits downvotes*. Lots of things can make an answer unhelpful or not useful besides just misinformation.  Additionally, rather than trying to encourage people to just keep contributing *anything* in the hopes that they get to a point that they can ignore signs that their posts are problematic, I think people would be better served *actually improving their contributions* so that they don't merit downvotes.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that if people dislike a question (the question is being downvoted), they are often (mad?) at people that answer the question and may downvote a reasonable answer. Just something to be aware of.

Comment: Also, one explanation for downvotes on valid answers to bad questions IMO is that when a low quality question gets answered and the answer is upvoted, question cannot be deleted, I think some users try to avoid that by downvoting the answer

Comment: @Andrew It's *really* hard to post a useful answer to a bad question.  That's what makes a question bad after all.  The *overwhelming* majority of answers to bad questions are going to be bad *because the problems with the questions make it impossible, or almost impossible, to post a good answer*.  An answer being factually correct doesn't mean it's a useful and quality answer to the question asked.  So just assuming people thing answers to bad questions are good, but that they choose to downvote anyway, is a poor assumption.  It's *far* more likely that the felt the answer wasn't useful.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Some keywords to writing well-received posts in general:

- Narrow scope. Ask specific questions to specific problems. Only answer what's asked for and avoid de-railing the topic.
- Effort. Before posting code on the site, make sure it compiles and is properly indented. And do some:
- Research. If you have been looking for answers on your own unsuccessfully, please mention where you have looked or what you have tried.
- On-site. Content is expected to be posted on-site, at Stack Overflow. This means, no pictures of code, no links to Github, no asking where to find external resources, no posting link-only answers etc etc.
- "MCVE". [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
- Boring. No chatty language, user signatures, anecdotes, jokes, opinions, discussions, cat pictures.

Comment: no cat pictures? no pictures of code? but can we post a code done by a cat?

Answer (score 10):

At a first glance [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54674798/sending-react-projects-to-a-customer) itself appeared to be *too broad* and *unclear what the OP is asking* as the question:

- Doesn't include a specific problem.
- Not enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
- Doesn't highlights exactly what you need.
- Doesn't include the desired behavior.

and was correctly ***put on hold** as too broad*.

However I don't see any major issue with [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54674798/sending-react-projects-to-a-customer/54675888#54675888) considering the broader perspective of the question. But the ideal way to handle these questions should be to mark the question for *closure*.

Moreover the phrases *seems like*, *you could do research*, etc. mustn't be used while constructing a canonical answer and must have irked the other *contributors*.

Finally before publishing an answer, review the verbatim of your answer to keep it *short* and *simple* and avoid phrases like *could maybe*.

Taking care of these simple facts and facets can help you to turn out as a better member of the community and earn more reputation points in the long run.

Answer (score 6):

For being a better member of the community:

1. Drop the negative vibe and obsession of stats like reputation, recognition etc. If you get obsessed with these you will loose your attitude and will not be able to see the big picture.
2. Got couple of downvotes so what, we all get, its not a bad thing but its the opposite don't you think, it means that there are places which you are not good at and people are letting you know through downvotes. They may think that you are capable of finding the problem on your own and so they mayn't have commented which from your post we could see that you are trying and finding the reason for your downvotes.
3. I believe that you are already a better member of this community. you take time to understand and try to contribute what ever you can. That's really great and I believe many  may have got a help from your answers already.

Now moving on to writing better:

1. Follow simple language with examples (if possible): There are many users who don't understand English but still use Stack Overflow. So with simple English and examples they will be able to solve their problems.
2. Keep it short: Answers and questions both need to be short. As I am sure no one is interested in reading long posts in Stack Overflow as this is more like a Q&A and not blog posts.
3. Be specific and answer the questions: no derailing and make sure your answer doesn't lead to more questions.
4. Before posting your content try to look your answer from a third person point of view whether he would be able to understand or not.
5. No images, no error codes in answer and no marketing your products. Links to other sites will be OK I guess if that link will give scope, understanding/ background to the problem or the answer.

Answer (score 2):

We've all been new members of Stack Overflow, and we all have been downvoted more than once. So, based on my own experience here and in other Stack Exchange communities, I can give you this advice:

- First of all: **you are already a valuable member of the community**. Stack Overflow is for everyone, newbie, or expert. By being here you contribute to the growth of our community, and help us "pay-it-forward" for all that have been helped.
- If you want to ask a question, be thorough; make your "homework", investigate, look for a solution, Google around. When asking, tell us [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com). Be honest, state your problem clearly and tell us your attempted solutions, and why they didn't work. Tell us also what you expect.
- If you answer a question, keep it simple, and clear. If you are honest, and you really know what you're talking about, write your answer without fear. If possible, provide the output of your proposed solution. Add references, if you have them.
- Be patient. You may not get upvoted as fast as you want, but if you contribute, you will see the results (I've received a lot of votes for questions and answers I've posted years ago).
- Keep posting in Stack Overflow and also here in meta. Be active. "Pay-it-forward" whenever you can (upvoting, commenting, sharing links to questions and answers you find useful).
- A downvoted post is not (by itself) a bad thing. It only means somebody thinks your post can be improved. Edit your downvoted posts and make them better. I have downvoted many posts, and then, when I go back and see the edits, I frequently have no choice but to upvote them, because they become valuable for me.

I'll be happy to help you if I see a good question or a good answer from you. That's the way this place works.